# What is the best regular expression to check if a string is a valid URL?

Tags: regex, url, language-agnostic

How can I check if a given string is a valid URL address?

My knowledge of regular expressions is basic and doesn't allow me to choose from the hundreds of regular expressions I've already seen on the web.

Comment: Any URL or just HTTP? E.g. does mailto:me@example.com count as a URL? A a AIM chat link?

Comment: If a URL has no leading "http(etc)", how would you be able to distinguish it from any other arbitrary string that happens to have dots in it? Say something like "MyClass.MyProperty.MyMethod"? Or "I somtimes miss the spacebar.is this a problem?"

Comment: Microsoft has a Regex page that includes an expression for URLs. Surely a good start:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff650303.aspx
NB. The above page is retired, but the expressions in the table are essentially still valid for reference.
The URL expression recommended (and which worked great for me) is:
"^(ht|f)tp(s?)\:\/\/[0-9a-zA-Z]([-.\w]*[0-9a-zA-Z])*(:(0-9)*)*(\/?)([a-zA-Z0-9\-\.\?\,\'\/\\\+&amp;%\$#_]*)?$"

Comment: I tend to edit the title: The "best" regular expression is a "correct" one! What should be the "best" among all those correct ones? The shortest? Please OPs: Don't ask for the "best" unless you specify the sorting criteria. Otherwise just ask for "any".

Answer (score 486):

I wrote my URL (actually IRI, internationalized) pattern to comply with RFC 3987 (http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc3987.html). These are in PCRE syntax.

For absolute IRIs (internationalized):

```
/^[a-z](?:[-a-z0-9\+\.])*:(?:\/\/(?:(?:%[0-9a-f][0-9a-f]|[-a-z0-9\._~\x{A0}-\x{D7FF}\x{F900}-\x{FDCF}\x{FDF0}-\x{FFEF}\x{10000}-\x{1FFFD}\x{20000}-\x{2FFFD}\x{30000}-\x{3FFFD}\x{40000}-\x{4FFFD}\x{50000}-\x{5FFFD}\x{60000}-\x{6FFFD}\x{70000}-\x{7FFFD}\x{80000}-\x{8FFFD}\x{90000}-\x{9FFFD}\x{A0000}-\x{AFFFD}\x{B0000}-\x{BFFFD}\x{C0000}-\x{CFFFD}\x{D0000}-\x{DFFFD}\x{E1000}-\x{EFFFD}!\$&'\(\)\*\+,;=:])*@)?(?:\[(?:(?:(?:[0-9a-f]{1,4}:){6}(?:[0-9a-f]{1,4}:[0-9a-f]{1,4}|(?:[0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9][0-9]|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])(?:\.(?:[0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9][0-9]|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])){3})|::(?:[0-9a-f]{1,4}:){5}(?:[0-9a-f]{1,4}:[0-9a-f]{1,4}|(?:[0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9][0-9]|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])(?:\.(?:[0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9][0-9]|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])){3})|(?:[0-9a-f]{1,4})?::(?:[0-9a-f]{1,4}:){4}(?:[0-9a-f]{1,4}:[0-9a-f]{1,4}|(?:[0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9][0-9]|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])(?:\.(?:[0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9][0-9]|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])){3})|(?:(?:[0-9a-f]{1,4}:){0,1}[0-9a-f]{1,4})?::(?:[0-9a-f]{1,4}:){3}(?:[0-9a-f]{1,4}:[0-9a-f]{1,4}|(?:[0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9][0-9]|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])(?:\.(?:[0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9][0-9]|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])){3})|(?:(?:[0-9a-f]{1,4}:){0,2}[0-9a-f]{1,4})?::(?:[0-9a-f]{1,4}:){2}(?:[0-9a-f]{1,4}:[0-9a-f]{1,4}|(?:[0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9][0-9]|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])(?:\.(?:[0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9][0-9]|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])){3})|(?:(?:[0-9a-f]{1,4}:){0,3}[0-9a-f]{1,4})?::[0-9a-f]{1,4}:(?:[0-9a-f]{1,4}:[0-9a-f]{1,4}|(?:[0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9][0-9]|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])(?:\.(?:[0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9][0-9]|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])){3})|(?:(?:[0-9a-f]{1,4}:){0,4}[0-9a-f]{1,4})?::(?:[0-9a-f]{1,4}:[0-9a-f]{1,4}|(?:[0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9][0-9]|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])(?:\.(?:[0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9][0-9]|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])){3})|(?:(?:[0-9a-f]{1,4}:){0,5}[0-9a-f]{1,4})?::[0-9a-f]{1,4}|(?:(?:[0-9a-f]{1,4}:){0,6}[0-9a-f]{1,4})?::)|v[0-9a-f]+\.[-a-z0-9\._~!\$&'\(\)\*\+,;=:]+)\]|(?:[0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9][0-9]|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])(?:\.(?:[0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9][0-9]|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])){3}|(?:%[0-9a-f][0-9a-f]|[-a-z0-9\._~\x{A0}-\x{D7FF}\x{F900}-\x{FDCF}\x{FDF0}-\x{FFEF}\x{10000}-\x{1FFFD}\x{20000}-\x{2FFFD}\x{30000}-\x{3FFFD}\x{40000}-\x{4FFFD}\x{50000}-\x{5FFFD}\x{60000}-\x{6FFFD}\x{70000}-\x{7FFFD}\x{80000}-\x{8FFFD}\x{90000}-\x{9FFFD}\x{A0000}-\x{AFFFD}\x{B0000}-\x{BFFFD}\x{C0000}-\x{CFFFD}\x{D0000}-\x{DFFFD}\x{E1000}-\x{EFFFD}!\$&'\(\)\*\+,;=])*)(?::[0-9]*)?(?:\/(?:(?:%[0-9a-f][0-9a-f]|[-a-z0-9\._~\x{A0}-\x{D7FF}\x{F900}-\x{FDCF}\x{FDF0}-\x{FFEF}\x{10000}-\x{1FFFD}\x{20000}-\x{2FFFD}\x{30000}-\x{3FFFD}\x{40000}-\x{4FFFD}\x{50000}-\x{5FFFD}\x{60000}-\x{6FFFD}\x{70000}-\x{7FFFD}\x{80000}-\x{8FFFD}\x{90000}-\x{9FFFD}\x{A0000}-\x{AFFFD}\x{B0000}-\x{BFFFD}\x{C0000}-\x{CFFFD}\x{D0000}-\x{DFFFD}\x{E1000}-\x{EFFFD}!\$&'\(\)\*\+,;=:@]))*)*|\/(?:(?:(?:(?:%[0-9a-f][0-9a-f]|[-a-z0-9\._~\x{A0}-\x{D7FF}\x{F900}-\x{FDCF}\x{FDF0}-\x{FFEF}\x{10000}-\x{1FFFD}\x{20000}-\x{2FFFD}\x{30000}-\x{3FFFD}\x{40000}-\x{4FFFD}\x{50000}-\x{5FFFD}\x{60000}-\x{6FFFD}\x{70000}-\x{7FFFD}\x{80000}-\x{8FFFD}\x{90000}-\x{9FFFD}\x{A0000}-\x{AFFFD}\x{B0000}-\x{BFFFD}\x{C0000}-\x{CFFFD}\x{D0000}-\x{DFFFD}\x{E1000}-\x{EFFFD}!\$&'\(\)\*\+,;=:@]))+)(?:\/(?:(?:%[0-9a-f][0-9a-f]|[-a-z0-9\._~\x{A0}-\x{D7FF}\x{F900}-\x{FDCF}\x{FDF0}-\x{FFEF}\x{10000}-\x{1FFFD}\x{20000}-\x{2FFFD}\x{30000}-\x{3FFFD}\x{40000}-\x{4FFFD}\x{50000}-\x{5FFFD}\x{60000}-\x{6FFFD}\x{70000}-\x{7FFFD}\x{80000}-\x{8FFFD}\x{90000}-\x{9FFFD}\x{A0000}-\x{AFFFD}\x{B0000}-\x{BFFFD}\x{C0000}-\x{CFFFD}\x{D0000}-\x{DFFFD}\x{E1000}-\x{EFFFD}!\$&'\(\)\*\+,;=:@]))*)*)?|(?:(?:(?:%[0-9a-f][0-9a-f]|[-a-z0-9\._~\x{A0}-\x{D7FF}\x{F900}-\x{FDCF}\x{FDF0}-\x{FFEF}\x{10000}-\x{1FFFD}\x{20000}-\x{2FFFD}\x{30000}-\x{3FFFD}\x{40000}-\x{4FFFD}\x{50000}-\x{5FFFD}\x{60000}-\x{6FFFD}\x{70000}-\x{7FFFD}\x{80000}-\x{8FFFD}\x{90000}-\x{9FFFD}\x{A0000}-\x{AFFFD}\x{B0000}-\x{BFFFD}\x{C0000}-\x{CFFFD}\x{D0000}-\x{DFFFD}\x{E1000}-\x{EFFFD}!\$&'\(\)\*\+,;=:@]))+)(?:\/(?:(?:%[0-9a-f][0-9a-f]|[-a-z0-9\._~\x{A0}-\x{D7FF}\x{F900}-\x{FDCF}\x{FDF0}-\x{FFEF}\x{10000}-\x{1FFFD}\x{20000}-\x{2FFFD}\x{30000}-\x{3FFFD}\x{40000}-\x{4FFFD}\x{50000}-\x{5FFFD}\x{60000}-\x{6FFFD}\x{70000}-\x{7FFFD}\x{80000}-\x{8FFFD}\x{90000}-\x{9FFFD}\x{A0000}-\x{AFFFD}\x{B0000}-\x{BFFFD}\x{C0000}-\x{CFFFD}\x{D0000}-\x{DFFFD}\x{E1000}-\x{EFFFD}!\$&'\(\)\*\+,;=:@]))*)*|(?!(?:%[0-9a-f][0-9a-f]|[-a-z0-9\._~\x{A0}-\x{D7FF}\x{F900}-\x{FDCF}\x{FDF0}-\x{FFEF}\x{10000}-\x{1FFFD}\x{20000}-\x{2FFFD}\x{30000}-\x{3FFFD}\x{40000}-\x{4FFFD}\x{50000}-\x{5FFFD}\x{60000}-\x{6FFFD}\x{70000}-\x{7FFFD}\x{80000}-\x{8FFFD}\x{90000}-\x{9FFFD}\x{A0000}-\x{AFFFD}\x{B0000}-\x{BFFFD}\x{C0000}-\x{CFFFD}\x{D0000}-\x{DFFFD}\x{E1000}-\x{EFFFD}!\$&'\(\)\*\+,;=:@])))(?:\?(?:(?:%[0-9a-f][0-9a-f]|[-a-z0-9\._~\x{A0}-\x{D7FF}\x{F900}-\x{FDCF}\x{FDF0}-\x{FFEF}\x{10000}-\x{1FFFD}\x{20000}-\x{2FFFD}\x{30000}-\x{3FFFD}\x{40000}-\x{4FFFD}\x{50000}-\x{5FFFD}\x{60000}-\x{6FFFD}\x{70000}-\x{7FFFD}\x{80000}-\x{8FFFD}\x{90000}-\x{9FFFD}\x{A0000}-\x{AFFFD}\x{B0000}-\x{BFFFD}\x{C0000}-\x{CFFFD}\x{D0000}-\x{DFFFD}\x{E1000}-\x{EFFFD}!\$&'\(\)\*\+,;=:@])|[\x{E000}-\x{F8FF}\x{F0000}-\x{FFFFD}\x{100000}-\x{10FFFD}\/\?])*)?(?:\#(?:(?:%[0-9a-f][0-9a-f]|[-a-z0-9\._~\x{A0}-\x{D7FF}\x{F900}-\x{FDCF}\x{FDF0}-\x{FFEF}\x{10000}-\x{1FFFD}\x{20000}-\x{2FFFD}\x{30000}-\x{3FFFD}\x{40000}-\x{4FFFD}\x{50000}-\x{5FFFD}\x{60000}-\x{6FFFD}\x{70000}-\x{7FFFD}\x{80000}-\x{8FFFD}\x{90000}-\x{9FFFD}\x{A0000}-\x{AFFFD}\x{B0000}-\x{BFFFD}\x{C0000}-\x{CFFFD}\x{D0000}-\x{DFFFD}\x{E1000}-\x{EFFFD}!\$&'\(\)\*\+,;=:@])|[\/\?])*)?$/i
```

To also allow relative IRIs:

```
/^(?:[a-z](?:[-a-z0-9\+\.])*:(?:\/\/(?:(?:%[0-9a-f][0-9a-f]|[-a-z0-9\._~\x{A0}-\x{D7FF}\x{F900}-\x{FDCF}\x{FDF0}-\x{FFEF}\x{10000}-\x{1FFFD}\x{20000}-\x{2FFFD}\x{30000}-\x{3FFFD}\x{40000}-\x{4FFFD}\x{50000}-\x{5FFFD}\x{60000}-\x{6FFFD}\x{70000}-\x{7FFFD}\x{80000}-\x{8FFFD}\x{90000}-\x{9FFFD}\x{A0000}-\x{AFFFD}\x{B0000}-\x{BFFFD}\x{C0000}-\x{CFFFD}\x{D0000}-\x{DFFFD}\x{E1000}-\x{EFFFD}!\$&'\(\)\*\+,;=:])*@)?(?:\[(?:(?:(?:[0-9a-f]{1,4}:){6}(?:[0-9a-f]{1,4}:[0-9a-f]{1,4}|(?:[0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9][0-9]|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])(?:\.(?:[0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9][0-9]|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])){3})|::(?:[0-9a-f]{1,4}:){5}(?:[0-9a-f]{1,4}:[0-9a-f]{1,4}|(?:[0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9][0-9]|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])(?:\.(?:[0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9][0-9]|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])){3})|(?:[0-9a-f]{1,4})?::(?:[0-9a-f]{1,4}:){4}(?:[0-9a-f]{1,4}:[0-9a-f]{1,4}|(?:[0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9][0-9]|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])(?:\.(?:[0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9][0-9]|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])){3})|(?:(?:[0-9a-f]{1,4}:){0,1}[0-9a-f]{1,4})?::(?:[0-9a-f]{1,4}:){3}(?:[0-9a-f]{1,4}:[0-9a-f]{1,4}|(?:[0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9][0-9]|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])(?:\.(?:[0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9][0-9]|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])){3})|(?:(?:[0-9a-f]{1,4}:){0,2}[0-9a-f]{1,4})?::(?:[0-9a-f]{1,4}:){2}(?:[0-9a-f]{1,4}:[0-9a-f]{1,4}|(?:[0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9][0-9]|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])(?:\.(?:[0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9][0-9]|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])){3})|(?:(?:[0-9a-f]{1,4}:){0,3}[0-9a-f]{1,4})?::[0-9a-f]{1,4}:(?:[0-9a-f]{1,4}:[0-9a-f]{1,4}|(?:[0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9][0-9]|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])(?:\.(?:[0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9][0-9]|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])){3})|(?:(?:[0-9a-f]{1,4}:){0,4}[0-9a-f]{1,4})?::(?:[0-9a-f]{1,4}:[0-9a-f]{1,4}|(?:[0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9][0-9]|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])(?:\.(?:[0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9][0-9]|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])){3})|(?:(?:[0-9a-f]{1,4}:){0,5}[0-9a-f]{1,4})?::[0-9a-f]{1,4}|(?:(?:[0-9a-f]{1,4}:){0,6}[0-9a-f]{1,4})?::)|v[0-9a-f]+\.[-a-z0-9\._~!\$&'\(\)\*\+,;=:]+)\]|(?:[0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9][0-9]|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])(?:\.(?:[0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9][0-9]|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])){3}|(?:%[0-9a-f][0-9a-f]|[-a-z0-9\._~\x{A0}-\x{D7FF}\x{F900}-\x{FDCF}\x{FDF0}-\x{FFEF}\x{10000}-\x{1FFFD}\x{20000}-\x{2FFFD}\x{30000}-\x{3FFFD}\x{40000}-\x{4FFFD}\x{50000}-\x{5FFFD}\x{60000}-\x{6FFFD}\x{70000}-\x{7FFFD}\x{80000}-\x{8FFFD}\x{90000}-\x{9FFFD}\x{A0000}-\x{AFFFD}\x{B0000}-\x{BFFFD}\x{C0000}-\x{CFFFD}\x{D0000}-\x{DFFFD}\x{E1000}-\x{EFFFD}!\$&'\(\)\*\+,;=])*)(?::[0-9]*)?(?:\/(?:(?:%[0-9a-f][0-9a-f]|[-a-z0-9\._~\x{A0}-\x{D7FF}\x{F900}-\x{FDCF}\x{FDF0}-\x{FFEF}\x{10000}-\x{1FFFD}\x{20000}-\x{2FFFD}\x{30000}-\x{3FFFD}\x{40000}-\x{4FFFD}\x{50000}-\x{5FFFD}\x{60000}-\x{6FFFD}\x{70000}-\x{7FFFD}\x{80000}-\x{8FFFD}\x{90000}-\x{9FFFD}\x{A0000}-\x{AFFFD}\x{B0000}-\x{BFFFD}\x{C0000}-\x{CFFFD}\x{D0000}-\x{DFFFD}\x{E1000}-\x{EFFFD}!\$&'\(\)\*\+,;=:@]))*)*|\/(?:(?:(?:(?:%[0-9a-f][0-9a-f]|[-a-z0-9\._~\x{A0}-\x{D7FF}\x{F900}-\x{FDCF}\x{FDF0}-\x{FFEF}\x{10000}-\x{1FFFD}\x{20000}-\x{2FFFD}\x{30000}-\x{3FFFD}\x{40000}-\x{4FFFD}\x{50000}-\x{5FFFD}\x{60000}-\x{6FFFD}\x{70000}-\x{7FFFD}\x{80000}-\x{8FFFD}\x{90000}-\x{9FFFD}\x{A0000}-\x{AFFFD}\x{B0000}-\x{BFFFD}\x{C0000}-\x{CFFFD}\x{D0000}-\x{DFFFD}\x{E1000}-\x{EFFFD}!\$&'\(\)\*\+,;=:@]))+)(?:\/(?:(?:%[0-9a-f][0-9a-f]|[-a-z0-9\._~\x{A0}-\x{D7FF}\x{F900}-\x{FDCF}\x{FDF0}-\x{FFEF}\x{10000}-\x{1FFFD}\x{20000}-\x{2FFFD}\x{30000}-\x{3FFFD}\x{40000}-\x{4FFFD}\x{50000}-\x{5FFFD}\x{60000}-\x{6FFFD}\x{70000}-\x{7FFFD}\x{80000}-\x{8FFFD}\x{90000}-\x{9FFFD}\x{A0000}-\x{AFFFD}\x{B0000}-\x{BFFFD}\x{C0000}-\x{CFFFD}\x{D0000}-\x{DFFFD}\x{E1000}-\x{EFFFD}!\$&'\(\)\*\+,;=:@]))*)*)?|(?:(?:(?:%[0-9a-f][0-9a-f]|[-a-z0-9\._~\x{A0}-\x{D7FF}\x{F900}-\x{FDCF}\x{FDF0}-\x{FFEF}\x{10000}-\x{1FFFD}\x{20000}-\x{2FFFD}\x{30000}-\x{3FFFD}\x{40000}-\x{4FFFD}\x{50000}-\x{5FFFD}\x{60000}-\x{6FFFD}\x{70000}-\x{7FFFD}\x{80000}-\x{8FFFD}\x{90000}-\x{9FFFD}\x{A0000}-\x{AFFFD}\x{B0000}-\x{BFFFD}\x{C0000}-\x{CFFFD}\x{D0000}-\x{DFFFD}\x{E1000}-\x{EFFFD}!\$&'\(\)\*\+,;=:@]))+)(?:\/(?:(?:%[0-9a-f][0-9a-f]|[-a-z0-9\._~\x{A0}-\x{D7FF}\x{F900}-\x{FDCF}\x{FDF0}-\x{FFEF}\x{10000}-\x{1FFFD}\x{20000}-\x{2FFFD}\x{30000}-\x{3FFFD}\x{40000}-\x{4FFFD}\x{50000}-\x{5FFFD}\x{60000}-\x{6FFFD}\x{70000}-\x{7FFFD}\x{80000}-\x{8FFFD}\x{90000}-\x{9FFFD}\x{A0000}-\x{AFFFD}\x{B0000}-\x{BFFFD}\x{C0000}-\x{CFFFD}\x{D0000}-\x{DFFFD}\x{E1000}-\x{EFFFD}!\$&'\(\)\*\+,;=:@]))*)*|(?!(?:%[0-9a-f][0-9a-f]|[-a-z0-9\._~\x{A0}-\x{D7FF}\x{F900}-\x{FDCF}\x{FDF0}-\x{FFEF}\x{10000}-\x{1FFFD}\x{20000}-\x{2FFFD}\x{30000}-\x{3FFFD}\x{40000}-\x{4FFFD}\x{50000}-\x{5FFFD}\x{60000}-\x{6FFFD}\x{70000}-\x{7FFFD}\x{80000}-\x{8FFFD}\x{90000}-\x{9FFFD}\x{A0000}-\x{AFFFD}\x{B0000}-\x{BFFFD}\x{C0000}-\x{CFFFD}\x{D0000}-\x{DFFFD}\x{E1000}-\x{EFFFD}!\$&'\(\)\*\+,;=:@])))(?:\?(?:(?:%[0-9a-f][0-9a-f]|[-a-z0-9\._~\x{A0}-\x{D7FF}\x{F900}-\x{FDCF}\x{FDF0}-\x{FFEF}\x{10000}-\x{1FFFD}\x{20000}-\x{2FFFD}\x{30000}-\x{3FFFD}\x{40000}-\x{4FFFD}\x{50000}-\x{5FFFD}\x{60000}-\x{6FFFD}\x{70000}-\x{7FFFD}\x{80000}-\x{8FFFD}\x{90000}-\x{9FFFD}\x{A0000}-\x{AFFFD}\x{B0000}-\x{BFFFD}\x{C0000}-\x{CFFFD}\x{D0000}-\x{DFFFD}\x{E1000}-\x{EFFFD}!\$&'\(\)\*\+,;=:@])|[\x{E000}-\x{F8FF}\x{F0000}-\x{FFFFD}\x{100000}-\x{10FFFD}\/\?])*)?(?:\#(?:(?:%[0-9a-f][0-9a-f]|[-a-z0-9\._~\x{A0}-\x{D7FF}\x{F900}-\x{FDCF}\x{FDF0}-\x{FFEF}\x{10000}-\x{1FFFD}\x{20000}-\x{2FFFD}\x{30000}-\x{3FFFD}\x{40000}-\x{4FFFD}\x{50000}-\x{5FFFD}\x{60000}-\x{6FFFD}\x{70000}-\x{7FFFD}\x{80000}-\x{8FFFD}\x{90000}-\x{9FFFD}\x{A0000}-\x{AFFFD}\x{B0000}-\x{BFFFD}\x{C0000}-\x{CFFFD}\x{D0000}-\x{DFFFD}\x{E1000}-\x{EFFFD}!\$&'\(\)\*\+,;=:@])|[\/\?])*)?|(?:\/\/(?:(?:%[0-9a-f][0-9a-f]|[-a-z0-9\._~\x{A0}-\x{D7FF}\x{F900}-\x{FDCF}\x{FDF0}-\x{FFEF}\x{10000}-\x{1FFFD}\x{20000}-\x{2FFFD}\x{30000}-\x{3FFFD}\x{40000}-\x{4FFFD}\x{50000}-\x{5FFFD}\x{60000}-\x{6FFFD}\x{70000}-\x{7FFFD}\x{80000}-\x{8FFFD}\x{90000}-\x{9FFFD}\x{A0000}-\x{AFFFD}\x{B0000}-\x{BFFFD}\x{C0000}-\x{CFFFD}\x{D0000}-\x{DFFFD}\x{E1000}-\x{EFFFD}!\$&'\(\)\*\+,;=:])*@)?(?:\[(?:(?:(?:[0-9a-f]{1,4}:){6}(?:[0-9a-f]{1,4}:[0-9a-f]{1,4}|(?:[0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9][0-9]|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])(?:\.(?:[0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9][0-9]|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])){3})|::(?:[0-9a-f]{1,4}:){5}(?:[0-9a-f]{1,4}:[0-9a-f]{1,4}|(?:[0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9][0-9]|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])(?:\.(?:[0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9][0-9]|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])){3})|(?:[0-9a-f]{1,4})?::(?:[0-9a-f]{1,4}:){4}(?:[0-9a-f]{1,4}:[0-9a-f]{1,4}|(?:[0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9][0-9]|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])(?:\.(?:[0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9][0-9]|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])){3})|(?:(?:[0-9a-f]{1,4}:){0,1}[0-9a-f]{1,4})?::(?:[0-9a-f]{1,4}:){3}(?:[0-9a-f]{1,4}:[0-9a-f]{1,4}|(?:[0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9][0-9]|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])(?:\.(?:[0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9][0-9]|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])){3})|(?:(?:[0-9a-f]{1,4}:){0,2}[0-9a-f]{1,4})?::(?:[0-9a-f]{1,4}:){2}(?:[0-9a-f]{1,4}:[0-9a-f]{1,4}|(?:[0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9][0-9]|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])(?:\.(?:[0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9][0-9]|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])){3})|(?:(?:[0-9a-f]{1,4}:){0,3}[0-9a-f]{1,4})?::[0-9a-f]{1,4}:(?:[0-9a-f]{1,4}:[0-9a-f]{1,4}|(?:[0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9][0-9]|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])(?:\.(?:[0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9][0-9]|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])){3})|(?:(?:[0-9a-f]{1,4}:){0,4}[0-9a-f]{1,4})?::(?:[0-9a-f]{1,4}:[0-9a-f]{1,4}|(?:[0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9][0-9]|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])(?:\.(?:[0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9][0-9]|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])){3})|(?:(?:[0-9a-f]{1,4}:){0,5}[0-9a-f]{1,4})?::[0-9a-f]{1,4}|(?:(?:[0-9a-f]{1,4}:){0,6}[0-9a-f]{1,4})?::)|v[0-9a-f]+\.[-a-z0-9\._~!\$&'\(\)\*\+,;=:]+)\]|(?:[0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9][0-9]|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])(?:\.(?:[0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9][0-9]|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])){3}|(?:%[0-9a-f][0-9a-f]|[-a-z0-9\._~\x{A0}-\x{D7FF}\x{F900}-\x{FDCF}\x{FDF0}-\x{FFEF}\x{10000}-\x{1FFFD}\x{20000}-\x{2FFFD}\x{30000}-\x{3FFFD}\x{40000}-\x{4FFFD}\x{50000}-\x{5FFFD}\x{60000}-\x{6FFFD}\x{70000}-\x{7FFFD}\x{80000}-\x{8FFFD}\x{90000}-\x{9FFFD}\x{A0000}-\x{AFFFD}\x{B0000}-\x{BFFFD}\x{C0000}-\x{CFFFD}\x{D0000}-\x{DFFFD}\x{E1000}-\x{EFFFD}!\$&'\(\)\*\+,;=])*)(?::[0-9]*)?(?:\/(?:(?:%[0-9a-f][0-9a-f]|[-a-z0-9\._~\x{A0}-\x{D7FF}\x{F900}-\x{FDCF}\x{FDF0}-\x{FFEF}\x{10000}-\x{1FFFD}\x{20000}-\x{2FFFD}\x{30000}-\x{3FFFD}\x{40000}-\x{4FFFD}\x{50000}-\x{5FFFD}\x{60000}-\x{6FFFD}\x{70000}-\x{7FFFD}\x{80000}-\x{8FFFD}\x{90000}-\x{9FFFD}\x{A0000}-\x{AFFFD}\x{B0000}-\x{BFFFD}\x{C0000}-\x{CFFFD}\x{D0000}-\x{DFFFD}\x{E1000}-\x{EFFFD}!\$&'\(\)\*\+,;=:@]))*)*|\/(?:(?:(?:(?:%[0-9a-f][0-9a-f]|[-a-z0-9\._~\x{A0}-\x{D7FF}\x{F900}-\x{FDCF}\x{FDF0}-\x{FFEF}\x{10000}-\x{1FFFD}\x{20000}-\x{2FFFD}\x{30000}-\x{3FFFD}\x{40000}-\x{4FFFD}\x{50000}-\x{5FFFD}\x{60000}-\x{6FFFD}\x{70000}-\x{7FFFD}\x{80000}-\x{8FFFD}\x{90000}-\x{9FFFD}\x{A0000}-\x{AFFFD}\x{B0000}-\x{BFFFD}\x{C0000}-\x{CFFFD}\x{D0000}-\x{DFFFD}\x{E1000}-\x{EFFFD}!\$&'\(\)\*\+,;=:@]))+)(?:\/(?:(?:%[0-9a-f][0-9a-f]|[-a-z0-9\._~\x{A0}-\x{D7FF}\x{F900}-\x{FDCF}\x{FDF0}-\x{FFEF}\x{10000}-\x{1FFFD}\x{20000}-\x{2FFFD}\x{30000}-\x{3FFFD}\x{40000}-\x{4FFFD}\x{50000}-\x{5FFFD}\x{60000}-\x{6FFFD}\x{70000}-\x{7FFFD}\x{80000}-\x{8FFFD}\x{90000}-\x{9FFFD}\x{A0000}-\x{AFFFD}\x{B0000}-\x{BFFFD}\x{C0000}-\x{CFFFD}\x{D0000}-\x{DFFFD}\x{E1000}-\x{EFFFD}!\$&'\(\)\*\+,;=:@]))*)*)?|(?:(?:%[0-9a-f][0-9a-f]|[-a-z0-9\._~\x{A0}-\x{D7FF}\x{F900}-\x{FDCF}\x{FDF0}-\x{FFEF}\x{10000}-\x{1FFFD}\x{20000}-\x{2FFFD}\x{30000}-\x{3FFFD}\x{40000}-\x{4FFFD}\x{50000}-\x{5FFFD}\x{60000}-\x{6FFFD}\x{70000}-\x{7FFFD}\x{80000}-\x{8FFFD}\x{90000}-\x{9FFFD}\x{A0000}-\x{AFFFD}\x{B0000}-\x{BFFFD}\x{C0000}-\x{CFFFD}\x{D0000}-\x{DFFFD}\x{E1000}-\x{EFFFD}!\$&'\(\)\*\+,;=@])+)(?:\/(?:(?:%[0-9a-f][0-9a-f]|[-a-z0-9\._~\x{A0}-\x{D7FF}\x{F900}-\x{FDCF}\x{FDF0}-\x{FFEF}\x{10000}-\x{1FFFD}\x{20000}-\x{2FFFD}\x{30000}-\x{3FFFD}\x{40000}-\x{4FFFD}\x{50000}-\x{5FFFD}\x{60000}-\x{6FFFD}\x{70000}-\x{7FFFD}\x{80000}-\x{8FFFD}\x{90000}-\x{9FFFD}\x{A0000}-\x{AFFFD}\x{B0000}-\x{BFFFD}\x{C0000}-\x{CFFFD}\x{D0000}-\x{DFFFD}\x{E1000}-\x{EFFFD}!\$&'\(\)\*\+,;=:@]))*)*|(?!(?:%[0-9a-f][0-9a-f]|[-a-z0-9\._~\x{A0}-\x{D7FF}\x{F900}-\x{FDCF}\x{FDF0}-\x{FFEF}\x{10000}-\x{1FFFD}\x{20000}-\x{2FFFD}\x{30000}-\x{3FFFD}\x{40000}-\x{4FFFD}\x{50000}-\x{5FFFD}\x{60000}-\x{6FFFD}\x{70000}-\x{7FFFD}\x{80000}-\x{8FFFD}\x{90000}-\x{9FFFD}\x{A0000}-\x{AFFFD}\x{B0000}-\x{BFFFD}\x{C0000}-\x{CFFFD}\x{D0000}-\x{DFFFD}\x{E1000}-\x{EFFFD}!\$&'\(\)\*\+,;=:@])))(?:\?(?:(?:%[0-9a-f][0-9a-f]|[-a-z0-9\._~\x{A0}-\x{D7FF}\x{F900}-\x{FDCF}\x{FDF0}-\x{FFEF}\x{10000}-\x{1FFFD}\x{20000}-\x{2FFFD}\x{30000}-\x{3FFFD}\x{40000}-\x{4FFFD}\x{50000}-\x{5FFFD}\x{60000}-\x{6FFFD}\x{70000}-\x{7FFFD}\x{80000}-\x{8FFFD}\x{90000}-\x{9FFFD}\x{A0000}-\x{AFFFD}\x{B0000}-\x{BFFFD}\x{C0000}-\x{CFFFD}\x{D0000}-\x{DFFFD}\x{E1000}-\x{EFFFD}!\$&'\(\)\*\+,;=:@])|[\x{E000}-\x{F8FF}\x{F0000}-\x{FFFFD}\x{100000}-\x{10FFFD}\/\?])*)?(?:\#(?:(?:%[0-9a-f][0-9a-f]|[-a-z0-9\._~\x{A0}-\x{D7FF}\x{F900}-\x{FDCF}\x{FDF0}-\x{FFEF}\x{10000}-\x{1FFFD}\x{20000}-\x{2FFFD}\x{30000}-\x{3FFFD}\x{40000}-\x{4FFFD}\x{50000}-\x{5FFFD}\x{60000}-\x{6FFFD}\x{70000}-\x{7FFFD}\x{80000}-\x{8FFFD}\x{90000}-\x{9FFFD}\x{A0000}-\x{AFFFD}\x{B0000}-\x{BFFFD}\x{C0000}-\x{CFFFD}\x{D0000}-\x{DFFFD}\x{E1000}-\x{EFFFD}!\$&'\(\)\*\+,;=:@])|[\/\?])*)?)$/i
```

How they were compiled (in PHP):

```php
<?php

/* Regex convenience functions (character class, non-capturing group) */
function cc($str, $suffix = '', $negate = false) {
    return '[' . ($negate ? '^' : '') . $str . ']' . $suffix;
}
function ncg($str, $suffix = '') {
    return '(?:' . $str . ')' . $suffix;
}

/* Preserved from RFC3986 */

$ALPHA = 'a-z';
$DIGIT = '0-9';
$HEXDIG = $DIGIT . 'a-f';

$sub_delims = '!\\$&\'\\(\\)\\*\\+,;=';
$gen_delims = ':\\/\\?\\#\\[\\]@';
$reserved = $gen_delims . $sub_delims;
$unreserved = '-' . $ALPHA . $DIGIT . '\\._~';

$pct_encoded = '%' . cc($HEXDIG) . cc($HEXDIG);

$dec_octet = ncg(implode('|', array(
    cc($DIGIT),
    cc('1-9') . cc($DIGIT),
    '1' . cc($DIGIT) . cc($DIGIT),
    '2' . cc('0-4') . cc($DIGIT),
    '25' . cc('0-5')
)));

$IPv4address = $dec_octet . ncg('\\.' . $dec_octet, '{3}');

$h16 = cc($HEXDIG, '{1,4}');
$ls32 = ncg($h16 . ':' . $h16 . '|' . $IPv4address);

$IPv6address = ncg(implode('|', array(
    ncg($h16 . ':', '{6}') . $ls32,
    '::' . ncg($h16 . ':', '{5}') . $ls32,
    ncg($h16, '?') . '::' . ncg($h16 . ':', '{4}') . $ls32,
    ncg($h16 . ':' . $h16, '?') . '::' . ncg($h16 . ':', '{3}') . $ls32,
    ncg(ncg($h16 . ':', '{0,2}') . $h16, '?') . '::' . ncg($h16 . ':', '{2}') . $ls32,
    ncg(ncg($h16 . ':', '{0,3}') . $h16, '?') . '::' . $h16 . ':' . $ls32,
    ncg(ncg($h16 . ':', '{0,4}') . $h16, '?') . '::' . $ls32,
    ncg(ncg($h16 . ':', '{0,5}') . $h16, '?') . '::' . $h16,
    ncg(ncg($h16 . ':', '{0,6}') . $h16, '?') . '::',
)));

$IPvFuture = 'v' . cc($HEXDIG, '+') . cc($unreserved . $sub_delims . ':', '+');

$IP_literal = '\\[' . ncg(implode('|', array($IPv6address, $IPvFuture))) . '\\]';

$port = cc($DIGIT, '*');

$scheme = cc($ALPHA) . ncg(cc('-' . $ALPHA . $DIGIT . '\\+\\.'), '*');

/* New or changed in RFC3987 */

$iprivate = '\x{E000}-\x{F8FF}\x{F0000}-\x{FFFFD}\x{100000}-\x{10FFFD}';

$ucschar = '\x{A0}-\x{D7FF}\x{F900}-\x{FDCF}\x{FDF0}-\x{FFEF}' .
    '\x{10000}-\x{1FFFD}\x{20000}-\x{2FFFD}\x{30000}-\x{3FFFD}' .
    '\x{40000}-\x{4FFFD}\x{50000}-\x{5FFFD}\x{60000}-\x{6FFFD}' .
    '\x{70000}-\x{7FFFD}\x{80000}-\x{8FFFD}\x{90000}-\x{9FFFD}' .
    '\x{A0000}-\x{AFFFD}\x{B0000}-\x{BFFFD}\x{C0000}-\x{CFFFD}' .
    '\x{D0000}-\x{DFFFD}\x{E1000}-\x{EFFFD}';

$iunreserved = '-' . $ALPHA . $DIGIT . '\\._~' . $ucschar;

$ipchar = ncg($pct_encoded . '|' . cc($iunreserved . $sub_delims . ':@'));

$ifragment = ncg($ipchar . '|' . cc('\\/\\?'), '*');

$iquery = ncg($ipchar . '|' . cc($iprivate . '\\/\\?'), '*');

$isegment_nz_nc = ncg($pct_encoded . '|' . cc($iunreserved . $sub_delims . '@'), '+');
$isegment_nz = ncg($ipchar, '+');
$isegment = ncg($ipchar, '*');

$ipath_empty = '(?!' . $ipchar . ')';
$ipath_rootless = ncg($isegment_nz) . ncg('\\/' . $isegment, '*');
$ipath_noscheme = ncg($isegment_nz_nc) . ncg('\\/' . $isegment, '*');
$ipath_absolute = '\\/' . ncg($ipath_rootless, '?'); // Spec says isegment-nz *( "/" isegment )
$ipath_abempty = ncg('\\/' . $isegment, '*');

$ipath = ncg(implode('|', array(
    $ipath_abempty,
    $ipath_absolute,
    $ipath_noscheme,
    $ipath_rootless,
    $ipath_empty
))) . ')';

$ireg_name = ncg($pct_encoded . '|' . cc($iunreserved . $sub_delims . '@'), '*');

$ihost = ncg(implode('|', array($IP_literal, $IPv4address, $ireg_name)));
$iuserinfo = ncg($pct_encoded . '|' . cc($iunreserved . $sub_delims . ':'), '*');
$iauthority = ncg($iuserinfo . '@', '?') . $ihost . ncg(':' . $port, '?');

$irelative_part = ncg(implode('|', array(
    '\\/\\/' . $iauthority . $ipath_abempty . '',
    '' . $ipath_absolute . '',
    '' . $ipath_noscheme . '',
    '' . $ipath_empty . ''
)));

$irelative_ref = $irelative_part . ncg('\\?' . $iquery, '?') . ncg('\\#' . $ifragment, '?');

$ihier_part = ncg(implode('|', array(
    '\\/\\/' . $iauthority . $ipath_abempty . '',
    '' . $ipath_absolute . '',
    '' . $ipath_rootless . '',
    '' . $ipath_empty . ''
)));

$absolute_IRI = $scheme . ':' . $ihier_part . ncg('\\?' . $iquery, '?');

$IRI = $scheme . ':' . $ihier_part . ncg('\\?' . $iquery, '?') . ncg('\\#' . $ifragment, '?');

$IRI_reference = ncg($IRI . '|' . $irelative_ref);
```

Edit 7 March 2011: Because of the way PHP handles backslashes in quoted strings, these are unusable by default. You'll need to double-escape backslashes except where the backslash has a special meaning in regex. You can do that this way:

```php
$escape_backslash = '/(?<!\\)\\(?![\[\]\\\^\$\.\|\*\+\(\)QEnrtaefvdwsDWSbAZzB1-9GX]|x\{[0-9a-f]{1,4}\}|\c[A-Z]|)/';
$absolute_IRI = preg_replace($escape_backslash, '\\\\', $absolute_IRI);
$IRI = preg_replace($escape_backslash, '\\\\', $IRI);
$IRI_reference = preg_replace($escape_backslash, '\\\\', $IRI_reference);
```

Comment: If you think that's bad, you should see the one for e-mail: http://ex-parrot.com/~pdw/Mail-RFC822-Address.html

Comment: @Gumbo, it's allowed in the spec and used in URI implementations for HTTP applications. It's discouraged (for obvious reasons) but perfectly valid and should be anticipated. Most (if not all?) browsers sometimes translate HTTP authentication into the URL for subsequent access.

Comment: I got this `Parse failure: Invalid regular expression:` in nodeJS... : / any ideas?

Comment: @mesqueeb to adapt this regexp for JS I had to 1) replace `\x` character classes with `\u` , 2) replace 2-digit unicode referencese with 4-digit `\u{A0}` => `\u{00A0}`, 3) use `u` flag to support `\u{xxxx}` format, 4) remove escaping before `#` character

Answer (score 191):

I've just written up a blog post for a great solution for recognizing URLs in most used formats such as:

- `www.google.com`
- `http://www.google.com`
- `mailto:somebody@google.com`
- `somebody@google.com`
- `www.url-with-querystring.com/?url=has-querystring`

The regular expression used is:

```
/((([A-Za-z]{3,9}:(?:\/\/)?)(?:[-;:&=\+\$,\w]+@)?[A-Za-z0-9.-]+|(?:www.|[-;:&=\+\$,\w]+@)[A-Za-z0-9.-]+)((?:\/[\+~%\/.\w-_]*)?\??(?:[-\+=&;%@.\w_]*)#?(?:[\w]*))?)/
```

Comment: That one also works, but it's missing support for the port number (useful in debugging).
Modified would be `/((([A-Za-z]{3,9}:(?:\/\/)?)(?:[-;:&=\+\$,\w]+@)?[A-Za-z0-9.-]+(:[0-9]+)?|(?:www.|[-;:&=\+\$,\w]+@)[A-Za-z0-9.-]+)((?:\/[\+~%\/.\w-_]*)?\??(?:[-\+=&;%@.\w_]*)#?(?:[\w]*))?)/`

Comment: Got another match mate:
`width:210px;` and `margin:3px`

Comment: doesn't capture `google.com`

Comment: @MAC google.com is not a url

Comment: "- You cannot create a range with shorthand escape sequences" according to https://regex101.com/

Comment: If it matches `www.google.com`, it should match `google.com`. How is it any different?

Comment: Why is this considered a proper test? This is passing "https://google.", that is not valid.

Comment: regex101.com I used Java language, it works well

Comment: the regex shared above giving the pattern error

Answer (score 91):

What platform? If using .NET, use [`System.Uri.TryCreate`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.trycreate), not a regex.

For example:

```
static bool IsValidUrl(string urlString)
{
    Uri uri;
    return Uri.TryCreate(urlString, UriKind.Absolute, out uri)
        && (uri.Scheme == Uri.UriSchemeHttp
         || uri.Scheme == Uri.UriSchemeHttps
         || uri.Scheme == Uri.UriSchemeFtp
         || uri.Scheme == Uri.UriSchemeMailto
            /*...*/);
}

// In test fixture...

[Test]
void IsValidUrl_Test()
{
    Assert.True(IsValidUrl("http://www.example.com"));
    Assert.False(IsValidUrl("javascript:alert('xss')"));
    Assert.False(IsValidUrl(""));
    Assert.False(IsValidUrl(null));
}
```

(Thanks to [@Yoshi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/450141/yoshi) for the tip about `javascript:`)

Comment: how would you use system.uri to check for a valid url?

Comment: Uri.TryCreate() returns true if it's valid

Comment: A HUGE warning to anyone who uses this technique: System.Uri correctly accepts `javascript: alert('blah')`.  You need to do further validation on [Uri.Scheme](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.scheme.aspx) to confirm the http/https/ftp protocol is being used, otherwise if such a URL is inserted into your ASP.NET pages' HTML as a link, **your users are vulnerable to XSS attacks**.

Comment: Notably, Uri.TryCreate returns true for empty strings as well. It appears that TryCreate isn't very effective...

Comment: what if I need a regex to do server/client-side in an ASP.NET MVC app? How would this help me on the client?

Comment: For .Net, use `Uri.IsWellFormedUriString()`

Comment: -1 for a few reasons: 1. Doesn't answer the original question, at all. 2. Puts an undue amount of faith in a black box system that according to these comments doesn't even work remotely as well as the regex examples provided.

Comment: @rw-nandemo: I would argument a *mile-long* RegEx-String isn't less of a black box than an official and probably thoroughly real-world-tested .NET API. (Also see [Andy Lester's answer below](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18724720/2822719))

Comment: @DuncanSmart I like your approach. Also, it would be interesting to go even further and make it event simpler and language agnostic. 

If you only accept public URLs and only if they are available, it would be interesting to try to do an actual request to the URL and if everything is fine to accept it, otherwise it means is not valid.

Comment: ```Uri.IsWellFormedUriString()``` fails for IP address with port, such as ```10.1.20.1:8080``` so I don't see it as a suitable alternative in .NET. The regex approach seems more flexible. Specific use-case is also important. For instance, I want a validator for URIs that may be a host/IP with port and where the user may or may not specify the scheme, and only HTTP or HTTPS schemes are accepted - and so this is certainly not the standards-based URI check. I therefore believe people should evaluate available regex or deduce a suitable one for their use-case.

Answer (score 79):

Mathias Bynens has a great article on the best comparison of a lot of regular expressions: [In search of the perfect URL validation regex](https://mathiasbynens.be/demo/url-regex)

[The best one posted](https://gist.github.com/729294) is a little long, but it matches just about anything you can throw at it.

#### JavaScript version

```
/^(?:(?:(?:https?|ftp):)?\/\/)(?:\S+(?::\S*)?@)?(?:(?!(?:10|127)(?:\.\d{1,3}){3})(?!(?:169\.254|192\.168)(?:\.\d{1,3}){2})(?!172\.(?:1[6-9]|2\d|3[0-1])(?:\.\d{1,3}){2})(?:[1-9]\d?|1\d\d|2[01]\d|22[0-3])(?:\.(?:1?\d{1,2}|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])){2}(?:\.(?:[1-9]\d?|1\d\d|2[0-4]\d|25[0-4]))|(?:(?:[a-z0-9\u00a1-\uffff][a-z0-9\u00a1-\uffff_-]{0,62})?[a-z0-9\u00a1-\uffff]\.)+(?:[a-z\u00a1-\uffff]{2,}\.?))(?::\d{2,5})?(?:[/?#]\S*)?$/i
```

#### PHP version (uses `%` symbol as delimiter)

```
%^(?:(?:(?:https?|ftp):)?\/\/)(?:\S+(?::\S*)?@)?(?:(?!(?:10|127)(?:\.\d{1,3}){3})(?!(?:169\.254|192\.168)(?:\.\d{1,3}){2})(?!172\.(?:1[6-9]|2\d|3[0-1])(?:\.\d{1,3}){2})(?:[1-9]\d?|1\d\d|2[01]\d|22[0-3])(?:\.(?:1?\d{1,2}|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])){2}(?:\.(?:[1-9]\d?|1\d\d|2[0-4]\d|25[0-4]))|(?:(?:[a-z0-9\x{00a1}-\x{ffff}][a-z0-9\x{00a1}-\x{ffff}_-]{0,62})?[a-z0-9\x{00a1}-\x{ffff}]\.)+(?:[a-z\x{00a1}-\x{ffff}]{2,}\.?))(?::\d{2,5})?(?:[/?#]\S*)?$%iuS
```

Comment: For preg_match use with PHP use


`%^(?:(?:https?|ftp)://)(?:\S+(?::\S*)?@|\d{1,3}(?:\.\d{1,3}){3}|(?:(?:[a-z\d\x{00a1}-\x{ffff}]+-?)*[a-z\d\x{00a1}-\x{ffff}]+)(?:\.(?:[a-z\d\x{00a1}-\x{ffff}]+-?)*[a-z\d\x{00a1}-\x{ffff}]+)*(?:\.[a-z\x{00a1}-\x{ffff}]{2,6}))(?::\d+)?(?:[^\s]*)?$%iu`

Comment: On that page, I prefer stephenhay's solution, because it's 38 chars instead of 502!

Comment: Also doesn't allow for IP addresses

Comment: give valid (slash slash) : //www.2test.com/

Comment: I tested some JavaScript regular expression URL testers. The above Kril/nhahtdh tester came out the best, with no false negatives and only one false positive, namely http://www.foo.bar./. Interestingly, the Diego Perini original has the same error. Test results posted at http://pagenotes.com/url%20tester.htm

Comment: @MattFletcher what do you mean exactly by "doesn't allow for IP addresses?" I found that https://255.255.255.255 works for example?

Comment: There are valid protocols other than https and ftp. Standard http, for one, also gopher, many many others.

Comment: ports not allowed

Answer (score 74):

Here's what [RegexBuddy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RegexBuddy) uses.

```
(\b(https?|ftp|file)://)?[-A-Za-z0-9+&@#/%?=~_|!:,.;]+[-A-Za-z0-9+&@#/%=~_|]
```

It matches these below (inside the `** **` marks):

```
**http://www.regexbuddy.com**  
**http://www.regexbuddy.com/**  
**http://www.regexbuddy.com/index.html**  
**http://www.regexbuddy.com/index.html?source=library**  
**http://www.regexbuddy.com/index.html?source=library#copyright**
```

You can download RegexBuddy at **http://www.regexbuddy.com/download.html**.

Comment: Your regex doesn't match any url I can come up with - including those you've included. I paste your regex into http://www.rubular.com and it says "Forward slashes must be escaped." Is there a typo or can you clarify by getting it to work at rubular.com?

Comment: @PandaWood that's because you need to format for Ruby.  What is Ruby's escape character?

Comment: Hi Keng, even if I copy your exact RegEx above into RegexBuddy, I can't match it on any URL. I guess there's something gone amiss in the markup. Ruby regex is hardly any different at this basic syntax level.

Comment: @PandaWood wait...if you have REB just go to the library and grab it.  that's where i got it...check to see if they are the same.

Comment: As a JavaScript RegExp literal: `/\b(https?|ftp|file):\/\/[\-A-Za-z0-9+&@#\/%?=~_|!:,.;]*[\-A-Za-z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|]/`

Comment: @Mahesh Chand thanks for the update; the edit got rejected so I couldnt get a moderator to reinstate the enhancement.  I think it got rejected because the reviewers would rather see code changes in comments and then let the OP add it.  I made the update though.  thanks.

Comment: The good thing about this regex is that it matches URLs with commas. For example: http://www.example.com/todo.do?id=123,456

Comment: This regex not only does not match many valid URIs, but also matches anything like `[-A-Za-z0-9+&@#/%?=~_|!:,.;]`, which is of course nothing like a URI. I suggest deletion.

Comment: It maches also non valid urls like: `http://https://www.google.com`

Comment: Your regex match also not valid url, you can check it [here](https://tools.waytolearnx.com/regex-tester/c9e12ec7dc69).

Answer (score 51):

With regard to **eyelidness**' answer post that reads "This is based on my reading of the URI specification.": Thanks Eyelidness, yours is the perfect solution I sought, as it is based on the URI spec! Superb work. :)

I had to make two amendments. The first to get the regexp to match IP address URLs correctly in PHP (v5.2.10) with the preg_match() function.

I had to add one more set of parenthesis to the line above "IP Address" around the pipes:

```
)|((\d|[1-9]\d|1\d{2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])\.){3}(?#
```

Not sure why.

I have also reduced the top level domain minimum length from 3 to 2 letters to support .co.uk and similar.

Final code:

```
/^(https?|ftp):\/\/(?#                                      protocol
)(([a-z0-9$_\.\+!\*\'\(\),;\?&=-]|%[0-9a-f]{2})+(?#         username
)(:([a-z0-9$_\.\+!\*\'\(\),;\?&=-]|%[0-9a-f]{2})+)?(?#      password
)@)?(?#                                                     auth requires @
)((([a-z0-9]\.|[a-z0-9][a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9]\.)*(?#             domain segments AND
)[a-z][a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9](?#                                 top level domain  OR
)|((\d|[1-9]\d|1\d{2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])\.){3}(?#
    )(\d|[1-9]\d|1\d{2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])(?#             IP address
))(:\d+)?(?#                                                port
))(((\/+([a-z0-9$_\.\+!\*\'\(\),;:@&=-]|%[0-9a-f]{2})*)*(?# path
)(\?([a-z0-9$_\.\+!\*\'\(\),;:@&=-]|%[0-9a-f]{2})*)(?#      query string
)?)?)?(?#                                                   path and query string optional
)(#([a-z0-9$_\.\+!\*\'\(\),;:@&=-]|%[0-9a-f]{2})*)?(?#      fragment
)$/i
```

This modified version was not checked against the URI specification so I can't vouch for it's compliance, it was altered to handle URLs on local network environments and two digit TLDs as well as other kinds of Web URL, and to work better in the PHP setup I use.

As **PHP** code:

```php
define('URL_FORMAT', 
'/^(https?):\/\/'.                                         // protocol
'(([a-z0-9$_\.\+!\*\'\(\),;\?&=-]|%[0-9a-f]{2})+'.         // username
'(:([a-z0-9$_\.\+!\*\'\(\),;\?&=-]|%[0-9a-f]{2})+)?'.      // password
'@)?(?#'.                                                  // auth requires @
')((([a-z0-9]\.|[a-z0-9][a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9]\.)*'.                      // domain segments AND
'[a-z][a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9]'.                                 // top level domain  OR
'|((\d|[1-9]\d|1\d{2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])\.){3}'.
'(\d|[1-9]\d|1\d{2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])'.                 // IP address
')(:\d+)?'.                                                // port
')(((\/+([a-z0-9$_\.\+!\*\'\(\),;:@&=-]|%[0-9a-f]{2})*)*'. // path
'(\?([a-z0-9$_\.\+!\*\'\(\),;:@&=-]|%[0-9a-f]{2})*)'.      // query string
'?)?)?'.                                                   // path and query string optional
'(#([a-z0-9$_\.\+!\*\'\(\),;:@&=-]|%[0-9a-f]{2})*)?'.      // fragment
'$/i');
```

Here is a test program in PHP which validates a variety of URLs using the regex:

```php
<?php

define('URL_FORMAT',
'/^(https?):\/\/'.                                         // protocol
'(([a-z0-9$_\.\+!\*\'\(\),;\?&=-]|%[0-9a-f]{2})+'.         // username
'(:([a-z0-9$_\.\+!\*\'\(\),;\?&=-]|%[0-9a-f]{2})+)?'.      // password
'@)?(?#'.                                                  // auth requires @
')((([a-z0-9]\.|[a-z0-9][a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9]\.)*'.                      // domain segments AND
'[a-z][a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9]'.                                 // top level domain  OR
'|((\d|[1-9]\d|1\d{2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])\.){3}'.
'(\d|[1-9]\d|1\d{2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])'.                 // IP address
')(:\d+)?'.                                                // port
')(((\/+([a-z0-9$_\.\+!\*\'\(\),;:@&=-]|%[0-9a-f]{2})*)*'. // path
'(\?([a-z0-9$_\.\+!\*\'\(\),;:@&=-]|%[0-9a-f]{2})*)'.      // query string
'?)?)?'.                                                   // path and query string optional
'(#([a-z0-9$_\.\+!\*\'\(\),;:@&=-]|%[0-9a-f]{2})*)?'.      // fragment
'$/i');

/**
 * Verify the syntax of the given URL. 
 * 
 * @access public
 * @param $url The URL to verify.
 * @return boolean
 */
function is_valid_url($url) {
  if (str_starts_with(strtolower($url), 'http://localhost')) {
    return true;
  }
  return preg_match(URL_FORMAT, $url);
}


/**
 * String starts with something
 * 
 * This function will return true only if input string starts with
 * niddle
 * 
 * @param string $string Input string
 * @param string $niddle Needle string
 * @return boolean
 */
function str_starts_with($string, $niddle) {
      return substr($string, 0, strlen($niddle)) == $niddle;
}


/**
 * Test a URL for validity and count results.
 * @param url url
 * @param expected expected result (true or false)
 */

$numtests = 0;
$passed = 0;

function test_url($url, $expected) {
  global $numtests, $passed;
  $numtests++;
  $valid = is_valid_url($url);
  echo "URL Valid?: " . ($valid?"yes":"no") . " for URL: $url. Expected: ".($expected?"yes":"no").". ";
  if($valid == $expected) {
    echo "PASS\n"; $passed++;
  } else {
    echo "FAIL\n";
  }
}

echo "URL Tests:\n\n";

test_url("http://localserver/projects/public/assets/javascript/widgets/UserBoxMenu/widget.css", true);
test_url("http://www.google.com", true);
test_url("http://www.google.co.uk/projects/my%20folder/test.php", true);
test_url("https://myserver.localdomain", true);
test_url("http://192.168.1.120/projects/index.php", true);
test_url("http://192.168.1.1/projects/index.php", true);
test_url("http://projectpier-server.localdomain/projects/public/assets/javascript/widgets/UserBoxMenu/widget.css", true);
test_url("https://2.4.168.19/project-pier?c=test&a=b", true);
test_url("https://localhost/a/b/c/test.php?c=controller&arg1=20&arg2=20", true);
test_url("http://user:password@localhost/a/b/c/test.php?c=controller&arg1=20&arg2=20", true);
  
echo "\n$passed out of $numtests tests passed.\n\n";

?>
```

Thanks again to **eyelidness** for the regex!

Comment: eyelidness' answer didn't work for me, but this one did. Thanks!

Comment: this one works in JavaScript, but I was *not* able to get the one eyelidness provided to work in JS, even after replacing \x with \u to escape unicode characters

Comment: [Sho Kuwamoto](http://stackoverflow.com/users/957663/sho-kuwamoto)'s comment: "I ended up using the regex by user244966, which to me is the perfect blend of readable but thorough.
However, there is one MAJOR issue in the regex.... His/her regex fails on domains that contain one character pieces, such as http://t.co The fix is to replace this line `')((([a-z0-9][a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9]\.)*'.` with `')((([a-z0-9]\.|[a-z0-9][a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9]\.)*'.`." I've made the relevant edit based on this comment.

Comment: `/^(https?|ftp):` (protocol) Why do you disallow protocols like data, file, svn, dc++, magnet, skype or any other supported by a browser having the corresponding plugin or a server?

Comment: Be warned that this matches `https://sdfasd`, but not `stackoverflow.com`.

Comment: eyelidness updated his answer to accept IRI (RFC 3987), but this answer only accepts URI. An update is needed. Example of a valid (and working) "url": `https://www.e-nuc.com/images/productos/adhesivo-tecl-blanco-español-2-2-2.jpg`

Answer (score 38):

The post [Getting parts of a URL (Regex)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27745/getting-parts-of-a-url-regex#27755) discusses parsing a URL to identify its various components. If you want to check if a URL is well-formed, it should be sufficient for your needs.

If you need to check if it's actually valid, you'll eventually have to try to access whatever's on the other end.

In general, though, you'd probably be better off using a function that's supplied to you by your framework or another library. Many platforms include functions that parse URLs. For example, there's Python's [urlparse](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html) module, and in .NET you could use the [System.Uri class's constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa332621.aspx) as a means of validating the URL.

Answer (score 35):

**This might not be a job for regexes, but for existing tools in your language of choice.**  You probably want to use existing code that has already been written, tested, and debugged.

In PHP, use the [`parse_url`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php) function.

Perl: [`URI` module](http://search.cpan.org/dist/URI/).

Ruby: [`URI` module](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/uri/rdoc/URI.html).

.NET: ['Uri' class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/txt7706a.aspx)

**Regexes are not a magic wand you wave at every problem that happens to involve strings.**

Comment: Your last sentence very much reminds me of [Law of the instrument/Maslow's hammer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_the_instrument): *"If all you have is a hammer, everything looks like a nail."*

Comment: Regexes are, however, beautiful for _extracting_ URLs from a body of plaintext.  If you suspect the entirety of a string is a URL, then I'd 100% agree with you and mention that Java's equivalent is `java.net.URL`.

Comment: The docs for parse_url in PHP state: This function is not meant to validate the given URL, it only breaks it up into the above listed parts.

Comment: @andy Lester What about JavaScript? Can you add an example for JavaScript to your answer? I think it'd be really beneficial for many!

Comment: Javascript has https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL_API "If the given base URL or the resulting URL are not valid URLs, the JavaScript TypeError exception is thrown." (Use try catch)

Answer (score 24):

This will match all URLs

- with or without *http*/*https*
- with or without *www*

...including sub-domains and those new top-level domain name extensions such as 
  .*museum*, 
  .*academy*, 
  .*foundation*
  etc. which can have up to 63 characters (not just .*com*, .*net*, .*info* etc.)

```
(([\w]+:)?//)?(([\d\w]|%[a-fA-f\d]{2,2})+(:([\d\w]|%[a-fA-f\d]{2,2})+)?@)?([\d\w][-\d\w]{0,253}[\d\w]\.)+[\w]{2,63}(:[\d]+)?(/([-+_~.\d\w]|%[a-fA-f\d]{2,2})*)*(\?(&?([-+_~.\d\w]|%[a-fA-f\d]{2,2})=?)*)?(#([-+_~.\d\w]|%[a-fA-f\d]{2,2})*)?
```

Because today maximum length of the available top-level domain name extension is 13 characters such as .*international*, you can change the number 63 in expression to 13 to prevent someone misusing it.

as javascript

```js
var urlreg=/(([\w]+:)?\/\/)?(([\d\w]|%[a-fA-f\d]{2,2})+(:([\d\w]|%[a-fA-f\d]{2,2})+)?@)?([\d\w][-\d\w]{0,253}[\d\w]\.)+[\w]{2,63}(:[\d]+)?(\/([-+_~.\d\w]|%[a-fA-f\d]{2,2})*)*(\?(&?([-+_~.\d\w]|%[a-fA-f\d]{2,2})=?)*)?(#([-+_~.\d\w]|%[a-fA-f\d]{2,2})*)?/;

$('textarea').on('input',function(){
  var url = $(this).val();
  $(this).toggleClass('invalid', urlreg.test(url) == false)
});

$('textarea').trigger('input');
```

```css
textarea{color:green;}
.invalid{color:red;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea>http://www.google.com</textarea>
<textarea>http//www.google.com</textarea>
<textarea>googlecom</textarea>
<textarea>https://www.google.com</textarea>
```

Wikipedia Article: [List of all internet top-level domains](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Internet_top-level_domains)

Comment: Could anyone please convert this for use in Javascript?

Comment: Finally!! Can someone mark this as an answer? Or at lease upvote it.
I thing though, i don't think it matches single letter domains, i.e. `t.co`. How would you adjust it to handle these case?

Comment: it seems to allow http// without :

Comment: matches telephone numbers and email addresses have a look at http://regexr.com/3eosr copy pasted your regex, just escaped all slashes

Comment: Be aware that this matches `http/stackoverflow.com/`, `h77ps://stackoverflow.com/`, and `//stackoverflow.com/`.

Comment: it allows www.google without the .com

Comment: Ports are not matched

Answer (score 23):

```
^(http:\/\/www\.|https:\/\/www\.|http:\/\/|https:\/\/)?[a-z0-9]+([\-\.]{1}[a-z0-9]+)*\.[a-z]{2,5}(:[0-9]{1,5})?(\/.*)?$
```

live demo: https://regex101.com/r/HUNasA/2

I have tested various expressions to match my requirements.

As a user I can hit browser search bar with following strings:

**valid urls**

- https://www.google.com
- http://www.google.com
- http://google.com/
- https://google.com/
- www.google.com
- google.com
- https://www.google.com.ua
- http://www.google.com.ua
- http://google.com.ua
- https://google.com.ua/
- www.google.com.ua
- google.com.ua
- https://mail.google.com
- http://mail.google.com
- mail.google.com

**invalid urls**

- http://google
- https://google.c
- google
- google.
- .google
- .google.com
- goole.c
- ...

Comment: Test this URL: https://www.Google.com
URL should be case insensitive

Comment: In the end of the URL put space and then symbols/letters again it will be considered
it will be calculated as part of URL

Comment: Shortened and corrected `/^(http(s)?:\/\/)?(www.)?([a-zA-Z0-9])+([\-\.]{1}[a-zA-Z0-9]+)*\.[a-zA-Z]{2,5}(:[0-9]{1,5})?(\/[^\s]*)?$/gm` 
https://regex101.com/r/KR2b6n/1

Comment: The corrected version by @AniNaslyan works well for me if I replace the `^` and `?` bookends with `\b`

Comment: What about `localhost`?

Comment: How to capture invalid urls so. It can happen that by mistake in text `google.com` would have misplaced by `google.co`

Comment: for example google.academy does not match

Answer (score 20):

## Non-validating URI-reference Parser

For reference purposes, here's the IETF Spec: ([TXT](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3986.txt) | [HTML](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#appendix-B)). In particular, *Appendix B. **Parsing** a URI Reference with a Regular Expression* demonstrates how to parse a **valid regex**. This is described as,

> for an example of a non-validating URI-reference parser that will take any given string and extract the URI components.

Here's the regex they provide:

```
^(([^:/?#]+):)?(//([^/?#]*))?([^?#]*)(\?([^#]*))?(#(.*))?
```

As someone else said, it's probably best to leave this to a lib/framework you're already using.

Comment: Completely useless. Can someone show me a string which this regex does *not* match? (Both "#?#?#" or "<<<>>>" match. What kind of URIs are those?)

Comment: @AlexD Don't complain to me. That's the official specification for a URI. Take it up with the IETF if you don't like it.

Comment: @AlexD I think those might be considered _relative references_. See RFC 3986, section 4.2.

Comment: @andyg0808, you may be right, but the fact remains that this regex matches virtually any string under the sun.

Comment: This is not a good answer because it's not validating, as per the question. It's parsing. Those are two different functions. If you give this regex trash, it tries to parse it. If the URL isn't valid, the parsing isn't guaranteed to work.

Comment: @Evan Carroll: Anything can be parsed according to some criteria. Feed any regex on this page with a string, and where it doesn't parse to a valid URL, it's an invalid URL by assertion. Then trialing the result validates the regex assertion. You're right, the answer says _Non-validating URI-reference Parser_ "for reference purposes", which might be included in an answer to something like [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3487089/are-regular-expressions-used-to-build-parsers), and then cross-linked.

Comment: @AlexD According to Python's `urllib.parse.urlparse()`, an entirely valid URI: `ParseResult(scheme='', netloc='', path='', params='', query='', fragment='?#?#')`. Just because it's useless doesn't mean it's invalid.

Answer (score 13):

The best regular expression for URL for me would be:

```
"(([\w]+:)?//)?(([\d\w]|%[a-fA-F\d]{2,2})+(:([\d\w]|%[a-fA-f\d]{2,2})+)?@)?([\d\w][-\d\w]{0,253}[\d\w]\.)+[\w]{2,4}(:[\d]+)?(/([-+_~.\d\w]|%[a-fA-f\d]{2,2})*)*(\?(&?([-+_~.\d\w]|%[a-fA-f\d]{2,2})=?)*)?(#([-+_~.\d\w]|%[a-fA-f\d]{2,2})*)?"
```

Comment: this seems to be limited w/r/t number of domains it'll accept?

Comment: Thanks! Here's the escaped version that worked for me on iOS: `(([\\w]+:)?//)?(([\\d\\w]|%[a-fA-f\\d]{2,2})+(:([\\d\\w]|%[a-fA-f\\d]{2,2})+)?@)?([\\d\\w][-\\d\\w]{0,253}[\\d\\w]\\.)+[\\w]{2,4}(:[\\d]+)?(/([-+_~.\\d\\w]|%[a-fA-f\\d]{2,2})*)*(\\?(&?([-+_~.\\d\\w]|%[a-fA-f\\d]{2,2})=?)*)?(#([-+_~.\\d\\w]|%[a-fA-f\\d]{2,2})*)?`

Comment: This regex only matches suffixes up to 4 characters long and fails on IP addresses (v4 and v6), localhost, and domain names with foreign characters.  I would recommend editing your inclusion size ranges and replacing `\w` with `\p{L}` at a minimum.

Comment: Note that this RegEx doesn't capture URLs that have subdomains of one letter only, like **"http://m.sitename.com"**. In order to fix that, I had to change `([\d\w][-\d\w]{0,253}[\d\w]\.)+` into `([\d\w][-\d\w]{0,253}[\d\w]?\.)+` (add a question mark near the end of it)

Comment: doesnt work with http://something.co.uk

Answer (score 12):

Here is a good rule that covers all possible cases: ports, params and etc

```
/(https?:\/\/(?:[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]{0,61}[a-z0-9])?\.)+[a-z0-9][a-z0-9-]{0,61}[a-z0-9])(:?\d*)\/?([a-z_\/0-9\-#.]*)\??([a-z_\/0-9\-#=&]*)/g
```

Comment: please check : www.ankit.com

Comment: work for these variations
`https://www.domainname.com
http://www.domainname.com
http://domainname.com 
https://domainname.com 
https://www.domainname.com/
http://www.domainname.com/ 
http://domainname.com/
https://domainname.com/ 
https://www.domainname.com/inner-page
http://www.domainname.com/inner-page
http://domainname.com/inner-page
https://domainname.com/inner-page
https://www.domainname.com/inner-page/
http://www.domainname.com/inner-page/
http://domainname.com/inner-page/
https://domainname.com/inner-page/`

Comment: Although this is the best REGEX in this thread, I fear this misses some cases with certain character in the URL argument part.
Example: `https://onedrive.live.com/?authkey=%dfdsssdf7LJSM3w&id=88ADFF5%21285&cid=2DC78C46388A4354`
This is cut after the `=` sign.
Also, uppercase characters can be part of a domain (case insesitive) or URL argument as in example given above.

Suggestion:

`/https?:\/\/(?:[a-zA-Z0-9](?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]{0,61}[a-zA-Z0-9])?\.)+[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9-]{0,61}[a-zA-Z0-9])(:?\d*)\/?([a-zA-Z0-9_\/\-#.]*)\??([a-zA-Z0-9\-_~:\/?#\[\]@!$&'()*+,;=%.]*/g`

Comment: Does not work with localhost

Answer (score 11):

I wrote a little groovy version that you can run

it matches the following URLs (which is good enough for me)

```java
public static void main(args) {
    String url = "go to http://www.m.abut.ly/abc its awesome"
    url = url.replaceAll(/https?:\/\/w{0,3}\w*?\.(\w*?\.)?\w{2,3}\S*|www\.(\w*?\.)?\w*?\.\w{2,3}\S*|(\w*?\.)?\w*?\.\w{2,3}[\/\?]\S*/ , { it ->
        "woof${it}woof"
    })
    println url 
}
```

```
http://google.com
http://google.com/help.php
http://google.com/help.php?a=5

http://www.google.com
http://www.google.com/help.php
http://www.google.com?a=5

google.com?a=5
google.com/help.php
google.com/help.php?a=5

http://www.m.google.com/help.php?a=5 (and all its permutations)
www.m.google.com/help.php?a=5 (and all its permutations)
m.google.com/help.php?a=5 (and all its permutations)
```

The important thing for any URLs that don't start with `http` or `www` is that they must include a `/` or `?`

I bet this can be tweaked a little more but it does the job pretty nice for being so short and compact... because you can pretty much split it in 3:

find anything that starts with `http`:

```
https?:\/\/w{0,3}\w*?\.\w{2,3}\S*
```

find anything that starts with `www`:

```
www\.\w*?\.\w{2,3}\S*
```

or find anything that must have a text then a dot then at least 2 letters and then a `?` or `/`:

```
\w*?\.\w{2,3}[\/\?]\S*
```

Comment: It also matches non valid URLs like: `https://http://www.google.com`

Answer (score 10):

I was not able to find the regex I was looking for so I modified a regex to fullfill my requirements, and apparently it seems to work fine now. My requirements were:

- Match URLs w/o protocol ([www.gooogle.com](http://www.gooogle.com))
- Match URLs with query parameters and path (http://subdomain.web-site.com/cgi-bin/perl.cgi?key1=value1&key2=value2e)
- Don't match URLs where there are not acceptable characters (e.g. "'£), for instance: ([www.google.com/somthing"/somethingmore](http://www.google.com/somthing%22/somethingmore))

Here what I came up with, any suggestion is appreciated:

```java
@Test
    public void testWebsiteUrl(){
        String regularExpression = "((http|ftp|https):\\/\\/)?[\\w\\-_]+(\\.[\\w\\-_]+)+([\\w\\-\\.,@?^=%&amp;:/~\\+#]*[\\w\\-\\@?^=%&amp;/~\\+#])?";
 
        assertTrue("www.google.com".matches(regularExpression));
        assertTrue("www.google.co.uk".matches(regularExpression));
        assertTrue("http://www.google.com".matches(regularExpression));
        assertTrue("http://www.google.co.uk".matches(regularExpression));
        assertTrue("https://www.google.com".matches(regularExpression));
        assertTrue("https://www.google.co.uk".matches(regularExpression));
        assertTrue("google.com".matches(regularExpression));
        assertTrue("google.co.uk".matches(regularExpression));
        assertTrue("google.mu".matches(regularExpression));
        assertTrue("mes.intnet.mu".matches(regularExpression));
        assertTrue("cse.uom.ac.mu".matches(regularExpression));
 
        assertTrue("http://www.google.com/path".matches(regularExpression));
        assertTrue("http://subdomain.web-site.com/cgi-bin/perl.cgi?key1=value1&key2=value2e".matches(regularExpression));
        assertTrue("http://www.google.com/?queryparam=123".matches(regularExpression));
        assertTrue("http://www.google.com/path?queryparam=123".matches(regularExpression));
         
        assertFalse("www..dr.google".matches(regularExpression));
 
        assertFalse("www:google.com".matches(regularExpression));
 
        assertFalse("https://www@.google.com".matches(regularExpression));
         
        assertFalse("https://www.google.com\"".matches(regularExpression));
        assertFalse("https://www.google.com'".matches(regularExpression));
         
        assertFalse("http://www.google.com/path'".matches(regularExpression));
        assertFalse("http://subdomain.web-site.com/cgi-bin/perl.cgi?key1=value1&key2=value2e'".matches(regularExpression));
        assertFalse("http://www.google.com/?queryparam=123'".matches(regularExpression));
        assertFalse("http://www.google.com/path?queryparam=12'3".matches(regularExpression));
         
    }
```

Comment: This matches `http/stackoverflow.com/`, `h77ps://stackoverflow.com/`, and `//stackoverflow.com/`.

Comment: http/stackoverflow.com/ is a valid relative url, //stackoverflow.com/ is a valid url without a specific protocol, the h77ps case is problematic

Comment: Thanks for the feedbacks. I believe the intention here is to not include relative path either so you are both right, it is a valid relative URL but our regex should not match those.
We need to improve the regex :)

Answer (score 9):

```js
        function validateURL(textval) {
            var urlregex = new RegExp(
            "^(http|https|ftp)\://([a-zA-Z0-9\.\-]+(\:[a-zA-Z0-9\.&amp;%\$\-]+)*@)*((25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[0-1]{1}[0-9]{2}|[1-9]{1}[0-9]{1}|[1-9])\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[0-1]{1}[0-9]{2}|[1-9]{1}[0-9]{1}|[1-9]|0)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[0-1]{1}[0-9]{2}|[1-9]{1}[0-9]{1}|[1-9]|0)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[0-1]{1}[0-9]{2}|[1-9]{1}[0-9]{1}|[0-9])|localhost|([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+\.)*[a-zA-Z0-9\-]+\.(com|edu|gov|int|mil|net|org|biz|arpa|info|name|pro|aero|coop|museum|[a-zA-Z]{2}))(\:[0-9]+)*(/($|[a-zA-Z0-9\.\,\?\'\\\+&amp;%\$#\=~_\-]+))*$");
            return urlregex.test(textval);
        }
```

Matches
http://example.com/dir/file.php?var=moo | ftp://user:pass@example.com:21/file/dir

Non-Matches
example.com | http://example.com/dir//

Comment: Note that this regex will match if we have [empty space] in the url. Example: `http://www.goo gle.com` will match.

Comment: use parse_url() before calling this function

Comment: Dont forget to escape the "/"'s and "?", its good practice and should make it cross compatible (from what i know (which isn't much on this matter :) ))

Answer (score 7):

If you really search for the **ultimate** match, you probably find it on "[A Good Url Regular Expression?](http://flanders.co.nz/2009/11/08/a-good-url-regular-expression-repost/)".

But a regex that really matches all possible domains and allows anything that is allowed according to RFCs is horribly long and unreadable, trust me ;-)

Answer (score 7):

```js
function validateURL(textval) {
            var urlregex = new RegExp(
            "^(http|https|ftp)\://[a-zA-Z0-9\-\.]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,3}(:[a-zA-Z0-9]*)?/?([a-zA-Z0-9\-\._\?\,\'/\\\+&amp;%\$#\=~])*$");
            return urlregex.test(textval);
        }
```

Matches
[http://www.asdah.com/~joe](http://www.asdah.com/%7Ejoe) | ftp://ftp.asdah.co.uk:2828/asdah%20asdah.gif | https://asdah.gov/asdh-ah.as

Answer (score 6):

I hope it's helpful for you...

```
^(http|https):\/\/+[\www\d]+\.[\w]+(\/[\w\d]+)?
```

Answer (score 6):

Here is a regex I made which extracts the different parts from an URL:

`^((?:(?:http|ftp|ws)s?|sftp):\/\/?)?([^:/\s.#?]+\.[^:/\s#?]+|localhost)(:\d+)?((?:\/\w+)*\/)?([\w\-.]+[^#?\s]+)?([^#]+)?(#[\w-]*)?$`

`((?:(?:http|ftp|ws)s?|sftp):\/\/?)?`*(group 1)*: extracts the protocol
`([^:/\s.#?]+\.[^:/\s#?]+|localhost)`*(group 2)*: extracts the hostname
`(:\d+)?`*(group 3)*: extracts the port number
`((?:\/\w+)*\/)?([\w\-.]+[^#?\s]+)?`*(groups 4 & 5)*: extracts the path part
`([^#]+)?`*(group 6)*: extracts the query part
`(#[\w-]*)?`*(group 7)*: extracts the hash part

For every part of the regex listed above, you can remove the ending `?` to force it (or add one to make it facultative). You can also remove the `^` at the beginning and `$` at the end of the regex so it won't need to match the whole string.

See it on [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/Q2ilqN/17).

***Note:** this regex is not 100% safe and may accept some strings which are not necessarily valid URLs but it does indeed validate some criterias. Its main goal was to extract the different parts of an URL not to validate it.*

Comment: Thanks. The group approach to these answers is best. Here's hoping for updates following the direction of [this article](http://jmrware.com/articles/2009/uri_regexp/URI_regex.html) linked on the next page, and a revision of the "not 100% safe". A quantification like 99.9% is enough for most readers. :P

Comment: Good pattern. Probably we can also add `file`. Also somebody can add `wss` and other protocols for his aims.

Answer (score 5):

I've been working on an in-depth article discussing URI validation using regular expressions. It is based on RFC3986.

[Regular Expression URI Validation](http://jmrware.com/articles/2009/uri_regexp/URI_regex.html)

Although the article is not yet complete, I have come up with a PHP function which does a pretty good job of validating HTTP and FTP URLs. Here is the current version:

```php
// function url_valid($url) { Rev:20110423_2000
//
// Return associative array of valid URI components, or FALSE if $url is not
// RFC-3986 compliant. If the passed URL begins with: "www." or "ftp.", then
// "http://" or "ftp://" is prepended and the corrected full-url is stored in
// the return array with a key name "url". This value should be used by the caller.
//
// Return value: FALSE if $url is not valid, otherwise array of URI components:
// e.g.
// Given: "http://www.jmrware.com:80/articles?height=10&width=75#fragone"
// Array(
//    [scheme] => http
//    [authority] => www.jmrware.com:80
//    [userinfo] =>
//    [host] => www.jmrware.com
//    [IP_literal] =>
//    [IPV6address] =>
//    [ls32] =>
//    [IPvFuture] =>
//    [IPv4address] =>
//    [regname] => www.jmrware.com
//    [port] => 80
//    [path_abempty] => /articles
//    [query] => height=10&width=75
//    [fragment] => fragone
//    [url] => http://www.jmrware.com:80/articles?height=10&width=75#fragone
// )
function url_valid($url) {
    if (strpos($url, 'www.') === 0) $url = 'http://'. $url;
    if (strpos($url, 'ftp.') === 0) $url = 'ftp://'. $url;
    if (!preg_match('/# Valid absolute URI having a non-empty, valid DNS host.
        ^
        (?P<scheme>[A-Za-z][A-Za-z0-9+\-.]*):\/\/
        (?P<authority>
          (?:(?P<userinfo>(?:[A-Za-z0-9\-._~!$&\'()*+,;=:]|%[0-9A-Fa-f]{2})*)@)?
          (?P<host>
            (?P<IP_literal>
              \[
              (?:
                (?P<IPV6address>
                  (?:                                                (?:[0-9A-Fa-f]{1,4}:){6}
                  |                                                ::(?:[0-9A-Fa-f]{1,4}:){5}
                  | (?:                          [0-9A-Fa-f]{1,4})?::(?:[0-9A-Fa-f]{1,4}:){4}
                  | (?:(?:[0-9A-Fa-f]{1,4}:){0,1}[0-9A-Fa-f]{1,4})?::(?:[0-9A-Fa-f]{1,4}:){3}
                  | (?:(?:[0-9A-Fa-f]{1,4}:){0,2}[0-9A-Fa-f]{1,4})?::(?:[0-9A-Fa-f]{1,4}:){2}
                  | (?:(?:[0-9A-Fa-f]{1,4}:){0,3}[0-9A-Fa-f]{1,4})?::   [0-9A-Fa-f]{1,4}:
                  | (?:(?:[0-9A-Fa-f]{1,4}:){0,4}[0-9A-Fa-f]{1,4})?::
                  )
                  (?P<ls32>[0-9A-Fa-f]{1,4}:[0-9A-Fa-f]{1,4}
                  | (?:(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.){3}
                       (?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)
                  )
                |   (?:(?:[0-9A-Fa-f]{1,4}:){0,5}[0-9A-Fa-f]{1,4})?::   [0-9A-Fa-f]{1,4}
                |   (?:(?:[0-9A-Fa-f]{1,4}:){0,6}[0-9A-Fa-f]{1,4})?::
                )
              | (?P<IPvFuture>[Vv][0-9A-Fa-f]+\.[A-Za-z0-9\-._~!$&\'()*+,;=:]+)
              )
              \]
            )
          | (?P<IPv4address>(?:(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.){3}
                               (?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?))
          | (?P<regname>(?:[A-Za-z0-9\-._~!$&\'()*+,;=]|%[0-9A-Fa-f]{2})+)
          )
          (?::(?P<port>[0-9]*))?
        )
        (?P<path_abempty>(?:\/(?:[A-Za-z0-9\-._~!$&\'()*+,;=:@]|%[0-9A-Fa-f]{2})*)*)
        (?:\?(?P<query>       (?:[A-Za-z0-9\-._~!$&\'()*+,;=:@\\/?]|%[0-9A-Fa-f]{2})*))?
        (?:\#(?P<fragment>    (?:[A-Za-z0-9\-._~!$&\'()*+,;=:@\\/?]|%[0-9A-Fa-f]{2})*))?
        $
        /mx', $url, $m)) return FALSE;
    switch ($m['scheme']) {
    case 'https':
    case 'http':
        if ($m['userinfo']) return FALSE; // HTTP scheme does not allow userinfo.
        break;
    case 'ftps':
    case 'ftp':
        break;
    default:
        return FALSE;   // Unrecognized URI scheme. Default to FALSE.
    }
    // Validate host name conforms to DNS "dot-separated-parts".
    if ($m['regname']) { // If host regname specified, check for DNS conformance.
        if (!preg_match('/# HTTP DNS host name.
            ^                      # Anchor to beginning of string.
            (?!.{256})             # Overall host length is less than 256 chars.
            (?:                    # Group dot separated host part alternatives.
              [A-Za-z0-9]\.        # Either a single alphanum followed by dot
            |                      # or... part has more than one char (63 chars max).
              [A-Za-z0-9]          # Part first char is alphanum (no dash).
              [A-Za-z0-9\-]{0,61}  # Internal chars are alphanum plus dash.
              [A-Za-z0-9]          # Part last char is alphanum (no dash).
              \.                   # Each part followed by literal dot.
            )*                     # Zero or more parts before top level domain.
            (?:                    # Explicitly specify top level domains.
              com|edu|gov|int|mil|net|org|biz|
              info|name|pro|aero|coop|museum|
              asia|cat|jobs|mobi|tel|travel|
              [A-Za-z]{2})         # Country codes are exactly two alpha chars.
              \.?                  # Top level domain can end in a dot.
            $                      # Anchor to end of string.
            /ix', $m['host'])) return FALSE;
    }
    $m['url'] = $url;
    for ($i = 0; isset($m[$i]); ++$i) unset($m[$i]);
    return $m; // return TRUE == array of useful named $matches plus the valid $url.
}
```

This function utilizes two regexes; one to match a subset of valid generic URIs (absolute ones having a non-empty host), and a second to validate the DNS "dot-separated-parts" host name. Although this function currently validates only HTTP and FTP schemes, it is structured such that it can be easily extended to handle other schemes.

Comment: I'm curious why you chose to follow URI RFC3986 rather than IRI RFC3987.

Comment: @eyelidlessness - Good question. I'm not really well versed with IRIs. Thanks for pointing out that RFC. I see that according to RFC3987: _"...in the HTTP protocol [RFC2616], the Request URI is defined as a URI, which means that direct use of IRIs is not allowed in HTTP requests."_  So an IRI is actually encoded as a URI before being sent via HTTP. So for the time being, there will always be a need for URI validation. Maybe I'll tackle IRI validation at a later date. Thanks for the comment!

Comment: @ridgerunner, the reference to 2616 is outdated. IRIs are sent as IRIs, with all of the characters that IRIs allow and URIs don't. I appreciate the effort to create a "human readable" pattern (and I've worked on one myself but haven't had the opportunity to test sufficiently) but in 2012 and going into 2013 it's unacceptable to limit addresses to western characters while non-western characters are in fact in wide use in paths, fragments and even domains.

Answer (score 5):

I use this regex:

```
((https?:)?//)?(([\d\w]|%[a-fA-f\d]{2,2})+(:([\d\w]|%[a-fA-f\d]{2,2})+)?@)?([\d\w][-\d\w]{0,253}[\d\w]\.)+[\w]{2,63}(:[\d]+)?(/([-+_~.\d\w]|%[a-fA-f\d]{2,2})*)*(\?(&?([-+_~.\d\w]|%[a-fA-f\d]{2,2})=?)*)?(#([-+_~.\d\w]|%[a-fA-f\d]{2,2})*)?
```

To support both:

```
http://stackoverflow.com
https://stackoverflow.com
```

And:

```
//stackoverflow.com
```

Comment: I had to update your regex. The third '?' was allowing all sorts of text to be selected. After removing it only 'http', 'https', or '//' were selected.

I modified this so it works on relative URLs to '/'. And escaped the forward slashes.

`((https?:)?(\/?\/))(([\d\w]|%[a-fA-f\d]{2,2})+(:([\d\w]|%[a-fA-f\d]{2,2})+)?@)?([\d\w][-\d\w]{0,253}[\d\w]\.)+[\w]{2,63}(:[\d]+)?(/([-+_~.\d\w]|%[a-fA-f\d]{2,2})*)*(\?(&?([-+_~.\d\w]|%[a-fA-f\d]{2,2})=?)*)?(#([-+_~.\d\w]|%[a-fA-f\d]{2,2})*)?`

Comment: Updated the capturing groups so they can be more useful:

`((?:https?:)?(?:\/?\/))((?:[\d\w]|%[a-fA-f\d]{2,2})+(?::(?:[\d\w]|%[a-fA-f\d]{2,2})+)?@)?((?:[\d\w][-\d\w]{0,253}[\d\w]\.)+[\w]{2,63})(:[\d]+)?(\/(?:[-+_~.\d\w]|%[a-fA-f\d]{2,2})*)*(\?(?:&?(?:[-+_~.\d\w]|%[a-fA-f\d]{2,2})=?)*)?(#(?:[-+_~.\d\w]|%[a-fA-f\d]{2,2})*)?`

Answer (score 5):

Here's a ready-to-go Java version from the Android source code.  This is the best one I've found.

```java
public static final Matcher WEB  = Pattern.compile(new StringBuilder()                 
.append("((?:(http|https|Http|Https|rtsp|Rtsp):")                      
.append("\\/\\/(?:(?:[a-zA-Z0-9\\$\\-\\_\\.\\+\\!\\*\\'\\(\\)")                         
.append("\\,\\;\\?\\&\\=]|(?:\\%[a-fA-F0-9]{2})){1,64}(?:\\:(?:[a-zA-Z0-9\\$\\-\\_")                         
.append("\\.\\+\\!\\*\\'\\(\\)\\,\\;\\?\\&\\=]|(?:\\%[a-fA-F0-9]{2})){1,25})?\\@)?)?")                         
.append("((?:(?:[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9\\-]{0,64}\\.)+")   // named host                            
.append("(?:")   // plus top level domain                         
.append("(?:aero|arpa|asia|a[cdefgilmnoqrstuwxz])")                         
.append("|(?:biz|b[abdefghijmnorstvwyz])")                         
.append("|(?:cat|com|coop|c[acdfghiklmnoruvxyz])")                         
.append("|d[ejkmoz]")                         
.append("|(?:edu|e[cegrstu])")                         
.append("|f[ijkmor]")                         
.append("|(?:gov|g[abdefghilmnpqrstuwy])")                         
.append("|h[kmnrtu]")                         
.append("|(?:info|int|i[delmnoqrst])")                         
.append("|(?:jobs|j[emop])")                         
.append("|k[eghimnrwyz]")                         
.append("|l[abcikrstuvy]")                         
.append("|(?:mil|mobi|museum|m[acdghklmnopqrstuvwxyz])")                         
.append("|(?:name|net|n[acefgilopruz])")                         
.append("|(?:org|om)")                         
.append("|(?:pro|p[aefghklmnrstwy])")                         
.append("|qa")                         
.append("|r[eouw]")                         
.append("|s[abcdeghijklmnortuvyz]")                         
.append("|(?:tel|travel|t[cdfghjklmnoprtvwz])")                         
.append("|u[agkmsyz]")                         
.append("|v[aceginu]")                         
.append("|w[fs]")                         
.append("|y[etu]")                         
.append("|z[amw]))")                         
.append("|(?:(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4]") // or ip address                                                 
.append("[0-9]|[0-1][0-9]{2}|[1-9][0-9]|[1-9])\\.(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]")                             
.append("|[0-1][0-9]{2}|[1-9][0-9]|[1-9]|0)\\.(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[0-1]")                         
.append("[0-9]{2}|[1-9][0-9]|[1-9]|0)\\.(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[0-1][0-9]{2}")                         
.append("|[1-9][0-9]|[0-9])))")                         
.append("(?:\\:\\d{1,5})?)") // plus option port number                             
.append("(\\/(?:(?:[a-zA-Z0-9\\;\\/\\?\\:\\@\\&\\=\\#\\~")  // plus option query params                         
.append("\\-\\.\\+\\!\\*\\'\\(\\)\\,\\_])|(?:\\%[a-fA-F0-9]{2}))*)?")                         
.append("(?:\\b|$)").toString()                 
).matcher("");
```

Comment: This don't work with "New gTLDs", check http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Internet_top-level_domains & http://newgtlds.icann.org/en/program-status/delegated-strings. Hardcoding list of TLD is bad practice... Some public suffix lists are available, they include recent variant of TLD: https://publicsuffix.org/  (used in Firefox, Chrome, IE)

Comment: My first thought at seeing this: there's no kill like overkill.  They literally took all ccTLDs and built a regex to match them specifically.  Cuts down on false positives, I suppose, but a terrible way to handle the situation.

Answer (score 5):

### Updated, International & Modern Answer for 2023 And Beyond

Covering 99%+ URLs supported by modern browsers, that includes:

- [emojis  in domain name and path](http://factmyth.com/factoids/you-%F0%9F%91%8F-can-%F0%9F%91%8F-put-%F0%9F%91%8F-emojis-%F0%9F%91%8F-in-%F0%9F%91%8F-urls-%F0%9F%91%8F/)
- enforcing for top level domain: [first character should be alpha but can have numbers afterwards](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53875771/7333766), [2 characters minimum](https://www.quora.com/Will-there-be-a-single-letter-TLD-such-as-a-or-b-in-the-future-Why-didnt-ICANN-allow-such-TLDs-from-the-beginning), up to [the theoretical limit of 63](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9238640/how-long-can-a-tld-possibly-be), yet allowing [underscores](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2180465/can-domain-name-subdomains-have-an-underscore-in-it), [accented characters](https://www.cira.ca/ca-domains/register-your-ca-domain/domains-french-accented-characters) and [internationalized characters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Internet_top-level_domains#Internationalized_generic_top-level_domains)
- [world's most common languages alphabets, characters & diacritics](https://www.berlitz.com/blog/most-spoken-languages-world) in path & domain name. Includes English (duh), French, Spanish, Portuguese, German, Italian, Bengali, Devenagri, Marathi, ~99% Chinese (CJK), Japanese, Korean, Taiwanese, Vietnamese, Urdu, Arabic, Greek, Cyrillic **and all others that share their character sets with these**
- Added versions with and without support for IPv4 URLs that are also used and seen online & supported by all modern browsers

##### Use this to include the protocol ("http/https") & IPv4 URLs:

```
https?:\/\/(\b(?:(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.){3}(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?):\d{1,5}\b|([-a-zA-Z0-9\u1F60-\uFFFF\u1F60-\uFFFF\u00C0-\u00D6\u00D8-\u00F6\u00F8-\u024F@:%._\+~#=]{1,256})\.([a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9\u1F60-\uFFFF\u00C0-\u00D6\u00D8-\u00F6\u00F8-\u024F\u0370-\u03ff\u1f00-\u1fff\u0400-\u04ff()-]{1,62}))\b([\/#][-a-zA-Z0-9\u1F60-\uFFFF\u00C0-\u00D6\u00D8-\u00F6\u00F8-\u024F\u0370-\u03ff\u1f00-\u1fff\u0400-\u04ff\u0900-\u097F\u0600-\u06FF\u0985-\u0994\u0995-\u09a7\u09a8-\u09ce\u0981\u0982\u0983\u09e6-\u09ef\u0750-\u077F\uFB50-\uFDFF\uFE70-\uFEFF\u4E00-\u9FFFẸɓɗẹỊỌịọṢỤṣụ()@:%_\+.~#?&//=\[\]!\$'*+,;]*)?
```

###### Use this to include the protocol but not IPv4 addresses:

```
https?:\/\/([-a-zA-Z0-9\u1F60-\uFFFF\u1F60-\uFFFF\u00C0-\u00D6\u00D8-\u00F6\u00F8-\u024F@:%._\+~#=]{1,256})\.([a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9\u1F60-\uFFFF\u00C0-\u00D6\u00D8-\u00F6\u00F8-\u024F\u0370-\u03ff\u1f00-\u1fff\u0400-\u04ff()-]{1,62})\b([\/#][-a-zA-Z0-9\u1F60-\uFFFF\u00C0-\u00D6\u00D8-\u00F6\u00F8-\u024F\u0370-\u03ff\u1f00-\u1fff\u0400-\u04ff\u0900-\u097F\u0600-\u06FF\u0985-\u0994\u0995-\u09a7\u09a8-\u09ce\u0981\u0982\u0983\u09e6-\u09ef\u0750-\u077F\uFB50-\uFDFF\uFE70-\uFEFF\u4E00-\u9FFFẸɓɗẹỊỌịọṢỤṣụ()@:%_\+.~#?&//=\[\]!\$'*+,;]*)?
```

###### To match domain names and paths (no IPv4):

```
([-a-zA-Z0-9\u1F60-\uFFFF\u1F60-\uFFFF\u00C0-\u00D6\u00D8-\u00F6\u00F8-\u024F@:%._\+~#=]{1,256})\.([a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9\u1F60-\uFFFF\u00C0-\u00D6\u00D8-\u00F6\u00F8-\u024F\u0370-\u03ff\u1f00-\u1fff\u0400-\u04ff()-]{1,62})\b([\/#][-a-zA-Z0-9\u1F60-\uFFFF\u00C0-\u00D6\u00D8-\u00F6\u00F8-\u024F\u0370-\u03ff\u1f00-\u1fff\u0400-\u04ff\u0900-\u097F\u0600-\u06FF\u0985-\u0994\u0995-\u09a7\u09a8-\u09ce\u0981\u0982\u0983\u09e6-\u09ef\u0750-\u077F\uFB50-\uFDFF\uFE70-\uFEFF\u4E00-\u9FFFẸɓɗẹỊỌịọṢỤṣụ()@:%_\+.~#?&//=\[\]!\$'*+,;]*)?
```

#### Battle-Tested with all these Real-World & Theoretical Edge Cases:

```js
// Check with a simple copy/paste in console!

const regexURLsAndIPs =
  /^https?:\/\/(\b(?:(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.){3}(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?):\d{1,5}\b|([-a-zA-Z0-9\u1F60-\uFFFF\u1F60-\uFFFF\u00C0-\u00D6\u00D8-\u00F6\u00F8-\u024F@:%._\+~#=]{1,256})\.([a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9\u1F60-\uFFFF\u00C0-\u00D6\u00D8-\u00F6\u00F8-\u024F\u0370-\u03ff\u1f00-\u1fff\u0400-\u04ff()-]{1,62}))\b([\/#][-a-zA-Z0-9\u1F60-\uFFFF\u00C0-\u00D6\u00D8-\u00F6\u00F8-\u024F\u0370-\u03ff\u1f00-\u1fff\u0400-\u04ff\u0900-\u097F\u0600-\u06FF\u0985-\u0994\u0995-\u09a7\u09a8-\u09ce\u0981\u0982\u0983\u09e6-\u09ef\u0750-\u077F\uFB50-\uFDFF\uFE70-\uFEFF\u4E00-\u9FFFẸɓɗẹỊỌịọṢỤṣụ()@:%_\+.~#?&//=\[\]!\$'*+,;]*)?$/

const shouldMatch = [
  'https://base.com/',
  'http://t.co',
  'https://www.google.com.ua/',
  'https://subdomains.as.deep.as.you.want.example.com',
  'https://sub.second_leveldomain_underscore.verylongtoplevedomain/nice',
  'https://domain-name.com/path-common-characters/ABCxyz01789',
  'http://domaîn-with-àccents.ca',
  'http://path-with-accents.com/àèìòùçÇßØøÅåÆæœ',
  'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Möbius_strip',
  'http://www..tld/emojis--in--domain/-and-path-/',
  'https://y.at/',
  'https://hashtag.forpath#lets-go',
  "http://special.com/all-special-characters-._~:/?#[]@!$&'()*+,;=",
  'https://greek_with_diacritics.co/ΑαΒβΣσ/ςΤτϋΰήώΊΪΌΆΈΎΫΉΏᾶἀ',
  'https://el.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ποσειδώνας_(πλανήτης)',
  'http://cyrillic-and-extras.ru/АаБбВвЪъыӸӹЫЯЯяѶѷ',
  'https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Заглавная_страница',
  'https://most-arabic.co/گچپژیلفقهموء-يجريبتج/',
  'https://urdu.co/حروفِ/',
  'https://nigerian.ni/ƁƊƎẸɓɗǝẹỊƘỌịƙọṢỤṣụ',
  'https://bengali.sports.co/স্পর্শঅনুনাসিকলসওষ্ঠ্যপফবভম/',
  'https://devenagri.cc/कखगघङचछजझञटठडढणतथदधनपफबभमयरलवशषस',
  'https://h.org/wiki/Wikipedia:关于中文维基百科/en',
  'https://zh.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:关于中文维基百科/en',
  'http://others.kr/korean-안녕ㆅㅇㄹㅿㆍㅡㅣㅗㅑㅠㅕ/japanese-一龠ぁゔａｚＡＺ０９々〆〤ヶ',
  'https://龠.subdomain.com',
  'http://127.0.0.1:22/valid-ip',
  'http://127.00.00.01:22/ugly-but-still-works-with-modern-browsers',
  'http://0.0.0.0:0/is-min',
  'https://255.255.255.255:0/is-max',
  'https://this.tld-is-63-characters-wich-is-the-theoretical-limit-000000000000',
]

const shouldNotMatch = [
  'noprotocol.com',
  ' https://space-in-front.com',
  'https://invalid.0om',
  'https://invalid.-om',
  'https://invalid-single-letter-tld.c',
  'https://invalid-domain&char.com',
  'https://invalid:com',
  'https://not valid.com',
  'https://not,valid.com',
  'https://龠.c龠',
  'https://invalidαΒβΣσ.com',
  'notvalid://www.google.com',
  'http://missing-tld',
  'https://0.0.0.0missing-port',
  '0.0.0.0:0/missing-protocol',
  'https://256.255.255.255:0/is-above-max',
  'https://this.tld-is-64-characters-which-is-too-looooooooooooooooooooooooooong',
]

function checkStringsMatchRegex(regex, array, shouldMatch = true) {
  for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    if (regex.test(array[i]) !== shouldMatch) {
      const matchStr = shouldMatch ? 'match' : 'not match'
      console.error('regex.test(array[i])', regex.test(array[i]))
      throw new Error(`String "${array[i]}" should ${matchStr} regex "${regex}"`)
    }
  }
  const successMatchingStr = shouldMatch ? 'matching all strings' : 'not matching a single string'
  console.log(`Success with ${successMatchingStr} in the test array.`)
}

checkStringsMatchRegex(regexURLsAndIPs, shouldMatch, true)
checkStringsMatchRegex(regexURLsAndIPs, shouldNotMatch, false)
```

Comment: unfortunately it allows stuff such as "+" or "_" in the tld

Comment: and it also doesn't match urls with ports

Answer (score 4):

For Python, this is the actual URL validating regex used in Django 1.5.1:

```py
import re
regex = re.compile(
        r'^(?:http|ftp)s?://'  # http:// or https://
        r'(?:(?:[A-Z0-9](?:[A-Z0-9-]{0,61}[A-Z0-9])?\.)+(?:[A-Z]{2,6}\.?|[A-Z0-9-]{2,}\.?)|'  # domain...
        r'localhost|'  # localhost...
        r'\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}|'  # ...or ipv4
        r'\[?[A-F0-9]*:[A-F0-9:]+\]?)'  # ...or ipv6
        r'(?::\d+)?'  # optional port
        r'(?:/?|[/?]\S+)$', re.IGNORECASE)
```

This does both ipv4 and ipv6 addresses as well as ports and GET parameters.

Found in the [code here](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/core/validators.py), Line 44.

Answer (score 4):

This one works for me very well. `(https?|ftp)://(www\d?|[a-zA-Z0-9]+)?\.[a-zA-Z0-9-]+(\:|\.)([a-zA-Z0-9.]+|(\d+)?)([/?:].*)?`

Comment: Doesn't work, tested in https://regex101.com/. For instance, `https://demo.com`.

Answer (score 3):

For convenience here's a one-liner regexp for URL's that will also match localhost where you're more likely to have ports than `.com` or similar.

```
(http(s)?:\/\/.)?(www\.)?[-a-zA-Z0-9@:%._\+~#=]{2,256}(\.[a-z]{2,6}|:[0-9]{3,4})\b([-a-zA-Z0-9@:%_\+.~#?&\/\/=]*)
```

Answer (score 3):

I found the following Regex for URLs, **tested successfully with 500+ URLs**:

`/\b(?:(?:https?|ftp):\/\/)(?:\S+(?::\S*)?@)?(?:(?!10(?:\.\d{1,3}){3})(?!127(?:\.\d{1,3}){3})(?!169\.254(?:\.\d{1,3}){2})(?!192\.168(?:\.\d{1,3}){2})(?!172\.(?:1[6-9]|2\d|3[0-1])(?:\.\d{1,3}){2})(?:[1-9]\d?|1\d\d|2[01]\d|22[0-3])(?:\.(?:1?\d{1,2}|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])){2}(?:\.(?:[1-9]\d?|1\d\d|2[0-4]\d|25[0-4]))|(?:(?:[a-z\x{00a1}-\x{ffff}0-9]+-?)*[a-z\x{00a1}-\x{ffff}0-9]+)(?:\.(?:[a-z\x{00a1}-\x{ffff}0-9]+-?)*[a-z\x{00a1}-\x{ffff}0-9]+)*(?:\.(?:[a-z\x{00a1}-\x{ffff}]{2,})))(?::\d{2,5})?(?:\/[^\s]*)?\b/gi`

*I know it looks ugly, but the good thing is that it works. :)*

[Explanation and demo with **581 random URLs** on regex101.](https://regex101.com/r/hU9aV3/5)

Source: [In search of the perfect URL validation regex](https://mathiasbynens.be/demo/url-regex)

Comment: Your regex is doing the work in 155'000 steps. Here is another regex that is evaluating all the 580 URLS your provided in 19'000 steps [regex101 link](https://regex101.com/r/hU9aV3/7): `/(https?):\/\/([\w-]+(\.[\\w-]+)*\.([a-z]+))(([\w.,@?^=%&amp;:\/~+#()!-]*)([\w@?^=%&amp;\/~+#()!-]))?/gi`

Comment: Though much shorter than @eyelidlessness 's answer, I believe his excludes the "noncharacters" from `FDD0-FDEF` and those ending in `FFFE` or `FFFF` and the "reserved" characters from `D800-DFFF` and yours does not.

Comment: fails with broken urls like:  `abc.co.i `

Comment: doesn't work for partial urls, or incomplete urls>

Answer (score 3):

To Match a URL there are various option and it depend on you requirement.
below are few.

```
_(^|[\s.:;?\-\]<\(])(https?://[-\w;/?:@&=+$\|\_.!~*\|'()\[\]%#,☺]+[\w/#](\(\))?)(?=$|[\s',\|\(\).:;?\-\[\]>\)])_i

#\b(([\w-]+://?|www[.])[^\s()<>]+(?:\([\w\d]+\)|([^[:punct:]\s]|/)))#iS
```

And there is a link which gives you more than 10 different variations of validation for URL.

https://mathiasbynens.be/demo/url-regex

Answer (score 2):

I think some people weren't able to use your php code because of the modifiers implied. I copied your code as is and used as an example:

```php
if(
    preg_match(
        "/^{$IRI_reference}$/iu",
        'http://www.url.com'
    )
){
    echo 'true';
}
```

Notice the "i" and "u" modifiers. without "u" php throws an exception saying:

```
Warning: preg_match() [function.preg-match]: Compilation failed: character value in \x{...} sequence is too large at offset XX
```

Answer (score 2):

I tried to formulate my version of url. My requirement was to capture instances in a String where possible url can be cse.uom.ac.mu - noting that it is not preceded by http nor www

```java
String regularExpression = "((((ht{2}ps?://)?)((w{3}\\.)?))?)[^.&&[a-zA-Z0-9]][a-zA-Z0-9.-]+[^.&&[a-zA-Z0-9]](\\.[a-zA-Z]{2,3})";

assertTrue("www.google.com".matches(regularExpression));
assertTrue("www.google.co.uk".matches(regularExpression));
assertTrue("http://www.google.com".matches(regularExpression));
assertTrue("http://www.google.co.uk".matches(regularExpression));
assertTrue("https://www.google.com".matches(regularExpression));
assertTrue("https://www.google.co.uk".matches(regularExpression));
assertTrue("google.com".matches(regularExpression));
assertTrue("google.co.uk".matches(regularExpression));
assertTrue("google.mu".matches(regularExpression));
assertTrue("mes.intnet.mu".matches(regularExpression));
assertTrue("cse.uom.ac.mu".matches(regularExpression));

//cannot contain 2 '.' after www
assertFalse("www..dr.google".matches(regularExpression));

//cannot contain 2 '.' just before com
assertFalse("www.dr.google..com".matches(regularExpression));

// to test case where url www must be followed with a '.'
assertFalse("www:google.com".matches(regularExpression));

// to test case where url www must be followed with a '.'
//assertFalse("http://wwwe.google.com".matches(regularExpression));

// to test case where www must be preceded with a '.'
assertFalse("https://www@.google.com".matches(regularExpression));
```

Comment: you really use `ht{2}ps?` rather then `https?`

Comment: It should give the same result, but yeah you are right.
But I was on an experimental phase of regular expression and wanted to try all its syntax. Thanks for pointing this out.

Answer (score 2):

The following RegEx will work:

```
"@((((ht)|(f))tp[s]?://)|(www\.))([a-z][-a-z0-9]+\.)?([a-z][-a-z0-9]+\.)?[a-z][-a-z0-9]+\.[a-z]+[/]?[a-z0-9._\/~#&=;%+?-]*@si"
```

Answer (score 2):

Use this one its working for me

```
function validUrl(Url) {
    var myRegExp  =/^(?:(?:https?|ftp):\/\/)(?:\S+(?::\S*)?@)?(?:(?!10(?:\.\d{1,3}){3})(?!127(?:\.\d{1,3}){3})(?!169\.254(?:\.\d{1,3}){2})(?!192\.168(?:\.\d{1,3}){2})(?!172\.(?:1[6-9]|2\d|3[0-1])(?:\.\d{1,3}){2})(?:[1-9]\d?|1\d\d|2[01]\d|22[0-3])(?:\.(?:1?\d{1,2}|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])){2}(?:\.(?:[1-9]\d?|1\d\d|2[0-4]\d|25[0-4]))|(?:(?:[a-z\u00a1-\uffff0-9]+-?)*[a-z\u00a1-\uffff0-9]+)(?:\.(?:[a-z\u00a1-\uffff0-9]+-?)*[a-z\u00a1-\uffff0-9]+)*(?:\.(?:[a-z\u00a1-\uffff]{2,})))(?::\d{2,5})?(?:\/[^\s]*)?$/i;

    if (!RegExp.test(Url.value)) {
        $("#urlErrorLbl").removeClass('highlightNew');
        return false;
    } 

    $("#urlErrorLbl").addClass('highlightNew'); 
    return true; 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't specify which language you're using.
If PHP is, there is a native function for that:

```php
$url = 'http://www.yoururl.co.uk/sub1/sub2/?param=1&param2/';

if ( ! filter_var( $url, FILTER_VALIDATE_URL ) ) {
    // Wrong
}
else {
    // Valid
}
```

Returns the filtered data, or FALSE if the filter fails.

[Check it here >>](http://php.net/manual/en/function.filter-var.php)

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 2):

```
https?:\/{2}(?:[\/-\w.]|(?:%[\da-fA-F]{2}))+
```

You can use this pattern for detecting URLs.

Following is the proof of concept

[RegExr: URL Detector](https://regexr.com/48chr)

Answer (score 1):

whats wrong with plain and simple FILTER_VALIDATE_URL ?

```php
 $url = "http://www.example.com";

if(!filter_var($url, FILTER_VALIDATE_URL))
  {
  echo "URL is not valid";
  }
else
  {
  echo "URL is valid";
  }
```

I know its not the question exactly but it did the job for me when I needed to validate urls so thought it might be useful to others who come across this post looking for the same thing

Comment: This question is looking for a regexp but you suggest using some filter constant. Do you know how does it searches for links internally?

Comment: The question is: "What is the best regular expression to check if a string is a valid URL?" sometimes the problem is not to check a String that is supposed to be an URL, sometimes you have a text and you need to read all the URLs in that text, and using REGEX is the only way. Furthermore the OP asks for a solution without specifing a particular language, your solution can be applied only in a specific platform.

Answer (score 1):

To Check URL regex would be:

```
^http(s{0,1})://[a-zA-Z0-9_/\\-\\.]+\\.([A-Za-z/]{2,5})[a-zA-Z0-9_/\\&\\?\\=\\-\\.\\~\\%]*
```

Comment: it will not accept feed,ftp or any url other then http/https.

Comment: yes, its only for url which starts with 'http' or 'https'... but you can simply add ftp or other protocol by modyfying it.

Answer (score 1):

I created a similar regex (**PCRE**) to the one @eyelidlessness provided following RFC3987 along with other RFC documents. The major difference between @eyelidlessness and my regex are mainly readability and also URN support.

The regex below is all one piece (instead of being mixed with PHP) so it can be used in different languages very easily (so long as they support PCRE)

**The easiest way to test this regex is to use [regex101](http://regex101.com) and copy paste the code and test strings below with the appropriate modifiers (`gmx`).**

To use this regex in PHP, insert the regex below into the following code:

```php
$regex = <<<'EOD'
// Put the regex here
EOD;
```

---

You can match a link without a scheme by doing the following:
To match a link without a scheme (i.e. `john.doe@gmail.com` or `www.google.com/pathtofile.php?query`), replace this section:

```
  (?:
    (?<scheme>
      (?<urn>urn)|
      (?&d_scheme)
    )
    :
  )?
```

with this:

```
  (?:
    (?<scheme>
      (?<urn>urn)|
      (?&d_scheme)
    )
    :
  )?
```

Note, however, that by replacing this, the regex does not become 100% reliable.

---

**Regex (PCRE)** with `gmx` modifiers for the multi-line test string below

```
(?(DEFINE)
  # Definitions
  (?<ALPHA>[\p{L}])
  (?<DIGIT>[0-9])
  (?<HEX>[0-9a-fA-F])
  (?<NCCHAR>
    (?&UNRESERVED)|
    (?&PCT_ENCODED)|
    (?&SUB_DELIMS)|
    @
  )
  (?<PCHAR>
    (?&UNRESERVED)|
    (?&PCT_ENCODED)|
    (?&SUB_DELIMS)|
    :|
    @|
    \/
  )
  (?<UCHAR>
    (?&UNRESERVED)|
    (?&PCT_ENCODED)|
    (?&SUB_DELIMS)|
    :
  )
  (?<RCHAR>
    (?&UNRESERVED)|
    (?&PCT_ENCODED)|
    (?&SUB_DELIMS)
  )
  (?<PCT_ENCODED>%(?&HEX){2})
  (?<UNRESERVED>
    ((?&ALPHA)|(?&DIGIT)|[-._~])
  )
  (?<RESERVED>(?&GEN_DELIMS)|(?&SUB_DELIMS))
  (?<GEN_DELIMS>[:\/?#\[\]@])
  (?<SUB_DELIMS>[!$&'()*+,;=])
  # URI Parts
  (?<d_scheme>
    (?!urn)
    (?:
      (?&ALPHA)
      ((?&ALPHA)|(?&DIGIT)|[+-.])*
      (?=:)
    )
  )
  (?<d_hier_part_slashes>
    (\/{2})?
  )
  (?<d_authority>(?&d_userinfo)?)
  (?<d_userinfo>(?&UCHAR)*)
  (?<d_ipv6>
    (?![^:]*::[^:]*::[^:]*)
    (
      (
        ((?&HEX){0,4})
        :
      ){1,7}
      ((?&d_ipv4)|:|(?&HEX){1,4})
    )
  )
  (?<d_ipv4>
    ((?&octet)\.){3}
    (?&octet)
  )
  (?<octet>
    (
      25[]0-5]|
      2[0-4](?&DIGIT)|
      1(?&DIGIT){2}|
      [1-9](?&DIGIT)|
      (?&DIGIT)
    )
  )
  (?<d_reg_name>(?&RCHAR)*)
  (?<d_urn_name>(?&UCHAR)*)
  (?<d_port>(?&DIGIT)*)
  (?<d_path>
    (
      \/
      ((?&PCHAR)*)*
      (?=\?|\#|$)
    )
  )
  (?<d_query>
    (
      ((?&PCHAR)|\/|\?)*
    )?
  )
  (?<d_fragment>
    (
      ((?&PCHAR)|\/|\?)*
    )?
  )
)
^
(?<link>
  (?:
    (?<scheme>
      (?<urn>urn)|
      (?&d_scheme)
    )
    :
  )
  (?(urn)
    (?:
      (?<namespace_identifier>[0-9a-zA-Z\-]+)
      :
      (?<namespace_specific_string>(?&d_urn_name)+)
    )
    |
    (?<hier_part>
      (?<slashes>(?&d_hier_part_slashes))
      (?<authority>
        (?:
          (?<userinfo>(?&d_authority))
          @
        )?
        (?<host>
          (?<ipv4>\[?(?&d_ipv4)\]?)|
          (?<ipv6>\[(?&d_ipv6)\])|
          (?<domain>(?&d_reg_name))
        )
        (?:
          :
          (?<port>(?&d_port))
        )?
      )
      (?<path>(?&d_path))?
    )
    (?:
      \?
      (?<query>(?&d_query))
    )?
    (?:
      \#
      (?<fragment>(?&d_fragment))
    )?
  )
)
$
```

**Test Strings**

```
# Valid URIs
ftp://cnn.example.com&story=breaking_news@10.0.0.1/top_story.htm
ftp://ftp.is.co.za/rfc/rfc1808.txt
http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2396.txt
ldap://[2001:db8::7]/c=GB?objectClass?one
mailto:John.Doe@example.com
news:comp.infosystems.www.servers.unix
tel:+1-816-555-1212
telnet://192.0.2.16:80/
urn:isbn:0451450523
urn:oid:2.16.840
urn:isan:0000-0000-9E59-0000-O-0000-0000-2
urn:oasis:names:specification:docbook:dtd:xml:4.1.2
http://localhost/test/somefile.php?query=someval&variable=value#fragment
http://[2001:db8:a0b:12f0::1]/test
ftp://username:password@domain.com/path/to/file/somefile.html?queryVariable=value#fragment
https://subdomain.domain.com/path/to/file.php?query=value#fragment
https://subdomain.example.com/path/to/file.php?query=value#fragment
mailto:john.smith(comment)@example.com
mailto:user@[2001:DB8::1]
mailto:user@[255:192:168:1]
mailto:M.Handley@cs.ucl.ac.uk
http://localhost:4433/path/to/file?query#fragment
# Note that the example below IS a valid as it does follow RFC standards
localhost:4433/path/to/file

# These work with the optional scheme group although I'd suggest making the scheme mandatory as misinterpretations can occur
john.doe@gmail.com
www.google.com/pathtofile.php?query
[192a:123::192.168.1.1]:80/path/to/file.html?query#fragment
```

Answer (score 1):

This is not a regular expression but accomplishes the same thing (Javascript only):

```js
function isAValidUrl(url) {
  try {
    new URL(url);
    return true;
  } catch(e) {
    return false;
  }
}
```

Comment: @AliHabibzadeh no, your comment is not true. I tested. But this allows htt:// for instance. I guess it allows anything as a protocol except of course space character.

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

```
^(https?:\/\/(?:www\.|(?!www))[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9-]+[a-zA-Z0-9]\.[^\s]{2,}|www\.[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9-]+[a-zA-Z0-9]\.[^\s]{2,}|https?:\/\/(?:www\.|(?!www))[a-zA-Z0-9]\.[^\s]{2,}|www\.[a-zA-Z0-9]\.[^\s]{2,})$
```

These are the test cases:

[image: Test cases]

You can try it out in [here : https://regex101.com/r/mS9gD7/41](https://regex101.com/r/mS9gD7/41)

Answer (score 1):

**IMPROVED**

Detects Urls like these:

- https://www.example.pl
- http://www.example.com
- www.example.pl
- example.com
- http://blog.example.com
- http://www.example.com/product
- http://www.example.com/products?id=1&page=2
- http://www.example.com#up
- http://255.255.255.255
- 255.255.255.255
- http:// www.site.com:8008

Regex:

```
/^(?:http(s)?:\/\/)?[\w.-]+(?:\.[\w\.-]+)+[\w\-\._~:/?#[\]@!\$&'\(\)\*\+,;=.]+$/gm
```

Comment: http://www.x.com.y is not correct, but it results ina  a pass.

Answer (score 1):

I use this: `/((https?:\/\/|ftp:\/\/|www\.)\S+\.[^()\n ]+((?:\([^)]*\))|[^.,;:?!"'\n\)\]<* ])+)/`

It's short, but it handles edge cases like certain Wikipedia links (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sally_(name)) that ends in a bracket, which the most voted answers here don't seem to cover.

Answer (score 0):

This is a rather old thread now and the question asks for a regex based URL validator.  I ran into the thread whilst looking for precisely the same thing.  While it may well be possible to write a really comprehensive regex to validate URLs. I eventually settled on another way to do things - by using PHP's [parse_url](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php) function.

It returns boolean false if the url cannot be parsed. Otherwise, it returns the scheme, the host and other information.  This may well not be enough for a comprehensive URL check on its own, but can be drilled down into for further analysis.  If the intent is to simply catch typos, invalid schemes etc. It is perfectly adequate!

Answer (score 0):

Here is the best and the most matched regex for this situation

```
^(?:http(?:s)?:\/\/)?(?:www\.)?(?:[\w-]*)\.\w{2,}$
```

Comment: The question asks for URL, not just domain part.

Answer (score 0):

To match the URL up to the domain:

```
(^(\bhttp)(|s):\/{2})(?=[a-z0-9-_]{1,255})\.\1\.([a-z]{3,7}$)
```

It can be simplified to:

```
(^(\bhttp)(|s):\/{2})(?=[a-z0-9-_.]{1,255})\.([a-z]{3,7})
```

the latter does not check for the end for the end line so that it can be later used create full blown URL with full paths and query strings.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```js
function validateUrl(value){
 return /^(http(s)?:\/\/.)?(www\.)?[-a-zA-Z0-9@:%._\+~#=]{2,256}\.[a-z]{2,6}\b([-a-zA-Z0-9@:%_\+.~#?&//=]*)$/gi.test(value);
}

console.log(validateUrl('google.com')); // true
console.log(validateUrl('www.google.com')); // true
console.log(validateUrl('http://www.google.com')); // true
console.log(validateUrl('http:/www.google.com')); // false
console.log(validateUrl('www.google.com/test')); // true
```

Comment: Thank you Daniel, you need to add port support like http://localhost:8080

Answer (score 0):

I think I found a more general regexp to validate urls, particularly websites

```
​(https?:\/\/)?(www\.)[-a-zA-Z0-9@:%._\+~#=]{2,256}\.[a-z]{2,4}\b([-a-zA-Z0-9@:%_\+.~#?&//=]*)|(https?:\/\/)?(www\.)?(?!ww)[-a-zA-Z0-9@:%._\+~#=]{2,256}\.[a-z]{2,4}\b([-a-zA-Z0-9@:%_\+.~#?&//=]*)
```

it does not allow for instance www.something or http://www or http://www.something

Check it here: http://regexr.com/3e4a2

Answer (score 0):

As far as I have found, this expression is good for me-

```
(https?:\/\/(?:www\.|(?!www))[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9-]+[a-zA-Z0-9]\.[^\s]{2,}|https?:\/\/(?:www\.|(?!www))[a-zA-Z0-9]\.[^\s]{2,}|www\.[a-zA-Z0-9]\.[^\s]{2,})
```

Working example-

```js
function RegExForUrlMatch()
{
  var expression = /(https?:\/\/(?:www\.|(?!www))[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9-]+[a-zA-Z0-9]\.[^\s]{2,}|https?:\/\/(?:www\.|(?!www))[a-zA-Z0-9]\.[^\s]{2,}|www\.[a-zA-Z0-9]\.[^\s]{2,})/g;

  var regex = new RegExp(expression);
  var t = document.getElementById("url").value;

  if (t.match(regex)) {
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Successful match";
  } else {
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "No match";
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="url" placeholder="url" onkeyup="RegExForUrlMatch()">

<p id="demo">Please enter a URL to test</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Below expression will work for all popular domains. It will accept following urls:

- www.yourwebsite.com
- http://www.yourwebsite.com
- www.yourwebsite.com
- yourwebsite.com
- yourwebsite.co.in

In addition it will make message with url as link also
e.g. `please visit yourwebsite.com`
In above example it will make `yourwebsite.com` as hyperlink

```js
if (new RegExp("([-a-z0-9]{1,63}\\.)*?[a-z0-9][-a-z0-9]{0,61}[a-z0-9]\\.(com|com/|org|gov|cm|net|online|live|biz|us|uk|co.us|co.uk|in|co.in|int|info|edu|mil|ca|co|co.au|org/|gov/|cm/|net/|online/|live/|biz/|us/|uk/|co.us/|co.uk/|in/|co.in/|int/|info/|edu/|mil/|ca/|co/|co.au/)(/[-\\w@\\+\\.~#\\?*&/=% ]*)?$").test(strMessage) || (new RegExp("^[a-z ]+[\.]?[a-z ]+?[\.]+[a-z ]+?[\.]+[a-z ]+?[-\\w@\\+\\.~#\\?*&/=% ]*").test(strMessage) && new RegExp("([a-zA-Z0-9]+://)?([a-zA-Z0-9_]+:[a-zA-Z0-9_]+@)?([a-zA-Z0-9.-]+\\.[A-Za-z]{2,4})(:[0-9]+)?(/.*)?").test(strMessage)) || (new RegExp("^[a-z ]+[\.]?[a-z ]+?[-\\w@\\+\\.~#\\?*&/=% ]*").test(strMessage) && new RegExp("([a-zA-Z0-9]+://)?([a-zA-Z0-9_]+:[a-zA-Z0-9_]+@)?([a-zA-Z0-9.-]+\\.[A-Za-z]{2,4})(:[0-9]+)?(/.*)?").test(strMessage))) {
  if (new RegExp("^[a-z ]+[\.]?[a-z ]+?[\.]+[a-z ]+?[\.]+[a-z ]+?$").test(strMessage) && new RegExp("([a-zA-Z0-9]+://)?([a-zA-Z0-9_]+:[a-zA-Z0-9_]+@)?([a-zA-Z0-9.-]+\\.[A-Za-z]{2,4})(:[0-9]+)?(/.*)?").test(strMessage)) {
    var url1 = /(^|&lt;|\s)([\w\.]+\.(?:com|org|gov|cm|net|online|live|biz|us|uk|co.us|co.uk|in|co.in|int|info|edu|mil|ca|co|co.au))(\s|&gt;|$)/g;
    var html = $.trim(strMessage);
    if (html) {
      html = html.replace(url1, '$1<a style="color:blue; text-decoration:underline;" target="_blank"  href="http://$2">$2</a>$3');
    }
    returnString = html;
    return returnString;
  } else {
    var url1 = /(^|&lt;|\s)(www\..+?\.(?:com|org|gov|cm|net|online|live|biz|us|uk|co.us|co.uk|in|co.in|int|info|edu|mil|ca|co|co.au)[^,\s]*)(\s|&gt;|$)/g,
      url2 = /(^|&lt;|\s)(((https?|ftp):\/\/|mailto:).+?\.(?:com|org|gov|cm|net|online|live|biz|us|uk|co.us|co.uk|in|co.in|int|info|edu|mil|ca|co|co.au)[^,\s]*)(\s|&gt;|$)/g,
      url3 = /(^|&lt;|\s)([\w\.]+\.(?:com|org|gov|cm|net|online|live|biz|us|uk|co.us|co.uk|in|co.in|int|info|edu|mil|ca|co|co.au)[^,\s]*)(\s|&gt;|$)/g;

    var html = $.trim(strMessage);
    if (html) {
      html = html.replace(url1, '$1<a style="color:blue; text-decoration:underline;" target="_blank"  href="http://$2">$2</a>$3').replace(url2, '$1<a style="color:blue; text-decoration:underline;" target="_blank"  href="$2">$2</a>$5').replace(url3, '$1<a style="color:blue; text-decoration:underline;" target="_blank"  href="http://$2">$2</a>$3');
    }
    returnString = html;

    return returnString;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

After rigorous searching i finally settled with the following

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9]+\:\/\/[a-zA-Z0-9]+\.[-a-zA-Z0-9]+\.?[a-zA-Z0-9]+$|^[a-zA-Z0-9]+\.[-a-zA-Z0-9]+\.[a-zA-Z0-9]+$
```

And this thing work for general in future URLs.

Answer (score 0):

The best regex, i've found is: `/(^|\s)((https?:\/\/)?[\w-]+(\.[\w-]+)+\.?(:\d+)?(\/\S*)?)/gi`

For ios swift : `(^|\\s)((https?:\\/\\/)?[\\w-]+(\\.[\\w-]+)+\\.?(:\\d+)?(\\/\\S*)?)`

http://jsfiddle.net/9BYdp/1/

Found [here](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/480)

Answer (score 0):

Interestingly, none of the answers above worked for what I needed, so I figured I would offer my solution. I needed to be able to do the following:

- Match `http(s)://www.google.com`, `http://google.com`, `www.google.com`, and `google.com`
- Match Github markdown style links like `[Google](http://www.google.com)`
- Match all possible domain extensions, like .com, or .io, or .guru, etc. Basically anything between 2-6 characters in length
- Split everything into proper groupings so that I could access each part as needed.

Here was the solution:

```
/^(\[[A-z0-9 _]*\]\()?((?:(http|https):\/\/)?(?:[\w-]+\.)+[a-z]{2,6})(\))?$
```

This gives me all of the above requirements.  You could optionally add the ability for ftp and file if necessary:

```
/^(\[[A-z0-9 _]*\]\()?((?:(http|https|ftp|file):\/\/)?(?:[\w-]+\.)+[a-z]{2,6})(\))?$
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it is a very simple way. And it works very good.

```js
var hasURL = (str) =>{
 var url_pattern = new RegExp("(www.|http://|https://|ftp://)\w*");
 if(!url_pattern.test(str)){
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = 'No URL';
 }
 else
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = 'String has a URL';
};
```

```html
<p>Please enter a string and test it has any url or not</p>
<input type="text" id="url" placeholder="url" onkeyup="hasURL(document.getElementById('url').value)">
<p id="demo"></p>
```

Comment: Your regex doesn't work at all bro. All it validates is that your string contains either `www` immediately followed by **one** character (any character since you haven't escaped the `.`) or `http://` or `https://` or `ftp://` and any of these **can** be followed by any alphanumeric characters. So, in other words, all the following strings would result as being valid but they are obviously not valid urls : `www.`, `www▓`, `£¢¤£¢¤www¢` (See on [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/WOAt0M/2/tests)). You could have used a shorter regex: `(www.|(https?|ftp)://)\w*`. (This is still not a good regex btw)

Comment: Obviously www. , www▓, £¢¤£¢¤www¢ those are not valid urls. But I think, those are not also meaningful string. I just try to simplify the url pattern. @ DrunkenPoney

Comment: My goal wasn't to write *meaningful* strings but to show that weird strings would be accepted and anyway since your regex *validate* for `www` I suppose you don't necessarily need the protocol to be specified but your regex wouldn't allow urls like `google.com`. Moreover, one of the problems I was trying to show you is that your regex matches wherever the *validation parts* (`www`, `http`, ...) are in the string. You could at least specify that your string needs to start with it.

Comment: And if you want a quick regex to validate url but is not 100% safe [here](https://regex101.com/r/Q2ilqN/7) is one I made which I used to extract the different parts from an url but can be used to validate that a string contains the base parts of an url.

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to apply a more strict rule, here is what I have developed:

```
isValidUrl(input) {
    var regex = /^(((H|h)(T|t)(T|t)(P|p)(S|s)?):\/\/)?[-a-zA-Z0-9@:%._\+~#=]{2,100}\.[a-zA-Z]{2,10}(\/([-a-zA-Z0-9@:%_\+.~#?&//=]*))?/
    return regex.test(input)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Regardless the broad question asked, I post this for anyone in the future who is looking for something simple... as I think validating a URL has no perfect regular expression that fit all needs, it depends on your requirements, i.e: in my case, I just needed to verify if a URL is in the form of `domain.extension` and I wanted to allow the `www` or any other subdomain like `blog.domain.extension` I don't care about http(s) as in my app I have a field which says "enter the URL" so it's obvious what that entered string is.

so here is the regEx:

```
/^(www\.|[a-zA-Z0-9](.*[a-zA-Z0-9])?\.)?((?!www)[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9-]+[a-zA-Z0-9])\.[a-z]{2,5}(:[0-9]{1,5})?$/i
```

The first block in this regExp is:

`(www\.|[a-zA-Z0-9](.*[a-zA-Z0-9])?\.)?` ---> we start to check if the URL start with `www.` or `[a-zA-Z0-9](.*[a-zA-Z0-9])?` which means a letterOrNumber + **(anyCharacter(0 or multiple times) + another letterOrNumber) followed with a dot**

Note that the `(.*[a-zA-Z0-9])?\.)?` we translated by **(anyCharacter(0 or multiple times) + another letterOrNumber)**
is optional (can be or not) that's why we grouped it between parentheses and followed with the question mark `?`

the whole block we discussed so far is also put between parentheses and followed by ? which means both www or any other word (that represents a subdomain) is optional.

The second part is: `((?!www)[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9-]+[a-zA-Z0-9])\.` ---> which represents the "domain" part, it can be any word (except www) starting with an alphabet or a number + any other alphabet (including dash "-") repeated one or more time, and ending with any alphabet or number followed with a dot.

The final part is `[a-z]{2,}` ---> which represent the "extension", it can be any alphabet repeated 2 or more times, so it can be com, net, org, art basically any extension

Comment: doesn't work with domains that consist of only 2 characters.

Answer (score 0):

A simple check for URL is

```
^(ftp|http|https):\/\/[^ "]+$
```

Answer (score 0):

The following Regex works for me:

```
(http(s)?:\/\/.)?(ftp(s)?:\/\/.)?(www\.)?[-a-zA-Z0-9@:%._\+~#=]{0,256}\.[a-z] 
{2,6}\b([-a-zA-Z0-9@:%_\+.~#?&//=]*)
```

matches:

```
https://google.com t.me https://t.me ftp://google.com http://sm.tj http://bro.tj t.me/rshss https:google.com www.cool.com.au http://www.cool.com.au http://www.cool.com.au/ersdfs http://www.cool.com.au/ersdfs?dfd=dfgd@s=1 http://www.cool.com:81/index.html
```

Answer (score 0):

Javascript now has a URL Constructor called `new URL()`. It allows you to skip REGEX completely.

```js
/**
 * 
 * The URL() constructor returns a newly created URL object representing 
 * the URL defined by the parameters. 
 * 
 * https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/URL
 * 
 */
let requestUrl = new URL('https://username:password@developer.mozilla.org:8080/en-US/docs/search.html?par1=abc&par2=123&par3=true#Recent');

let urlParts = {
  origin: requestUrl.origin,
  href: requestUrl.href,
  protocol: requestUrl.protocol,
  username: requestUrl.username,
  password: requestUrl.password,
  host: requestUrl.host,
  hostname: requestUrl.hostname,
  port: requestUrl.port,
  pathname: requestUrl.pathname,
  search: requestUrl.search,
  searchParams: {
    par1: String(requestUrl.searchParams.get('par1')),
    par2: Number(requestUrl.searchParams.get('par2')),
    par3: Boolean(requestUrl.searchParams.get('par3')),
  },
  hash: requestUrl.hash      
};

console.log(urlParts);
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you to @eyelidlessness for the extremely thorough (albeit long) RFC based regular expression.

For those of us using EICMAScript / JavaScript / Apps Script it doesn't work, however. Here is an otherwise exact replica of his answer that will work with these (along with a snippet to run for example - neat new feature!):

```js
regEx_valid_URL = /^[a-z](?:[-a-z0-9\+\.])*:(?:\/\/(?:(?:%[0-9a-f][0-9a-f]|[-a-z0-9\._~\uA0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF\u10000-\u1FFFD\u20000-\u2FFFD\u30000-\u3FFFD\u40000-\u4FFFD\u50000-\u5FFFD\u60000-\u6FFFD\u70000-\u7FFFD\u80000-\u8FFFD\u90000-\u9FFFD\uA0000-\uAFFFD\uB0000-\uBFFFD\uC0000-\uCFFFD\uD0000-\uDFFFD\uE1000-\uEFFFD!\$&'\(\)\*\+,;=:])*@)?(?:\[(?:(?:(?:[0-9a-f]{1,4}:){6}(?:[0-9a-f]{1,4}:[0-9a-f]{1,4}|(?:[0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9][0-9]|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])(?:\.(?:[0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9][0-9]|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])){3})|::(?:[0-9a-f]{1,4}:){5}(?:[0-9a-f]{1,4}:[0-9a-f]{1,4}|(?:[0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9][0-9]|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])(?:\.(?:[0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9][0-9]|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])){3})|(?:[0-9a-f]{1,4})?::(?:[0-9a-f]{1,4}:){4}(?:[0-9a-f]{1,4}:[0-9a-f]{1,4}|(?:[0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9][0-9]|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])(?:\.(?:[0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9][0-9]|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])){3})|(?:(?:[0-9a-f]{1,4}:){0,1}[0-9a-f]{1,4})?::(?:[0-9a-f]{1,4}:){3}(?:[0-9a-f]{1,4}:[0-9a-f]{1,4}|(?:[0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9][0-9]|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])(?:\.(?:[0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9][0-9]|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])){3})|(?:(?:[0-9a-f]{1,4}:){0,2}[0-9a-f]{1,4})?::(?:[0-9a-f]{1,4}:){2}(?:[0-9a-f]{1,4}:[0-9a-f]{1,4}|(?:[0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9][0-9]|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])(?:\.(?:[0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9][0-9]|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])){3})|(?:(?:[0-9a-f]{1,4}:){0,3}[0-9a-f]{1,4})?::[0-9a-f]{1,4}:(?:[0-9a-f]{1,4}:[0-9a-f]{1,4}|(?:[0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9][0-9]|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])(?:\.(?:[0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9][0-9]|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])){3})|(?:(?:[0-9a-f]{1,4}:){0,4}[0-9a-f]{1,4})?::(?:[0-9a-f]{1,4}:[0-9a-f]{1,4}|(?:[0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9][0-9]|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])(?:\.(?:[0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9][0-9]|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])){3})|(?:(?:[0-9a-f]{1,4}:){0,5}[0-9a-f]{1,4})?::[0-9a-f]{1,4}|(?:(?:[0-9a-f]{1,4}:){0,6}[0-9a-f]{1,4})?::)|v[0-9a-f]+\.[-a-z0-9\._~!\$&'\(\)\*\+,;=:]+)\]|(?:[0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9][0-9]|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])(?:\.(?:[0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9][0-9]|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])){3}|(?:%[0-9a-f][0-9a-f]|[-a-z0-9\._~\uA0}-\uD7FF}\uF900-\uFDCF}\uFDF0}-\uFFEF}\u10000-\u1FFFD\u20000-\u2FFFD\u30000-\u3FFFD\u40000-\u4FFFD\u50000-\u5FFFD\u60000-\u6FFFD\u70000-\u7FFFD\u80000-\u8FFFD\u90000-\u9FFFD\uA0000-\uAFFFD\uB0000-\uBFFFD\uC0000-\uCFFFD\uD0000-\uDFFFD\uE1000-\uEFFFD!\$&'\(\)\*\+,;=])*)(?::[0-9]*)?(?:\/(?:(?:%[0-9a-f][0-9a-f]|[-a-z0-9\._~\uA0}-\uD7FF}\uF900-\uFDCF}\uFDF0}-\uFFEF}\u10000-\u1FFFD\u20000-\u2FFFD\u30000-\u3FFFD\u40000-\u4FFFD\u50000-\u5FFFD\u60000-\u6FFFD\u70000-\u7FFFD\u80000-\u8FFFD\u90000-\u9FFFD\uA0000-\uAFFFD\uB0000-\uBFFFD\uC0000-\uCFFFD\uD0000-\uDFFFD\uE1000-\uEFFFD!\$&'\(\)\*\+,;=:@]))*)*|\/(?:(?:(?:(?:%[0-9a-f][0-9a-f]|[-a-z0-9\._~\uA0}-\uD7FF}\uF900-\uFDCF}\uFDF0}-\uFFEF}\u10000-\u1FFFD\u20000-\u2FFFD\u30000-\u3FFFD\u40000-\u4FFFD\u50000-\u5FFFD\u60000-\u6FFFD\u70000-\u7FFFD\u80000-\u8FFFD\u90000-\u9FFFD\uA0000-\uAFFFD\uB0000-\uBFFFD\uC0000-\uCFFFD\uD0000-\uDFFFD\uE1000-\uEFFFD!\$&'\(\)\*\+,;=:@]))+)(?:\/(?:(?:%[0-9a-f][0-9a-f]|[-a-z0-9\._~\uA0}-\uD7FF}\uF900-\uFDCF}\uFDF0}-\uFFEF}\u10000-\u1FFFD\u20000-\u2FFFD\u30000-\u3FFFD\u40000-\u4FFFD\u50000-\u5FFFD\u60000-\u6FFFD\u70000-\u7FFFD\u80000-\u8FFFD\u90000-\u9FFFD\uA0000-\uAFFFD\uB0000-\uBFFFD\uC0000-\uCFFFD\uD0000-\uDFFFD\uE1000-\uEFFFD!\$&'\(\)\*\+,;=:@]))*)*)?|(?:(?:(?:%[0-9a-f][0-9a-f]|[-a-z0-9\._~\uA0}-\uD7FF}\uF900-\uFDCF}\uFDF0}-\uFFEF}\u10000-\u1FFFD\u20000-\u2FFFD\u30000-\u3FFFD\u40000-\u4FFFD\u50000-\u5FFFD\u60000-\u6FFFD\u70000-\u7FFFD\u80000-\u8FFFD\u90000-\u9FFFD\uA0000-\uAFFFD\uB0000-\uBFFFD\uC0000-\uCFFFD\uD0000-\uDFFFD\uE1000-\uEFFFD!\$&'\(\)\*\+,;=:@]))+)(?:\/(?:(?:%[0-9a-f][0-9a-f]|[-a-z0-9\._~\uA0}-\uD7FF}\uF900-\uFDCF}\uFDF0}-\uFFEF}\u10000-\u1FFFD\u20000-\u2FFFD\u30000-\u3FFFD\u40000-\u4FFFD\u50000-\u5FFFD\u60000-\u6FFFD\u70000-\u7FFFD\u80000-\u8FFFD\u90000-\u9FFFD\uA0000-\uAFFFD\uB0000-\uBFFFD\uC0000-\uCFFFD\uD0000-\uDFFFD\uE1000-\uEFFFD!\$&'\(\)\*\+,;=:@]))*)*|(?!(?:%[0-9a-f][0-9a-f]|[-a-z0-9\._~\uA0}-\uD7FF}\uF900-\uFDCF}\uFDF0}-\uFFEF}\u10000-\u1FFFD\u20000-\u2FFFD\u30000-\u3FFFD\u40000-\u4FFFD\u50000-\u5FFFD\u60000-\u6FFFD\u70000-\u7FFFD\u80000-\u8FFFD\u90000-\u9FFFD\uA0000-\uAFFFD\uB0000-\uBFFFD\uC0000-\uCFFFD\uD0000-\uDFFFD\uE1000-\uEFFFD!\$&'\(\)\*\+,;=:@])))(?:\?(?:(?:%[0-9a-f][0-9a-f]|[-a-z0-9\._~\uA0}-\uD7FF}\uF900-\uFDCF}\uFDF0}-\uFFEF}\u10000-\u1FFFD\u20000-\u2FFFD\u30000-\u3FFFD\u40000-\u4FFFD\u50000-\u5FFFD\u60000-\u6FFFD\u70000-\u7FFFD\u80000-\u8FFFD\u90000-\u9FFFD\uA0000-\uAFFFD\uB0000-\uBFFFD\uC0000-\uCFFFD\uD0000-\uDFFFD\uE1000-\uEFFFD!\$&'\(\)\*\+,;=:@])|[\uE000-\uF8FF}\uF0000-\uFFFFD\u100000-\u10FFFD\/\?])*)?(?:\#(?:(?:%[0-9a-f][0-9a-f]|[-a-z0-9\._~\uA0}-\uD7FF}\uF900-\uFDCF}\uFDF0}-\uFFEF}\u10000-\u1FFFD\u20000-\u2FFFD\u30000-\u3FFFD\u40000-\u4FFFD\u50000-\u5FFFD\u60000-\u6FFFD\u70000-\u7FFFD\u80000-\u8FFFD\u90000-\u9FFFD\uA0000-\uAFFFD\uB0000-\uBFFFD\uC0000-\uCFFFD\uD0000-\uDFFFD\uE1000-\uEFFFD!\$&'\(\)\*\+,;=:@])|[\/\?])*)?$/i;

checkedURL = RegExp(regEx_valid_URL).exec('gopher://example.somewhere.university/');

if (checkedURL != null) {
 console.log('The URL ' + checkedURL + ' is valid');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
[(http(s)?):\/\/(www\.)?a-zA-Z0-9@:%._\+~#=]{2,256}\.[a-z]{2,6}\b([-a-zA-Z0-9@:%_\+.~#?&//=]*)
```

Answer (score 0):

## URL regexes from Android Open Source Project

### Introduction

The ***Android Open Source Project*** (AOSP) contains multiple code blocks with URL regular expressions in [Patterns.java](https://github.com/aosp-mirror/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/java/android/util/Patterns.java). It can be difficult for non-Java users to extract the regex patterns out of it because of unicode, so I wrote some code to do it. Because the regex patterns contain unicode, which literal string syntax can differ per programming language, I've added two formats of each regex pattern.
For example, Java uses `\uUNICODE_NUMBER` format, whereas PHP uses `\u{UNICODE_NUMBER}`.

### Pattern called "*WEB_URL*"

Description from API doc:

> Regular expression pattern to match most part of RFC 3987 Internationalized URLs, aka IRIs.

Regex in unicode `\uUNICODE_NUMBER` (Java, Python, Ruby) format:

````
(((?:(?i:http|https|rtsp|ftp)://(?:(?:[a-zA-Z0-9\$\-\_\.\+\!\*\'\(\)\,\;\?\&\=]|(?:\%[a-fA-F0-9]{2})){1,64}(?:\:(?:[a-zA-Z0-9\$\-\_\.\+\!\*\'\(\)\,\;\?\&\=]|(?:\%[a-fA-F0-9]{2})){1,25})?\@)?)?(?:(([a-zA-Z0-9[\u00a0-\ud7ff\uf900-\ufdcf\ufdf0-\uffef\ud800\udc00-\ud83f\udffd\ud840\udc00-\ud87f\udffd\ud880\udc00-\ud8bf\udffd\ud8c0\udc00-\ud8ff\udffd\ud900\udc00-\ud93f\udffd\ud940\udc00-\ud97f\udffd\ud980\udc00-\ud9bf\udffd\ud9c0\udc00-\ud9ff\udffd\uda00\udc00-\uda3f\udffd\uda40\udc00-\uda7f\udffd\uda80\udc00-\udabf\udffd\udac0\udc00-\udaff\udffd\udb00\udc00-\udb3f\udffd\udb44\udc00-\udb7f\udffd&&[^\u00a0[\u2000-\u200a]\u2028\u2029\u202f\u3000]]](?:[a-zA-Z0-9[\u00a0-\ud7ff\uf900-\ufdcf\ufdf0-\uffef\ud800\udc00-\ud83f\udffd\ud840\udc00-\ud87f\udffd\ud880\udc00-\ud8bf\udffd\ud8c0\udc00-\ud8ff\udffd\ud900\udc00-\ud93f\udffd\ud940\udc00-\ud97f\udffd\ud980\udc00-\ud9bf\udffd\ud9c0\udc00-\ud9ff\udffd\uda00\udc00-\uda3f\udffd\uda40\udc00-\uda7f\udffd\uda80\udc00-\udabf\udffd\udac0\udc00-\udaff\udffd\udb00\udc00-\udb3f\udffd\udb44\udc00-\udb7f\udffd&&[^\u00a0[\u2000-\u200a]\u2028\u2029\u202f\u3000]]_\-]{0,61}[a-zA-Z0-9[\u00a0-\ud7ff\uf900-\ufdcf\ufdf0-\uffef\ud800\udc00-\ud83f\udffd\ud840\udc00-\ud87f\udffd\ud880\udc00-\ud8bf\udffd\ud8c0\udc00-\ud8ff\udffd\ud900\udc00-\ud93f\udffd\ud940\udc00-\ud97f\udffd\ud980\udc00-\ud9bf\udffd\ud9c0\udc00-\ud9ff\udffd\uda00\udc00-\uda3f\udffd\uda40\udc00-\uda7f\udffd\uda80\udc00-\udabf\udffd\udac0\udc00-\udaff\udffd\udb00\udc00-\udb3f\udffd\udb44\udc00-\udb7f\udffd&&[^\u00a0[\u2000-\u200a]\u2028\u2029\u202f\u3000]]]){0,1}\.)+(xn\-\-[\w\-]{0,58}\w|[a-zA-Z[\u00a0-\ud7ff\uf900-\ufdcf\ufdf0-\uffef\ud800\udc00-\ud83f\udffd\ud840\udc00-\ud87f\udffd\ud880\udc00-\ud8bf\udffd\ud8c0\udc00-\ud8ff\udffd\ud900\udc00-\ud93f\udffd\ud940\udc00-\ud97f\udffd\ud980\udc00-\ud9bf\udffd\ud9c0\udc00-\ud9ff\udffd\uda00\udc00-\uda3f\udffd\uda40\udc00-\uda7f\udffd\uda80\udc00-\udabf\udffd\udac0\udc00-\udaff\udffd\udb00\udc00-\udb3f\udffd\udb44\udc00-\udb7f\udffd&&[^\u00a0[\u2000-\u200a]\u2028\u2029\u202f\u3000]]]{2,63})|((25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[0-1][0-9]{2}|[1-9][0-9]|[1-9])\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[0-1][0-9]{2}|[1-9][0-9]|[1-9]|0)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[0-1][0-9]{2}|[1-9][0-9]|[1-9]|0)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[0-1][0-9]{2}|[1-9][0-9]|[0-9]))))(?:\:\d{1,5})?)([/\?](?:(?:[a-zA-Z0-9[\u00a0-\ud7ff\uf900-\ufdcf\ufdf0-\uffef\ud800\udc00-\ud83f\udffd\ud840\udc00-\ud87f\udffd\ud880\udc00-\ud8bf\udffd\ud8c0\udc00-\ud8ff\udffd\ud900\udc00-\ud93f\udffd\ud940\udc00-\ud97f\udffd\ud980\udc00-\ud9bf\udffd\ud9c0\udc00-\ud9ff\udffd\uda00\udc00-\uda3f\udffd\uda40\udc00-\uda7f\udffd\uda80\udc00-\udabf\udffd\udac0\udc00-\udaff\udffd\udb00\udc00-\udb3f\udffd\udb44\udc00-\udb7f\udffd&&[^\u00a0[\u2000-\u200a]\u2028\u2029\u202f\u3000]];/\?:@&=#~\-\.\+!\*'\(\),_\$])|(?:%[a-fA-F0-9]{2}))*)?(?:\b|$|^))```
````

Regex in unicode `\u{UNICODE_NUMBER}` (PHP) format:

```
(((?:(?i:http|https|rtsp|ftp)://(?:(?:[a-zA-Z0-9\$\-\_\.\+\!\*\'\(\)\,\;\?\&\=]|(?:\%[a-fA-F0-9]{2})){1,64}(?:\:(?:[a-zA-Z0-9\$\-\_\.\+\!\*\'\(\)\,\;\?\&\=]|(?:\%[a-fA-F0-9]{2})){1,25})?\@)?)?(?:(([a-zA-Z0-9[\u{00a0}-\u{d7ff}\u{f900}-\u{fdcf}\u{fdf0}-\u{ffef}\u{d800}\u{dc00}-\u{d83f}\u{dffd}\u{d840}\u{dc00}-\u{d87f}\u{dffd}\u{d880}\u{dc00}-\u{d8bf}\u{dffd}\u{d8c0}\u{dc00}-\u{d8ff}\u{dffd}\u{d900}\u{dc00}-\u{d93f}\u{dffd}\u{d940}\u{dc00}-\u{d97f}\u{dffd}\u{d980}\u{dc00}-\u{d9bf}\u{dffd}\u{d9c0}\u{dc00}-\u{d9ff}\u{dffd}\u{da00}\u{dc00}-\u{da3f}\u{dffd}\u{da40}\u{dc00}-\u{da7f}\u{dffd}\u{da80}\u{dc00}-\u{dabf}\u{dffd}\u{dac0}\u{dc00}-\u{daff}\u{dffd}\u{db00}\u{dc00}-\u{db3f}\u{dffd}\u{db44}\u{dc00}-\u{db7f}\u{dffd}&&[^\u{00a0}[\u{2000}-\u{200a}]\u{2028}\u{2029}\u{202f}\u{3000}]]](?:[a-zA-Z0-9[\u{00a0}-\u{d7ff}\u{f900}-\u{fdcf}\u{fdf0}-\u{ffef}\u{d800}\u{dc00}-\u{d83f}\u{dffd}\u{d840}\u{dc00}-\u{d87f}\u{dffd}\u{d880}\u{dc00}-\u{d8bf}\u{dffd}\u{d8c0}\u{dc00}-\u{d8ff}\u{dffd}\u{d900}\u{dc00}-\u{d93f}\u{dffd}\u{d940}\u{dc00}-\u{d97f}\u{dffd}\u{d980}\u{dc00}-\u{d9bf}\u{dffd}\u{d9c0}\u{dc00}-\u{d9ff}\u{dffd}\u{da00}\u{dc00}-\u{da3f}\u{dffd}\u{da40}\u{dc00}-\u{da7f}\u{dffd}\u{da80}\u{dc00}-\u{dabf}\u{dffd}\u{dac0}\u{dc00}-\u{daff}\u{dffd}\u{db00}\u{dc00}-\u{db3f}\u{dffd}\u{db44}\u{dc00}-\u{db7f}\u{dffd}&&[^\u{00a0}[\u{2000}-\u{200a}]\u{2028}\u{2029}\u{202f}\u{3000}]]_\-]{0,61}[a-zA-Z0-9[\u{00a0}-\u{d7ff}\u{f900}-\u{fdcf}\u{fdf0}-\u{ffef}\u{d800}\u{dc00}-\u{d83f}\u{dffd}\u{d840}\u{dc00}-\u{d87f}\u{dffd}\u{d880}\u{dc00}-\u{d8bf}\u{dffd}\u{d8c0}\u{dc00}-\u{d8ff}\u{dffd}\u{d900}\u{dc00}-\u{d93f}\u{dffd}\u{d940}\u{dc00}-\u{d97f}\u{dffd}\u{d980}\u{dc00}-\u{d9bf}\u{dffd}\u{d9c0}\u{dc00}-\u{d9ff}\u{dffd}\u{da00}\u{dc00}-\u{da3f}\u{dffd}\u{da40}\u{dc00}-\u{da7f}\u{dffd}\u{da80}\u{dc00}-\u{dabf}\u{dffd}\u{dac0}\u{dc00}-\u{daff}\u{dffd}\u{db00}\u{dc00}-\u{db3f}\u{dffd}\u{db44}\u{dc00}-\u{db7f}\u{dffd}&&[^\u{00a0}[\u{2000}-\u{200a}]\u{2028}\u{2029}\u{202f}\u{3000}]]]){0,1}\.)+(xn\-\-[\w\-]{0,58}\w|[a-zA-Z[\u{00a0}-\u{d7ff}\u{f900}-\u{fdcf}\u{fdf0}-\u{ffef}\u{d800}\u{dc00}-\u{d83f}\u{dffd}\u{d840}\u{dc00}-\u{d87f}\u{dffd}\u{d880}\u{dc00}-\u{d8bf}\u{dffd}\u{d8c0}\u{dc00}-\u{d8ff}\u{dffd}\u{d900}\u{dc00}-\u{d93f}\u{dffd}\u{d940}\u{dc00}-\u{d97f}\u{dffd}\u{d980}\u{dc00}-\u{d9bf}\u{dffd}\u{d9c0}\u{dc00}-\u{d9ff}\u{dffd}\u{da00}\u{dc00}-\u{da3f}\u{dffd}\u{da40}\u{dc00}-\u{da7f}\u{dffd}\u{da80}\u{dc00}-\u{dabf}\u{dffd}\u{dac0}\u{dc00}-\u{daff}\u{dffd}\u{db00}\u{dc00}-\u{db3f}\u{dffd}\u{db44}\u{dc00}-\u{db7f}\u{dffd}&&[^\u{00a0}[\u{2000}-\u{200a}]\u{2028}\u{2029}\u{202f}\u{3000}]]]{2,63})|((25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[0-1][0-9]{2}|[1-9][0-9]|[1-9])\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[0-1][0-9]{2}|[1-9][0-9]|[1-9]|0)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[0-1][0-9]{2}|[1-9][0-9]|[1-9]|0)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[0-1][0-9]{2}|[1-9][0-9]|[0-9]))))(?:\:\d{1,5})?)([/\?](?:(?:[a-zA-Z0-9[\u{00a0}-\u{d7ff}\u{f900}-\u{fdcf}\u{fdf0}-\u{ffef}\u{d800}\u{dc00}-\u{d83f}\u{dffd}\u{d840}\u{dc00}-\u{d87f}\u{dffd}\u{d880}\u{dc00}-\u{d8bf}\u{dffd}\u{d8c0}\u{dc00}-\u{d8ff}\u{dffd}\u{d900}\u{dc00}-\u{d93f}\u{dffd}\u{d940}\u{dc00}-\u{d97f}\u{dffd}\u{d980}\u{dc00}-\u{d9bf}\u{dffd}\u{d9c0}\u{dc00}-\u{d9ff}\u{dffd}\u{da00}\u{dc00}-\u{da3f}\u{dffd}\u{da40}\u{dc00}-\u{da7f}\u{dffd}\u{da80}\u{dc00}-\u{dabf}\u{dffd}\u{dac0}\u{dc00}-\u{daff}\u{dffd}\u{db00}\u{dc00}-\u{db3f}\u{dffd}\u{db44}\u{dc00}-\u{db7f}\u{dffd}&&[^\u{00a0}[\u{2000}-\u{200a}]\u{2028}\u{2029}\u{202f}\u{3000}]];/\?:@&=#~\-\.\+!\*'\(\),_\$])|(?:%[a-fA-F0-9]{2}))*)?(?:\b|$|^))
```

### Other patterns

[Patterns.java](https://github.com/aosp-mirror/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/java/android/util/Patterns.java) contains more patterns, but posting them will hit the Stackoverflow post length limit. But I'll post the API descriptions of them here, so that you know about their existence and purpose. I've also added code below to output these patterns using Kotlin.

#### Pattern called "*WEB_URL_WITHOUT_PROTOCOL*"

Description:

> Regular expression to match strings that do not start with a supported protocol. The TLDs are expected to be one of the known TLDs.

Definition:

```java
"("
+ WORD_BOUNDARY
+ "(?<!:\\/\\/)"
+ "("
+ "(?:" + STRICT_DOMAIN_NAME + ")"
+ "(?:" + PORT_NUMBER + ")?"
+ ")"
+ "(?:" + PATH_AND_QUERY + ")?"
+ WORD_BOUNDARY
+ ")";
```

#### Pattern called "*WEB_URL_WITH_PROTOCOL*"

Description:

> Regular expression to match strings that start with a supported protocol. Rules for domain names and TLDs are more relaxed. TLDs are optional.

Definition:

```java
"("
+ WORD_BOUNDARY
+ "(?:"
+ "(?:" + PROTOCOL + "(?:" + USER_INFO + ")?" + ")"
+ "(?:" + RELAXED_DOMAIN_NAME + ")?"
+ "(?:" + PORT_NUMBER + ")?"
+ ")"
+ "(?:" + PATH_AND_QUERY + ")?"
+ WORD_BOUNDARY
+ ")";
```

#### Pattern called "*AUTOLINK_WEB_URL*"

Description:

> Regular expression pattern to match IRIs. If a string starts with
> http(s):// the expression tries to match the URL structure with a
> relaxed rule for TLDs. If the string does not start with http(s)://
> the TLDs are expected to be one of the known TLDs.

Definition:

```java
"(" + WEB_URL_WITH_PROTOCOL + "|" + WEB_URL_WITHOUT_PROTOCOL + ")")
```

### Code to output the patterns from AOSP Patterns.java

This code is written in language Kotlin (a Java JVM based language). If converts the regex patterns from AOSP `Patterns.java` to a readable format:

```kotlin
import java.util.regex.Pattern

fun createPattern(pattern: Pattern, unicodeStringFormat: String): String =
    pattern.toString().flatMap {
        val charCode = it.code
        if (charCode > 126) {
            unicodeStringFormat.format(charCode).toList()
        } else {
            listOf(it)
        }
    }.joinToString("")

fun main() {
    val unicodeStringFormatJava = "\\u%04x"
    val unicodeStringFormatPHP = "\\u{%04x}"

    // Pattern: WEB_URL
    println(createPattern(Patterns.WEB_URL, unicodeStringFormatJava))
    println(createPattern(Patterns.WEB_URL, unicodeStringFormatPHP))

    // Pattern: AUTOLINK_WEB_URL
    println(createPattern(Patterns.AUTOLINK_WEB_URL, unicodeStringFormatJava))
    println(createPattern(Patterns.AUTOLINK_WEB_URL, unicodeStringFormatPHP))

    // Pattern: WEB_URL_WITH_PROTOCOL (variable modified to public visibility)
    println(createPattern(Patterns.WEB_URL_WITH_PROTOCOL.toPattern(), unicodeStringFormatJava))
    println(createPattern(Patterns.WEB_URL_WITH_PROTOCOL.toPattern(), unicodeStringFormatPHP))

    // Pattern: WEB_URL_WITHOUT_PROTOCOL (variable modified to public visibility)
    println(createPattern(Patterns.WEB_URL_WITHOUT_PROTOCOL.toPattern(), unicodeStringFormatJava))
    println(createPattern(Patterns.WEB_URL_WITHOUT_PROTOCOL.toPattern(), unicodeStringFormatPHP))
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
(http(s|)\:\/\/|)((([a-zA-Z0-9-_]{1,}\.){1,})([a-zA-Z]{1}[a-zA-Z0-9-]{1,}))(:[0-9]{1,}|)(\/[a-zA-Z0-9_~#?\+\&\.\/-=%-]{1,}|)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I just made one with unicode and capture groups according to RFC 1035 and RFC 3986.

```js
/(?<scheme>https):\/\/(?<host>(?:(?:xn--(?!-)|xn-(?=-)|[A-Za-z])(?:(?:-[A-Za-z\d]+)*-[A-Za-z\d]+|[A-Za-z\d]*)?\.)*(?:xn--(?!-)|xn-(?=-)|[A-Za-z])(?:(?:-[A-Za-z\d]+)*-[A-Za-z\d]+|[A-Za-z\d]*)?)(?::(?<port>\d+))?(?<path>(?:\/(?:[-\p{L}\p{N}._~]|%[0-9A-Fa-f]{2}|[!$&'()*+,;=]|:|@)*)*)(?:\?(?<query>(?:[-\p{L}\p{N}._~]|%[0-9A-Fa-f]{2}|[!$&'()*+,;=]|:|@|[?/])*))?(?:#(?<fragment>(?:[-\p{L}\p{N}._~]|%[0-9A-Fa-f]{2}|[!$&'()*+,;=]|:|@|[?/])*))?/u;
```

Comment: lord, you "just made that"? chapeau

Answer (score -1):

```
/^(http|HTTP)+(s|S)?:\/\/[\w.-]+(?:\.[\w\.-]+)+[\w\-\._\$\(\)/]+$/g
```

check demo with tests:

https://regexr.com/5cedu

Answer (score -1):

The best regex is a combination of the best answers here! hahaha! I have just tested them all, and put the best together! I changed it a little to only have one capture group! I was able to find 637 URLs in the source code of this page! Only a few false positives!

```
((?:(?:https?|ftp)://)(?:\S+(?::\S*)?@|\d{1,3}(?:\.\d{1,3}){3}|(?:(?:[a-z\d\x{00a1}-\x{ffff}]+-?)*[a-z\d\x{00a1}-\x{ffff}]+)(?:\.(?:[a-z\d\x{00a1}-\x{ffff}]+-?)*[a-z\d\x{00a1}-\x{ffff}]+)*(?:\.[a-z\x{00a1}-\x{ffff}]{2,6}))(?::\d+)?(?:[^\s]*)|(?:(?:(?:[A-Za-z]{3,9}:(?:\/\/)?)(?:[-;:&=\+\$,\w]+@)?[A-Za-z0-9.-]+(?::[0-9]+)?|(?:www.|[-;:&=\+\$,\w]+@)[A-Za-z0-9.-]+)(?:(?:\/[\+~%\/.\w-_]*)?\??(?:[-\+=&;%@.\w_]*)#?(?:[\w]*))?)|(?:(?:(?:(?:[A-Za-z]{3,9}:(?:\/\/)?)(?:[-;:&=\+\$,\w]+@)?[A-Za-z0-9.-]+|(?:www.|[-;:&=\+\$,\w]+@)[A-Za-z0-9.-]+)(?:(?:\/[\+~%\/.\w-_]*)?\??(?:[-\+=&;%@.\w_]*)#?(?:[\w]*))?))|(?:(?:(?:[\\w]+:)?//)?(?:(?:[\\d\\w]|%[a-fA-f\\d]{2,2})+(?::(?:[\\d\\w]|%[a-fA-f\\d]{2,2})+)?@)?(?:[\\d\\w][-\\d\\w]{0,253}[\\d\\w]\\.)+[\\w]{2,4}(?::[\\d]+)?(?:/(?:[-+_~.\\d\\w]|%[a-fA-f\\d]{2,2})*)*(?:\\?(?:&?(?:[-+_~.\\d\\w]|%[a-fA-f\\d]{2,2})=?)*)?(?:#(?:[-+_~.\\d\\w]|%[a-fA-f\\d]{2,2})*)?)|(?:https?:\/\/(?:[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]{0,61}[a-z0-9])?\.)+[a-z0-9][a-z0-9-]{0,61}[a-z0-9])(?::?\d*)\/?(?:[a-z_\/0-9\-#.]*)\??(?:[a-z_\/0-9\-#=&]*)|(?:(?:(?:https?:)?(?:\/?\/))(?:(?:[\d\w]|%[a-fA-f\d]{2,2})+(?::(?:[\d\w]|%[a-fA-f\d]{2,2})+)?@)?(?:[\d\w][-\d\w]{0,253}[\d\w]\.)+[\w]{2,63}(?::[\d]+)?(?:/(?:[-+_~.\d\w]|%[a-fA-f\d]{2,2})*)*(?:\?(?:&?(?:[-+_~.\d\w]|%[a-fA-f\d]{2,2})=?)*)?(?:#(?:[-+_~.\d\w]|%[a-fA-f\d]{2,2})*)?)|(?:(?:https?|ftp)://(?:www\d?|[a-zA-Z0-9]+)?\.[a-zA-Z0-9-]+(?:\:|\.)(?:[a-zA-Z0-9.]+|(?:\d+)?)(?:[/?:].*)?)|(?:\b(?:(?:https?|ftp):\/\/)(?:\S+(?::\S*)?@)?(?:(?!10(?:\.\d{1,3}){3})(?!127(?:\.\d{1,3}){3})(?!169\.254(?:\.\d{1,3}){2})(?!192\.168(?:\.\d{1,3}){2})(?!172\.(?:1[6-9]|2\d|3[0-1])(?:\.\d{1,3}){2})(?:[1-9]\d?|1\d\d|2[01]\d|22[0-3])(?:\.(?:1?\d{1,2}|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])){2}(?:\.(?:[1-9]\d?|1\d\d|2[0-4]\d|25[0-4]))|(?:(?:[a-z\x{00a1}-\x{ffff}0-9]+-?)*[a-z\x{00a1}-\x{ffff}0-9]+)(?:\.(?:[a-z\x{00a1}-\x{ffff}0-9]+-?)*[a-z\x{00a1}-\x{ffff}0-9]+)*(?:\.(?:[a-z\x{00a1}-\x{ffff}]{2,})))(?::\d{2,5})?(?:\/[^\s]*)?\b))
```