# Regex to check if valid URL that ends in .jpg, .png, or .gif

Tags: regex, perl

I would like users to submit a URL that is valid but also is an image, ending with .jpg, .png, or .gif.

Comment: What about "jpeg"?

Comment: What about "somescript.php?image_id=12345"?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12470263/2534236

Answer (score 78):

```
(?:([^:/?#]+):)?(?://([^/?#]*))?([^?#]*\.(?:jpg|gif|png))(?:\?([^#]*))?(?:#(.*))?
```

That's a (slightly modified) version of the official URI parsing regexp from [RFC 2396](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2396.txt). It allows for `#fragments` and `?querystrings` to appear after the filename, which may or may not be what you want. It also matches any valid domain, including `localhost`, which again might not be what you want, but it could be modified.

A more traditional regexp for this might look like the below.

```
^https?://(?:[a-z0-9\-]+\.)+[a-z]{2,6}(?:/[^/#?]+)+\.(?:jpg|gif|png)$
          |-------- domain -----------|--- path ---|-- extension ---|
```

**EDIT** See my [other comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/169625/regex-to-check-if-valid-url-that-ends-in-jpg-png-or-gif#169656), which although isn't answering the question as completely as this one, I feel it's probably a more useful in this case. However, I'm leaving this here for <del>karma-whoring</del> completeness reasons.

Comment: Replace "jpg" with "jpe?g" and also set the case-insensitive flag on the regex.

Comment: this is only really useful if the URL is actually valid.  I can't count the number of times I've seem 'illegal' characters in URLs, particularly spaces in filenames.

Comment: I second @PlexQ. Is there a unified regex to check if the url is valid AND is an image url?

Comment: This is very useful. I'm working on matching url based on extension. Thankyou

Answer (score 38):

Actually.

Why are you checking the URL? That's no guarantee what you're going to get is an image, and no guarantee that the things you're rejecting *aren't* images. Try performing a HEAD request on it, and see what content-type it *actually* is.

Comment: Depending on how paranoid you are about the data behind the URL, you might want to go beyond just the HEAD and grab the full content of the (alleged) image, then use an image-processing library to verify that it is what it claims to be.

Comment: That even wouldn't guarantee the image still exists and actually being an image at the moment the URL is served to a browser.

Answer (score 19):

In general, you're better off validating URLs using built-in library or framework functions, rather than rolling your own regular expressions to do this - see [What is the best regular expression to check if a string is a valid URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/161738/what-is-the-best-regular-expression-to-check-if-a-string-is-a-valid-url#161749) for details.

If you are keen on doing this, though, check out this question:

[Getting parts of a URL (Regex)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27745/getting-parts-of-a-url-regex)

Then, once you're satisfied with the URL (by whatever means you used to validate it), you could either use a simple "endswith" type string operator to check the extension, or a simple regex like

```
(?i)\.(jpg|png|gif)$
```

Comment: Very good call!  Here is what I did kids:
1) Use JQuery's validation 
http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation
2) Add in this regex piece to the end of URL, and renamed it "urlphoto"

Works like a charm! good job

Answer (score 15):

```
(http(s?):)|([/|.|\w|\s])*\.(?:jpg|gif|png)
```

This will mach all images from this string:

```
background: rgb(255, 0, 0) url(../res/img/temp/634043/original/cc3d8715eed0c.jpg) repeat fixed left top; cursor: auto;
<div id="divbg" style="background-color:#ff0000"><img id="bg" src="../res/img/temp/634043/original/cc3d8715eed0c.jpg" width="100%" height="100%" /></div>
background-image: url(../res/img/temp/634043/original/cc3d8715eed0c.png);
background: rgb(255, 0, 0) url(http://google.com/res/../img/temp/634043/original/cc3    _d8715eed0c.jpg) repeat fixed left top; cursor: auto;
background: rgb(255, 0, 0) url(https://google.com/res/../img/temp/634043/original/cc3_d8715eed0c.jpg) repeat fixed left top; cursor: auto;
```

Test your regex here: https://regex101.com/r/l2Zt7S/1

Comment: splits the path with hyphen in the dir/file name

Comment: `(http(s?):)([/|.|\w|\s|-])*\.(?:jpg|gif|png)` performs just slightly better. It requires the http(s) found in URLs (instead of being optional). Also, it supports dashes in the URL.

Answer (score 4):

`(http(s?):)([/|.|\w|\s|-])*\.(?:jpg|gif|png)` worked really well for me.

This will match URLs in the following forms:

```
https://farm4.staticflickr.com/3894/15008518202_c265dfa55f_h.jpg
http://farm4.staticflickr.com/3894/15008518202_c265dfa55f_h.jpg
https://farm4.staticflickr.com/3894/15008518202-c265dfa55f-h.jpg
https://farm4.staticflickr.com/3894/15008518202.c265dfa55f.h.jpg
https://farm4.staticflickr.com/3894/15008518202_c265dfa55f_h.gif
http://farm4.staticflickr.com/3894/15008518202_c265dfa55f_h.gif
https://farm4.staticflickr.com/3894/15008518202-c265dfa55f-h.gif
https://farm4.staticflickr.com/3894/15008518202.c265dfa55f.h.gif
https://farm4.staticflickr.com/3894/15008518202_c265dfa55f_h.png
http://farm4.staticflickr.com/3894/15008518202_c265dfa55f_h.png
https://farm4.staticflickr.com/3894/15008518202-c265dfa55f-h.png
https://farm4.staticflickr.com/3894/15008518202.c265dfa55f.h.png
```

Check this regular expression against the URLs here: http://regexr.com/3g1v7

Answer (score 2):

Here's the basic idea in Perl. Fetch the URL and see what it says in the `Content-type` header:

```
use LWP::UserAgent;
my $ua = LWP::UserAgent->new;
my $url = "http://www.example.com/logo.png";

my $response = $ua->head( $url );

my( $class, $type ) = split m|/|, lc $response->content_type;

print "It's an image!\n" if $class eq 'image';
```

If you need to inspect just the URL without accessing it, use a solid library for it rather than trying to handle all the odd situations yourself:

```
use URI;

my $url = "http://www.example.com/logo.png";
my $uri = URI->new( $url );

my $last = ( $uri->path_segments )[-1];

my( $extension ) = $last =~ m/\.([^.]+)$/g;

print "My extension is $extension\n";
```

And here's a Mojolicious example:

```
use Mojo::URL;

my $url = "http://www.example.com/logo.png";
my( $extension ) = 
    Mojo::URL->new($url)->path->parts->[-1] =~ m/\.([^.]+)$/g;

print "My extension is $extension\n";
```

Good luck, :)

Answer (score 2):

If you *really* want to be sure, grabbing the first kilobyte or two of the given URL should be sufficient to determine everything you need to know about the image.

Here's [an example of how you can get that information](http://effbot.org/zone/pil-image-size.htm), using Python, and here's [an example of it being put to use, as a Django form field](http://www.djangosnippets.org/snippets/402/) which allows you to easily validate an image's existence, filesize, dimensions and format, given its URL.

Answer (score 1):

I am working in Javascript based library (React). The below regex is working for me for the URL with image extension.

```
[^\\s]+(.*?)\\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|JPG|JPEG|PNG|GIF)$
```

Working URL`s are:

> https://images.pexels.com/photos/674010/pexels-photo-674010.jpeg
> https://images.pexels.com/photos/674010/pexels-photo-674010.jpg
> https://www.images.pexels.com/photos/674010/pexels-photo-674010.JPEG
> http://www.images.pexels.com/photos/674010/pexels-photo-674010.JPEG
> [www.images.pexels.com/photos/674010/pexels-photo-674010.JPEG](http://www.images.pexels.com/photos/674010/pexels-photo-674010.JPEG)
> images.pexels.com/photos/674010/pexels-photo-674010.JPEG

**Got the solution from:
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-validate-image-file-extension-using-regular-expression/**

Answer (score 0):

Use [FastImage](https://github.com/sdsykes/fastimage) - it'll grab the minimum required data from the URL to determine if it's an image, what type of image and what size.

Answer (score 0):

Addition to [Dan's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/169625/regex-to-check-if-valid-url-that-ends-in-jpg-png-or-gif#169631) Answer.

#### If there is an IP address instead of domain.

Change regex a bit. (Temporary solution for valid IPv4 and IPv6)

```
^https?://(?:[a-z0-9\-]+\.)+[a-z0-9]{2,6}(?:/[^/#?]+)+\.(?:jpg|gif|png)$
```

However this can be improved, for IPv4 and IPv6 to validate subnet range(s).

Answer (score 0):

This expression will match all the image urls -

```
^(?:http(s)?:\/\/)?[\w.-]+(?:\.[\w\.-]+)+[\w\-\._~:/?#[\]@!\$&'\(\)\*\+,;=.]+(?:png|jpg|jpeg|gif|svg)+$
```

**Examples -**

***Valid -***

```
https://itelligencegroup.com/wp-content/usermedia/de_home_teaser-box_puzzle_in_the_sun.png
http://sweetytextmessages.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/11/9-Happy-Monday-images.jpg
example.com/de_home_teaser-box_puzzle_in_the_sun.png
www.example.com/de_home_teaser-box_puzzle_in_the_sun.png
https://www.greetingseveryday.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/08/Happy-Independence-Day-Greetings-Cards-Pictures-in-Urdu-Marathi-1.jpg
http://thuglifememe.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/12/Top-Happy-tuesday-quotes-1.jpg
https://1.bp.blogspot.com/-ejYG9pr06O4/Wlhn48nx9cI/AAAAAAAAC7s/gAVN3tEV3NYiNPuE-Qpr05TpqLiG79tEQCLcBGAs/s1600/Republic-Day-2017-Wallpapers.jpg
```

***Invalid -***

```
https://www.example.com
http://www.example.com
www.example.com
example.com
http://blog.example.com
http://www.example.com/product
http://www.example.com/products?id=1&page=2
http://www.example.com#up
http://255.255.255.255
255.255.255.255
http://invalid.com/perl.cgi?key= | http://web-site.com/cgi-bin/perl.cgi?key1=value1&key2
http://www.siteabcd.com:8008
```

Answer (score 0):

Reference: See DecodeConfig section on the official go lang image lib docs [here](https://golang.org/pkg/image/)

I believe you could also use DecodeConfig to get the format of an image which you could then validate against const types like jpeg, png, jpg and gif ie

```
import (
  "encoding/base64"
  "fmt"
  "image"
  "log"
  "strings"
  "net/http"

  // Package image/jpeg is not used explicitly in the code below,
  // but is imported for its initialization side-effect, which allows
  // image.Decode to understand JPEG formatted images. Uncomment these
  // two lines to also understand GIF and PNG images:
  // _ "image/gif"
  // _ "image/png"
  _ "image/jpeg"
   )

func main() {
  resp, err := http.Get("http://i.imgur.com/Peq1U1u.jpg")
  if err != nil {
      log.Fatal(err)
  }
  defer resp.Body.Close()
  data, _, err := image.Decode(resp.Body)
  if err != nil {
      log.Fatal(err)
  }
  reader := base64.NewDecoder(base64.StdEncoding, strings.NewReader(data))
  config, format, err := image.DecodeConfig(reader)
  if err != nil {
      log.Fatal(err)
  }
  fmt.Println("Width:", config.Width, "Height:", config.Height, "Format:", format)
}
```

format here is a string that states the file format eg jpg, png etc

Answer (score 0):

Just providing a better solution. You can just validate the uri and check the format then:

```
public class IsImageUriValid
{
    private readonly string[] _supportedImageFormats =
    {
        ".jpg",
        ".gif",
        ".png"
    };

    public bool IsValid(string uri)
    {
        var isUriWellFormed = Uri.IsWellFormedUriString(uri, UriKind.Absolute);

        return isUriWellFormed && IsSupportedFormat(uri);
    }

    private bool IsSupportedFormat(string uri) => _supportedImageFormats.Any(supportedImageExtension => uri.EndsWith(supportedImageExtension));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    const url = "https://www.laoz.com/image.png";
    const acceptedImage = [".png", ".jpg", ".gif"];
    const extension = url.substring(url.lastIndexOf("."));
    const isValidImage = acceptedImage.find((m) => m === extension) != null;
    console.log("isValidImage", isValidImage);
    console.log("extension", extension);
```

Answer (score -1):

```
^((http(s?)\:\/\/|~/|/)?([\w]+:\w+@)?([a-zA-Z]{1}([\w\-]+\.)+([\w]{2,5}))(:[\d]{1,5})?((/?\w+/)+|/?)(\w+\.(jpg|png|gif))
```