# regex for url and image within a text or html

Tags: php, regex, image, url

i'm running out of ideas on the best regex implementation for this problem.

Sample user input:

```
bla bla bla http://foo.com bla bla bla http://tinypic.com/boo.png bla bla bla
```

Looking for solution that will detect non-image url and turn it into a link and also turn image url into an image embed (IMG tag).

so the output will be:

```
bla bla bla <a href="http://foo.com">http://foo.com</a> bla bla bla <img src="http://tinypic.com/boo.png" /> bla bla bla
```

#### Related

- [Regex to check if valid URL that ends in .jpg, .png, or .gif](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/169625/regex-to-check-if-valid-url-that-ends-in-jpg-png-or-gif)
- [What is the best regular expression to check if a string is a valid URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/161738/what-is-the-best-regular-expression-to-check-if-a-string-is-a-valid-url)
- [Getting parts of a URL (Regex)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27745/getting-parts-of-a-url-regex)

Comment: This is a typical “extract URLs” / “linkify URLs” question. Have you checked the questions? (See “Related” on the right side.)

Answer (score 4):

Break it into multiple steps.

First, find links with something like:

```
/http:[^ ,]+/i
```

Then replace the matched string with new content based on the type, which you can detect by matching the string to be replaced against something like:

```
/\.(jpg|png|gif|bmp)$/i
```

Answer (score 0):

> Looking for solution that will detect non-image url

There is no such thing as an image or non-image URL. The presence (or absence) of a ‘.gif’/‘.jpeg’/‘.jpg’/‘.png’ file extension has nothing to do with whether a URL points to an image or not.

eg. “http://www.example.com/getimage/3” could return a perfectly good JPEG. There is no way to know what media type a URL points to without fetching it (using GET or, better, HEAD) and checking the returned ‘Content-Type’ is ‘image/something’.