# Selecting image url from html using javascript regexp

Tags: javascript, html, regex

I'd like to select the image source url from html code using javascript regexp. I'm using it to simplify using picasaweb images in other websites. I'm rather new at this, and I constructed a regex using http://www.regular-expressions.info/javascriptexample.html, and there it works like a charm, but not in my own script. Can somebody point me out the error in my script?

```
function addImage() {
var picasaDump=prompt("Copy the picasa link");
if (picasaDump!=null && picasaDump!="")
{
    var regMatch = new RegExp("http:\/\/\S\.[jJ][pP][eE]?[gG]");
    var imageLink = regMatch.exec(picasaDump);
    if(imageLink == null) {
        alert("Error, no images found");
    } else if(imageLink.length > 1) {
        alert("Error, multiple images fount");
    } else {
        further parsing...
    }
}
}
```

EDIT: Some sample input

```
<a href="http://picasaweb.google.com/lh/photo/NHH78Y0WLPAAzIu0lzKlUA?feat=embedwebsite"><img src="http://lh3.ggpht.com/_ADW_3zOQhj8/TGgN4bXtfMI/AAAAAAAABCA/w6M-JKzNtBk/s144/DSC_2132.jpg" /></a>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in this line

```
var regMatch = new RegExp("http:\/\/\S\.[jJ][pP][eE]?[gG]");
```

you're escaping characters in the string rather than in your regular expression. also `\S` will only match a single character. it should be

```
var regMatch = new RegExp("http:\\/\\/\\S+\\.[jJ][pP][eE]?[gG]");
```

Comment: Thanks a million, that's the solution I was looking for!

Answer (score 1):

Here is another SO thread that talks about the appropriate regular expression for this: [Regex to check if valid URL that ends in .jpg, .png, or .gif](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/169625/regex-to-check-if-valid-url-that-ends-in-jpg-png-or-gif)

Regardless of the regular expression you use, a simple one-liner to test a string is :

```
({Regular_Expression}>/gi).test({String_To_Test}) 

For e.g. 
(/http:\/\/.+?\.jpg|jpeg/gi).test("http://www.google.com/image.jpg")
```

Comment: I'm not trying to validate an image url, I'm only extracting it

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
var regMatch = new RegExp("http:\/\/.+?\.jpg|jpeg","gi");
```

Comment: That will also match a regular link, I've added sample input to demonstrate

Answer (score 0):

This would be best implemented with look-behind. However, since JavaScript doesn't support look-behind, we have to mimic it by reversing the string, and using a look-ahead.

```
String.prototype.reverse = function () {
    return this.split('').reverse().join('');
};

var input = '<a href="http://picasaweb.google.com/lh/photo/NHH78Y0WLPAAzIu0lzKlUA?feat=embedwebsite"><img src="http://lh3.ggpht.com/_ADW_3zOQhj8/TGgN4bXtfMI/AAAAAAAABCA/w6M-JKzNtBk/s144/DSC_2132.jpg" /></a>'
var matches = input.reverse().match(/(gepj|gpj|gif|png)\..+?\/\/:ptth(?=\"\=crs)/g);
```

This will return an array of reversed image URLs, so you'll have to re-reverse them.

```
for (i = 0; i < matches.length; i++)
{
    matches[i] = matches[i].reverse();
}
```

If you know the format of your image links, you may be able to specify more of a look-ahead, like so:

```
var matches = input.reverse().match(/(gepj|gpj|gif|png)\..+?\/\/:ptth(?=\"\=crs gmi)/g);
```

Which will match only if `<img` is immediately followed by `src`.

Look-behind mimicking taken from [Steven Levithan](http://blog.stevenlevithan.com/archives/mimic-lookbehind-javascript)