# distinguish html link and image link like Facebook attach in .NET

Tags: .net, fetch

like facebook attach link,

when i share a link -> facebook fetch the html page

when i share a image link -> facebook fetch the image

so at server side (.NET, C#), how can i distinguish a html link or image link

any help?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Regex to check if valid URL that ends in .jpg, .png, or .gif](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/169625/regex-to-check-if-valid-url-that-ends-in-jpg-png-or-gif)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try a couple things:

- Do a regex on the URL and check for a file extension.  E.g. `\.(png|jpg|gif|bmp)$`
- Actually retrieve the document, and check the mime type

Also, check answers to this question:

[Regex to check if valid URL that ends in .jpg, .png, or .gif](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/169625/regex-to-check-if-valid-url-that-ends-in-jpg-png-or-gif)

[The most recent answer there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/169625/regex-to-check-if-valid-url-that-ends-in-jpg-png-or-gif/5497814#5497814) mentions a library called [FastImage](https://github.com/sdsykes/fastimage).