# Matching url with the regex

Tags: java, regex

I take this `(?:([^:/?#]+):)?(?://([^/?#]*))?([^?#]*\.  (?:jpg|gif|png))(?:\?([^#]*))?(?:#(.*))?` regular expression from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/169625/regex-to-check-if-valid-url-that-ends-in-jpg-png-or-gif/169631#169631). if i use this in my below program to match the url means i'm getting compiler error .

This is my code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
String url="http://justfuckinggoogleit.com/bart.gif";
matchesImageUrl(url);

}
public static void matchesImageUrl(String url){
Pattern imagePattern=Pattern.compile("(?:([^:/?#]+):)?(?://([^/?#]*))?([^?#]*\.  (?:jpg|gif|png))(?:\?([^#]*))?(?:#(.*))?");

if(imagePattern.matcher(url).matches()){

    System.out.println("image matches with the pattern" + url);


}
else{

    System.out.println("image does not matches with the pattern");

}


}
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to escape twice.

So replace `\` with `\\`.

[See it work](http://www.ideone.com/FH6vn)

Comment: I would give +10 for the link in your ideone, if I could :P

Answer (score 0):

The problem you have is that the backslash characters () in your regex are escape characters for Java, so it sees \. and \? and thinks your trying to escape a . and a ? - hence the compilation error that you're probably seeing talking about 'Invalid escape characters'.

To fix this, you need to escape the backslashes with their own backslashes. you get:

\\. and \\?

or, in full form:

```
(?:([^:/?#]+):)?(?://([^/?#]*))?([^?#]*\\.  (?:jpg|gif|png))(?:\\?([^#]*))?(?:#(.*))?
```