# regex javascript supply valid url image

Tags: regex, image, url

I need a regex for valid url image,
example: http://domain.something.jpg

protocol: http,https,ftp
estension: jpg,png,gif,bmp

Can you help me please?

Comment: What about `http://foo.com/dynamic`? Do you consider this as *valid image* assuming that this server side script sets the `Content-Type: 'image/jpg'` and writes a valid image into the response?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Regex to check if valid URL that ends in .jpg, .png, or .gif](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/169625/regex-to-check-if-valid-url-that-ends-in-jpg-png-or-gif)

Comment: what did you try? what's the difficulty?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe something like that:

```
"^(https?|ftp)://.*(jpeg|png|gif|bmp)"
```

Comment: that doesn't cover the ftp protocol

Comment: Just realized that, altered the regex. Thanks for the hint.

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
/^((https?|ftp):)?\/\/.*(jpeg|jpg|png|gif|bmp)$/
```

Comment: I'd suggest to add "bmp" as another valid extension.