# Regex JavaScript image file extension

Tags: javascript, regex, image

I need a regular expression to validate image file extensions in javascript. Do you have one ?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Image_file_formats and http://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/169625/regex-to-check-if-valid-url-that-ends-in-jpg-png-or-gif.

Answer (score 167, accepted):

Could you explain the purpose?

Anyway here's one assuming you support few image types.

```
(/\.(gif|jpe?g|tiff?|png|webp|bmp)$/i).test(filename)
```

I have put the whole regular expression within parentheses () so as to disambiguate between the slash (/) operator and RegExp object.  See JSLint for more details.

Here's the raw regex as well.

```
/\.(gif|jpe?g|tiff?|png|webp|bmp)$/i
```

This Regex also assumes that you're including the dot before the extension. Remove the `\.` if you're not.

Comment: Instead of `jpg|jpeg` you can do: `jpe?g`

Comment: How about adding `webp` to this list?

Comment: Could we consider `.ico` as na image ?

Comment: How would this look like when you also want to include capitalised extensions?
And thank you for your answer