# How to validate image file extension with regular expression using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, regex

How to validate image file extension (jpg,png,gif,bmp) with JavaScript regular expression?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10473185/regex-javascript-image-file-extension

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Accordingly your issue the regular expression is quite simple.

```
/\.(jpe?g|png|gif|bmp)$/i
```

Do you really sure that nothing else will be used? For example, JPEG format allows both .jpg and .jpeg extensions. That's why I put `e?` pattern in the regular expression.

Example of validation could be as follows:

```
var filename = "/site/images/test.png";
if ( /\.(jpe?g|png|gif|bmp)$/i.test(filename) ) {
. . .
```

.

Comment: yes this is the regex, but how to validate the url, as example I have this path "/site/images/test.png". how to validate it ?