# check whether variable in javascript is image url

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, json

I am getting json array which contains various  name/value pairs. and for every response its different as it comes from database. for every response i get, one name/value pair represents image url info. But problem is that name is not constant for all request. i.e. is for one request it  can be:

`'imgurl':'http://l1.yimg.com/071153.jpg'`

and for other it can be anything having different name.something like:

`'imginf':'http://lre.ghamg.co.in/arecon.png'`.

I am looking for a way to check whether given variable represents image url(any type of image) using javascript or jquery.i am looking for any good suggestions if they can help me with this.

Thanks for stopping by...!!

Comment: Is it good enough to see the file matches a known extension (i.e. does the value end in 'jpg', 'png', 'gif' ...), or do you need to open the file and see if it in fact looks like image content?

Comment: Did you try writing the regex (you tagged it with regex)?

Comment: @PaulProgrammer:how about other variables ending with same extension.and number of variables are very large as they come from database.

Comment: I'd say this is a reasonable discussion of what you're trying to do with multiple options: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/169625/regex-to-check-if-valid-url-that-ends-in-jpg-png-or-gif#169656

Comment: Can you assume about the prefix of the property name `imginf` and `imgurl`?

Comment: @WiredPrairie:ya i tried with image regex. it didn't worked though.

Comment: @nhahtdh:as i said variable names come from db. so it can be anything.not necessary that it starts with img.

Comment: @MilindAnantwar What's the problem of other variables ending with those extensions? They'll still be images.

Comment: You said "a given variable" ... that implies you know the name of the variable.  If you're looking for a way to iterate through the keys, that's a different question.

Comment: Why does the key names differ? Normally when you get something from a database, the field names are always exactly the same.

Comment: Should you need to iterate through the keys, here's a reference: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/684672/loop-through-javascript-object

Comment: @guffa.my bad.it's not coming from db. the whole table from db comes as a response. so you can imagine two different table for every other scenario.

Answer (score 0):

You mean something like this?

```
var fileName= {"imgurl": ["http://l1.yimg.com/071153.jpg"]};
var file = fileName['imgurl'][0]
var ext = file.substring(file.lastIndexOf('.') + 1);


if(ext ==="gif" || ext === "jpg" ||  ext === "png"|| ext === "BMP"){
alert('image');
}
```