# Regex Finding URL's Within a string and replacing any word which ends at ".com"

Tags: regex, url, replace, hyperlink

I am trying to figure out how to look through a string and replace any word which ends at ".com" at the end with a valid url link.

for example: 
"google.com has launces a .." will be replaced with

"<.a href='google.com'>google.com <./a> has launches .."

```
// I tried following code, but it only works for finding word which starts with "www."

data.rows[j].content = data.rows[j].content.replace(
  /(^|&lt;|\s)(www\..+?\..+?)(\s|&gt;|$)/g,'<a href="https://$2" target="_blank">$2</a>'
)
```

Comment: Why can't you just swap out the second `.+?` for `com` and remove `www\.`? You seem to have your regex already, is there something you're stuck on?

Comment: I'm new to regex. I tried above but doesn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, I recommend [learning how regex works](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions). It's a very powerful tool that all developers should understand because it appears in many different programming languages.

Once you understand the basics, this should make more sense:

```
/(^|&lt;|\b)(\S+?\.com)(\b|&gt;|$)/g
```

[Regex101 Demo](https://regex101.com/r/wZ3bL2/3) - *(for a breakdown of the regex, look in the top-right pane)*

Comment: It works but I only want to catch non spacing character which ends in '.com' or '.edu' or '.org'. The above works for words which is like <a href ="I am google.com>I am google.com</a> which is not correct. Instead I would only like I am <a href="google/com>google.com</a>

Comment: @user21 That makes sense. I've updated to fix that. Btw, to allow more top level domains than `.com`, you could use alternation like `(com|edu|org)`.

Comment: when I use data.rows[j].content = data.rows[j].content.replace(
                /(^|&lt;|\b)(\S+?\.com|edu|org)(\b|&gt;|$)/g,'<a href="https://$2" target="_blank"> $2</a>' 
              ); It will only replace the string to www.google <a href="https://.com">com</a>.

Comment: it works now. Thanks! data.rows[j].content = data.rows[j].content.replace(
                /(^|&lt;|\b)(\S+?\.(com|edu|org))(\b|&gt;|$)/g,'<a href="https://$2" target="_blank"> $2</a>' 
              );

Comment: Is there a way to differentiate words which has has 'https:'' in front, and only replace it with "<a href = "$2" target ="_blank"></a>

Comment: Certainly, just add that requirement to the pattern. The middle part of the regex would be like this: `https:\S+?\.(com|edu|org)`. If you want the `s` in `https` to be optional, make it `https?`

Answer (score 1):

`https://regex101.com/r/oF0mA9/2` should do the trick from the regex front.

Answer (score 1):

You can follow this ways for ending `com`

`(http(s?):)|([/|.|\w|\s])*\.(?:com)`

**OR**

`(?i)\.(com)$`

**OR**

`(?:([^:/?#]+):)?(?://([^/?#]*))?([^?#]*\.(?:com))(?:\?([^#]*))?(?:#(.*))?`

### Resource Link:

[Regex to check if valid URL that ends in .jpg, .png, or .gif](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/169625/regex-to-check-if-valid-url-that-ends-in-jpg-png-or-gif)