# How to validate a image url in golang?

Tags: go

I want to validate a image url that my code will accept the that image url which  having `http` and `https` if there is any other url is present that would not be accepted for example:-

```
fnc main(){
   var url1,url2,url3 string
   url1 = "/image.png" // not accepted
   url2 = "http://abc/image.jpg"  // accepted
   url3 = "https://abc/image.jpg" // accepted
}
```

What regular expression is used for this validation?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Regex to check if valid URL that ends in .jpg, .png, or .gif](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/169625/regex-to-check-if-valid-url-that-ends-in-jpg-png-or-gif)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your criteria is just "having `http`", you can simply use the [`strings.HasPrefix`](https://golang.org/pkg/strings/#HasPrefix):

```
if strings.HasPrefix(url1, "http://") || strings.HasPrefix(url1, "https://") {
    // Valid URL
}
```

However, you can use the [`url.Parse`](https://golang.org/pkg/net/url/) and check the `scheme`:

```
uri, err := url.Parse(url1)
if err != nil && uri.Scheme != "http" && uri.Scheme != "https" {
    // Error
}

// Valid URL
```

Comment: is there any regular expression for it?

Answer (score 0):

```
matched, err := regexp.MatchString("^http.*://", "https://www.google.com")
```

[Goplayground Example](https://play.golang.org/p/DWde5EkJ0Yi)