# how to solve the error of `unknown escape sequence (and 2 more errors)`

Tags: go

I m trying to validate the image url using golang code but there is error in regular expression I'm showing my regular expression in this question:-

```
 var validation = regexp.MustCompile("(http(s?):)|([/|.|\w|\s])*\.(?:jpg|gif|png)")
```

Error:-

> unknown escape sequence (and 2 more errors)

[play link](https://play.golang.org/p/YowUsrXSFZr)

Comment: I'd suggest using backtics when defining regex so that you won't have to escape "\"

Comment: @ssemilla can you tell me what corrections

Comment: Replace " with `. I didn't actually review your regex but people usually make mistakes when they mean "\\" rather than "\". Using backtics instead makes it very clear what we mean since nothing is escaped.

Comment: @ssemilla By using ` instead of  " it runs but not working properly it prints nothing

Comment: Why are you using `!validation.MatchString()` instead of just `validation.MatchString()`?

Comment: @ssemilla Can you tell me from start how i will write a proper regular expression in golang?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`\.` is an invalid escape sequence. I would suggest you use backticks when defining regular expressions. e.g.

```
regexp.MustCompile(`^https?://.*\.(jpg|gif|png)$`) // this will just check if the url ends with jpg,gif,png
```

If you are not using the capture groups, this is a simpler approach. However when parsing or validating URLs, use [url.Parse()](https://golang.org/pkg/net/url/?m=all#Parse) which provides better validation.

Comment: This might be a more proper regex for the URL: `^https?://(?:[a-z0-9\-]+\.)+[a-z]{2,6}(?:/[^/#?]+)+\.(?:jpg|gif|png)$` which was taken from here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/169625/regex-to-check-if-valid-url-that-ends-in-jpg-png-or-gif

Comment: if I used your code given regexp it was also correct?'

Comment: It won't validate invalid URL characters. I suggest you use `^https?://(?:[a-z0-9\-]+\.)+[a-z]{2,6}(?:/[^/#?]+)+\.(?:jpg|gif|png)$` if you really need a regex.