# How to handle no matching files when using ${f%.gz} syntax

Tags: bash, file, parsing, url

I'm developing a script to process and move away compressed files that get dropped into a certain folder.

The script works perfectly as long as what gets dropped into the folder is a compressed file.  However, if the script executes when there are no compressed files to process the bash function ${f%.gz} gives unexpected results.

Here is the script, with an example of the problem case afterwards:

```
FILES="$INGEST_DIR/*.gz"

for f in $FILES
do
    JUSTFILENAME=${f##/*/}
    syslog -s -l n "Archiving \"$JUSTFILENAME\""
    UNZIPPEDPATH=${f%.gz}
    syslog -s -l n "Moving \"$UNZIPPEDPATH\""
    UNZIPPEDNAME=${UNZIPPEDPATH##/*/}
    syslog -s -l n "    to \"ASR_DIR/$UNZIPPEDNAME\""
    syslog -s -l n "gunzip-ing $f"
    gunzip $f
    mv "$UNZIPPEDPATH" "$ASR_DIR/$UNZIPPEDNAME"
done
```

Again, it works perfectly if there's at least one .gz file in the target directory.

If there aren't any .gz, but there are other files in the directory (which must be there for other reasons) $FILES contains the expanded $INGEST_DIR plus the /*.gz, like this:

```
INGEST_DIR=/path/to/foo
FILES="$INGEST_DIR/*.gz"
echo $FILES
```

will show

```
/path/to/foo/*.gz
```

That isn't especially bad except that

```
for f in $FILES
do
    UNZIPPEDPATH=${f%.gz}
    echo $UNZIPPEDPATH
done
```

yields

```
somefile.txt someotherfile.exe yetsomeotherfile.dat
```

So is there an elegant way to not iterate if there are no such compressed files to handle?  My script is working as well as it is because I just learned about ${f##/*/} and ${f%.gz} from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1199613/extract-filename-and-path-from-url-in-bash-script) SO question & answer, so I'm thinking there might be a better way than

```
FILES="$INGEST_DIR/*.gz"
```

to start things off... or something to do right away before heading into the for loop.

Comment: I agree with [devnull](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18100393/how-to-handle-no-matching-files-when-using-f-gz-syntax/18100521#18100521) that when it comes to files you should use power of `find` tool, as for `${foo%boo}` syntax, if it don't find `boo` in your `foo` var it will return `foo` unchanged. That syntax just tries to cut off `boo` from the end of the `foo` string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using bash you could set nullglob before the loop:

```
shopt -s nullglob
for f in $FILES
```

---- Add ----

Another way to do it is by using while read and process substitution:

```
while IFS= read -r f; do
    ...
done < <(command)
```

Where command could be by the use of find or compgen, only that find could be more specific to files:

```
find -type f -name '*.gz'
compgen -G '*.gz'
```

If we're reading input within the loop, we could use other FDs when opening the file:

```
while IFS= read -ru 4 f; do
    ...
done 4< <(command)
```

Comment: Thank you konsolebox, that works nicely.  I'm going to accept your answer to help with your rep :) even though I personally am going to use the answer @devnull gave since it will be easier for me to know what's going on when I revisit the script 6 months from now!

Comment: Welcome. I added more suggestions just in case they would be helpful as well.

Comment: They are helpful -- I'm still not fluent speaking in bash... in particular, compgen was new to me and looks handy.  http://www.cyberciti.biz/open-source/command-line-hacks/compgen-linux-command/ <-- nice article, even for us Mac OS X users ;)

Answer (score 2):

Use `find` for getting the list of files instead:

```
for f in $(find . -type f -name "*.gz"); do

done
```

For limiting the matches to the current directory, you could say:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -name "*.gz"
```

Comment: Thank you @devnull, I like building the find right into the loop handler because it's clear what you're doing.

Comment: @devnull I think you set IFS to $'\n' as well to prevent splitting of filenames with spaces. Or if in Bash just use <code>find . -type f -name "*.gz" | while IFS= read -r f; do ...; done</code>

Comment: @konsolebox You could quote the `$(...)` and that would take care of *spaces* in filenames.

Comment: @devnull do you mean "$(...)"? but that would only be parsed as one string.

Comment: @konsolebox Did you try the quoted version?

Comment: The only thing that expands to multiple arguments are those of arrays e.g. "${ARRAY[@]}". "$(do something)" won't work. As an example this would only message "|a b c<newline>xyz|" not "|a b c|<newline>|x y z|": for __ in "$(echo a b c; echo x y z)"; do echo "|$__|"; done