# Standard C++ method for validating a URLs format?

Tags: c++

Is there a easy standards-compliant way to check if a URL string is a valid format?  Either through a specific URL-type class or maybe someone could show me how to do a regex validation of it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nope, there isn't one.

On windows, you could take a look at the [IsValidURL()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms775112(VS.85).aspx) function

Comment: Not cross platform, but a close enough answer for now. I guess the only cross platform solution is to use regex patterns.

Answer (score 5):

As others have answered, there is no URL parsing or validation code in the C++ Standard Library nor in STL. Neither is there regular expression parsing.

The first place to look for a solved problem is [Boost](http://www.boost.org/)! [Boost.Regex](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_43_0/libs/regex/doc/html/index.html) should have you on your way. And [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27745/getting-parts-of-a-url-regex) has a great URL regular expression.

Answer (score 4):

> Is there a easy standards-compliant way to check if a URL string is a valid format?

There's nothing in the standard library.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the Poco library:
https://pocoproject.org/docs/Poco.URI.html

Here is my use of it as a URL validator:

```
bool validateUrl(std::string u){
    try {
        Poco::URI uri(u);
    }
    catch (Poco::SyntaxException &e){
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```