# Validate URL in java

Tags: java, regex

Does anyone know how to validate the format of a url in Java using regex?

Thanks

Comment: See also this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27745/getting-parts-of-a-url-regex

Comment: Use regex. Don't use the classes shared below. They may open network connections.

Comment: @MikeNereson that's incorrect. java.net.URI will never accesses the network, it's the best way to validate URIs in Java. The equals() and hadhCode() methods of java.net.URL try to access the network, that's correct, but the java.net.URL constructor most likely won't.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A very sneaky way is to do:

```
try {
    new java.net.URI(myUrl);
} catch(URISyntaxException e) {
    // url badly formed
}
```

Comment: I'd advise against using the URL class (see my answer below for URI) - it does a network lookup to resolve server names.

Comment: I actually meant to use the `URI` class, thanks for pointing this out.

Comment: Thanks for fixing the example.

Comment: The java.net.URI constructor throws a URISyntaxException not a MalformedURLException. At least on the version of Java on Android!

Comment: Firstly, it should be URISyntaxException and not MalformedURLException. And second, using exceptions for normal flow control is not a good practice. Additionally, if you don't intend to use the object returned by `new java.net.URI(myUrl)`, then better avoid the invocation whatsoever. Checking the validity of a URI calls for a URIValidator class which should - to the best of my knowledge - make use of regex (which I'm still looking for around the net. I'll let you know as soon as I find something).

Answer (score 7):

You might be better off using the URI class in Java:
http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/net/URI.html

It will throw an exception in the constructor if it doesn't parse correctly.