# Invalid characters for http URL

Tags: java, http

Can anyone tell me what are the invalid characters for HTTP URL and the best way to validate the same in Java. What I am looking for is **URLString** validation in the URL format: **http(s)://ip:port/URLString**

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to RFC 1738 the following are deemed unsafe:

1. < and > - delimiters around URLs in free text
2. " (double quote) - delimits URLs in some systems
3. ## - delimits a URL from a fragment/anchor identifier that might follow it
4. % - used to indicate character encodings

General unsafe characters:
{ } | \ ^ ~ [ ] `

**Edit:**

Not a duplicate, but includes some thoughts on validation in Java: [Validate URL in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2992973/validate-url-in-java)

Answer (score 4):

You can use any unicode characters you want, as long as they are % encoded.  The explicitly reserved characters are defined in section 2.2 of RFC3986:  https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-2

From the document:

```
  reserved    = gen-delims / sub-delims

  gen-delims  = ":" / "/" / "?" / "#" / "[" / "]" / "@"

  sub-delims  = "!" / "$" / "&" / "'" / "(" / ")"
              / "*" / "+" / "," / ";" / "="
```

Answer (score 0):

Read [RFC1738](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1738.txt) Page 2 and Page 3 on the link for details.

Answer (score 0):

How about using [UrlValidator](http://commons.apache.org/validator/apidocs/org/apache/commons/validator/routines/UrlValidator.html) ? isValidPath method probably useful. :)