# Getting parts of a URL in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, regex, url

I have to match URLs in a text, linkify them, and then display only the host--domain name or IP address--to the user. How can I proceed with JavaScript?

Thanks.
PS: please don't tell me about [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27745/getting-parts-of-a-url-regex); **those** regular expressions are so buggy they can't match `http://google.com`

Comment: "regular expressions are so buggy they can't match"...not sure how ti fix this false assumption.  Are they *ideal*? No, but *correct* regular expressions aren't buggy, unless the engine is.

Comment: `http://google.com` is only a URL fragment; it doesn't have anything to describe what is wanted within the authority domain. (Browsers usually react to this by asking for the root resource, `/`, but that's convention only.)

Comment: I meant "the regular expressions given in that page."

Comment: You’re only looking for absolute URLs, right?

Answer (score 2):

<s>If you don't want to use regular expressions</s>, then you'll need to use things like `indexOf` and such instead. For instance, search for "://" in the text of every element and if you find it and the bit in front of it looks like a protocol (or "scheme"), grab it and the following characters that are valid URI characters ([RFC2396](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2396)). If the result ends in a dot or question mark, remove the dot or question (it probably ends a sentence). There's not really a lot more to say.

**Update**: Ah, I see from your edit that you don't have a problem with regular expressions, just the ones in the answers to that question. Fair enough.

This may well be one of those places where trying to do it *all* with a regular expression is more work that it should be, but using regular expressions as *part* of the solution is helpful. For instance,

```
/[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9+\-.]*:\/\//
```

...may well be a helpful way to find the *beginning* of a URL, since the scheme portion must start with an alpha and then can have zero or more alpha, digit, `+`, `-`, or `.` prior to the `:` ([section 3.1](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2396#section-3.1)).

Comment: But then I got to extract the hostname.

Comment: @sexyprout: Right. That's where the rest of the RFC comes in. (Hostnames are *fairly* straightforward, provided you process escaped characters correctly -- they're everything after the `://` and before the first unescaped `/` or `:`, if any; or end-of-URL-like-characters if there is no unescaped `/` or `:`.)