# Regex to check a Valid URL

Tags: regex

Problem: I need a Regex which would check a given author URL is  valid or not.

Requirement : Author URL is basically a URL from social networking sites/blogs etc having author id (profile id)

For eg .

```
www.facebook.com/RyanMathews 
www.mouthshut.com/zobo.786
```

The regex as per my understanding would have to accept any string(combination of any characters ) after the sites complete address is followed by a " / " .

Tried Using this regex but doesnt support author ids

```
var urlregex = /^((https?:\/\/)?((([a-z\d])+(\-)?([a-z\d])+)+)(\.([a-z\d])+(\-)?([az\d])+)?)(\.[a-z]{2,4}?){1,2}$/i;
```

PS : Please explain the Regex & Logic too :D

Comment: That's contradictory. If the regex accepts any string after the "sites complete address", it can't check if it is a valid author URL.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Getting parts of a URL (Regex)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27745/getting-parts-of-a-url-regex)

Comment: there are many library functions that are 1) unicode capable 2) can trully verify that site is accessible by downloading html or header 3) work in your favourite language. Tell us programming language or simply **UTFG**. You may have seen it, you type into this little box on google.com something like "programming language link check library" and you press I'm feeling lucky button.

Use regular expressions to match strings like 'user not found', not for link checking.

Answer (score 0):

it should Help but I will recommend to do little background reading.

[What is the best regular expression to check if a string is a valid URL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/161738/what-is-the-best-regular-expression-to-check-if-a-string-is-a-valid-url)

[Getting parts of a URL (Regex)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27745/getting-parts-of-a-url-regex#27755)

Please spend some time to read these links and understand them, hope this helps, cheers!

Comment: Nah ! Its a feature I need to support for my product.

Comment: hey, saweet, just asked because it looked like a homework question man, but the above should help you, rest you can get the idea and implement in the language you want.

Answer (score 0):

```
^(http:\/\/){0,1}(www.[^\W]+.com)(\/[^\W]+)+
```

maybe this would work

Comment: `[^\W]` is strictly the same than `\w`

Comment: yes but I am using in this way to exclude other characters as well like using [^\W_] since \w includes _. But of cource you can use \w