# Regex Matching First URL with word

Tags: c#, .net, regex

### **What I need:**

I have a string like this:

> Bike’s: http://website.net/bikeurl Toys: http://website.net/rc-cars
>     Calendar: http://website.net/schedule

I want to match the word I specify and the first URL after it. So if i specify the word as "Bike" i should get:

> Bike’s: http://website.net/bikeurl

Or if possible only the url of the Bike word:

> http://website.net/bikeurl

Or if I specify Toys I should get:

> Toys: http://website.net/rc-cars

or if possible

> http://website.net/rc-cars

### What I am using:

I am using this regex:

```
(Bike)(.*)((https?|ftp):/?/?)(?:(.*?)(?::(.*?)|)@)?([^:/\s]+)(:([^/]*))?(((?:/\w+)*)/)([-\w.]+[^#?\s]*)?(\?([^#]*))?(#(.*))?
```

### Result:

It is matching:

> Bike’s: http://website.net/bikeurl Toys: http://website.net/rc-cars

I only want:

> Bike’s: http://website.net/bikeurl

I am not a regex expert, I tried using {n} {n,} but it either didn't match anything or matches the same

I am using .NET C# so I am testing here http://regexhero.net/tester/

Comment: If you are sure the second word (the url) is always an URL, it would certainly make matching a lot easier, because you wouldn't have to verify the URL's format.

Comment: The regex I added works well only if each pair is on a different line.

Comment: @SwenKooij no I am not sure..

Answer (score 0):

Here is another approach:

`Bike(.*?):\s\S*`

and here is an example how to get the corresponding URL-candidate only:

```
var inputString = "Bike’s: http://website.net/bikeurl Toys: http://website.net/rc-cars Calendar: http://website.net/schedule";
var word = "Bike";
var url = new Regex( word + @"(.*?):\s(?<URL>\S*)" )
    .Match( inputString )
    .Result( "${URL}" );
```

Comment: I need to make sure it is a URL because it is not always a URL

Comment: You could do the verification afterwards. First try to match the basic pattern and then verify that the matches are valid. A valid URL can't contain a space anyway.

Comment: I added example URL extraction logic. If you want to check the URL with RegEx then replace `\S*` part with pattern that matches your detailed URL requirements.

Comment: Alternatively you  may use some .NET URL validator to validate URL-candidate value. RegEx for URL might be very tricky and error-prone...

Comment: I need to make sure it's a url because sometimes it may be Bike Shop: http://website.com and I need to select the website.com URL

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your problem correctly. You need a generic regex that will select a url based on a word. Here is one that would select the url with `bike` in it:

```
(.(?<!\s))*\/\/((?!\s).)*bike((?!\s).)*
```

If you replace `bike` with any other word. It would select the respective URL's.

**EDIT 1:**
Based on your edit, here is one that would select based on the word preceding the URL:

```
(TOKEN((?!\s).)*\s+)((?!\s).)*
```

It would select the word + the URL eg.
`(Bike((?!\s).)*\s+)((?!\s).)*` would select `Bike’s: http://website.net/bikeurl`
`(Toy((?!\s).)*\s+)((?!\s).)*` would select `Toys: http://website.net/rc-cars`
`(Calendar((?!\s).)*\s+)((?!\s).)*` would select `Calendar: http://website.net/schedule`
If you want to make sure the string contains a URL, you can use this instead:

```
(TOKEN((?!\s).)*\s+)((?!\s).)*\/\/((?!\s).)*
```

It will make sure that the 2nd part of the string ie. the one that is supposed to contain a URL has a `//` in between.

Comment: Okay thanks a lot, how can I only select the URL ? Also sometimes the case might be: Bikes for Men: http://website.com and the code didn't work.

Comment: You need to have some definition of a URL right? Make it a part of the pattern. If `website.com` is a URL than `abc.xyz` or `a.qqqq` is not right! That is something you have to work out.

Answer (score 0):

If you really need to make sure it's an url look at this:

[Validate urls with Regex](http://answers.oreilly.com/topic/280-how-to-validate-urls-with-regular-expressions/)

[Regex to check a valid Url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9733141/regex-to-check-a-valid-url)

Here's another solution. I would separate the Bike's, Toys and Calendar in a dictionary and put the url as a value then when needed call it.

```
        Dictionary<string, string> myDic = new Dictionary<string, string>() 
        { 
            { "Bike’s:",   "http://website.net/bikeurl" },

            { "Toys:",     "http://website.net/rc-cars" },

            { "Calendar:", "http://website.net/schedule"  }
        };

        foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> item in myDic)
        {
            if (item.Key.Equals("Bike's"))
            {
                 //do something
            }
        }
```

Hope one of my ideas helps you.