# Extract substring after a certain pattern

Tags: java, string, split

I have the following string:

```
http://xxx/Content/SiteFiles/30/32531a5d-b0b1-4a8b-9029-b48f0eb40a34/05%20%20LEISURE.mp3?&mydownloads=true
```

How can I extract the part after `30/`? In this case, it's `32531a5d-b0b1-4a8b-9029-b48f0eb40a34`.I have another strings having same part upto 30/ and after that every string having different id upto next / which I want.

Comment: Given an arbitrary string, what are the rules for determining which part you keep?  Do you only keep the part that matches the GUID format that is [specified in .NET with a D](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/97af8hh4.aspx)?

Comment: if there are a lot of such strings with different prefixes and as you say a pattern, you might wanna look at `Regular Expressions`

Comment: It would be better if you do sothing similar to this

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27745/getting-parts-of-a-url-regex

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`split` function of `String` class won't help you in this case, because it discards the delimiter and that's not what we want here. you need to make a pattern that looks behind. The look behind synatax is:

```
(?<=X)Y
```

Which identifies any `Y` that is preceded by a `X`.

So in you case you need this pattern:

```
(?<=30/).*
```

compile the pattern, match it with your input, find the match, and catch it:

```
String input = "http://xxx/Content/SiteFiles/30/32531a5d-b0b1-4a8b-9029-b48f0eb40a34/05%20%20LEISURE.mp3?&mydownloads=true";
Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile("(?<=30/).*").matcher(input);
matcher.find();
System.out.println(matcher.group());
```

Comment: sorry, I thought that's what you want. then the pattern would be:(?<=30/)[^/]*

Answer (score 6):

You can do like this:

```
String s = "http://xxx/Content/SiteFiles/30/32531a5d-b0b1-4a8b-9029-b48f0eb40a34/05%20%20LEISURE.mp3?&mydownloads=true";
        System.out.println(s.substring(s.indexOf("30/")+3, s.length()));
```

Comment: While this is certainly an answer to his question, I don't think he wanted the entire rest of the string.  Plus, why would you use the 2-argument version of substring, if you're just going to use length as the 2nd argument?  Look up the 1-arg version.

Answer (score 2):

Just for this one, or do you want a generic way to do it ?

```
String[] out = mystring.split("/")
return out[out.length - 2]
```

I think the / is definitely the delimiter you are searching for.
I can't see the problem you are talking about Alex

EDIT : Ok, Python got me with indexes.

Comment: That s why I am putting size -1. To return exactly 32531a5d-b0b1-4a8b-9029-b48f0eb40a34

Comment: You are returning the last part of the string here, he actually needs the second to last: `return out[out.length - 2];`

Answer (score 1):

Regular expression is the answer I think. However, how the expression is written depends on the data (url) format you want to process. Like this one:

```
    Pattern pat = Pattern.compile("/Content/SiteFiles/30/([a-z0-9\\-]+)/.*");
    Matcher m = pat.matcher("http://xxx/Content/SiteFiles/30/32531a5d-b0b1-4a8b-9029-b48f0eb40a34/05%20%20LEISURE.mp3?&mydownloads=true");
    if (m.find()) {
        System.out.println(m.group(1));
    }
```

Comment: I am getting last part of the string also from this i.e after last / which I dont want I juat want second last part

Comment: I made a little modifications to my answer.

Comment: still I am getting last part of string

Comment: That's weird. :/ I'm getting `32531a5d-b0b1-4a8b-9029-b48f0eb40a34`.