# Extract parts of a URL

Tags: regex

Basically I am looking to extract a URL until it encounters a number which may or may not be present

Examples:

```
http://www.test.com/products/cards/product_code/12345/something_else
http://www.test.com/products/cards/product_code2/
```

Desired output -

```
http://www.test.com/products/cards/product_code/
http://www.test.com/products/cards/product_code2/
```

Additional Information - Languauge agnostic regex similar to this question 
[Getting parts of a URL (Regex)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27745/getting-parts-of-a-url-regex)

Many Thanks

Answer (score 1):

**This might not be a job for regexes, but for existing tools in your language of choice.**  What language are you using? You probably don't want to use a regex, but rather an existing module that has already been written, tested, and debugged.

If you're using PHP, you want the [`parse_url`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php) function.

If you're using Perl, you want the [`URI`](http://search.cpan.org/dist/URI/) module.

If you're using Ruby, use the [`URI`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/uri/rdoc/URI.html) module.

Comment: .NET has the `Uri.GetComponents()` method.

Comment: Thanks, is there a canonical doc page on the web I can link to? I'll add it to my stock answer clip file.

Comment: MSDN has [a page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/txt7706a.aspx) on the `Uri` class; `GetComponents` is one of its methods.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple regex way of doing it:

```
<?php

$url = "http://www.test.com/products/cards/product_code/1234";
$pattern = '/\/[0-9]/';

preg_match($pattern, $url, $matches);

if (count($matches) > 0) {
    echo substr($url, 0, strpos($url,$matches[0])+1);
} else {
    echo $url;
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `sed` :

```
sed 's#\(http://.*/\)[0-9]\+.*#\1#'
```

which means :

- capture any characters starting with `http://` up to (not including) the first encountered digit with is preceded by a slash : `\(http://.*/\)[0-9]\+`
- continue matching any character up to the end of the line : `.*$`
- replace these with what has been previously captured : `\1`

I chose `#` as the `sed` separator instead of the classical `/` because otherwise you would have to escape these characters in your regexp.