# How to catch filetypes in malformed URLs

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

Just wondering how I can extract or match the specific file type, since there are a lot of malformed URLs and directories.

So I need a good regex to match only the real ones.

```
http://domain.com/1/image.jpg <-match .jpg
http://domain.com/1/image_1.jpg/.gif <-match first .jpg
http://domain.com/1/image_1.jpg/image.png <-match first .jpg
http://domain.com/1/image_1.jpg <-match .jpg
http://domain.com/1/image.jpg.jpeg <-match only the first .jpg
http://domain.com/1/.jpg <-not match
http://domain.com/.jpg.jpg <- not match
/1/.jpg <-not match
/.jpg.png <-match the first jpg
/image.jpg.png <-match the first jpg
```

I'm trying with this piece of code:

```
preg_match_all('([a-zA-Z0-9.-_](jpg))i', $url, $matches);
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

```
preg_match('(^(http://domain.com/\w.*?\.jpg))i', $url, $matches);
```

This will match everything from the start of the string up to the first `.jpg`.  The filename part must start with a letter, number, or `_`.

Comment: this works nice, but I forgot that some urls are incomplete, just referenced directories like /1/.jpg.gif

Answer (score 0):

Parsing URLs with regular expressions is usually a bad idea.  See [Getting parts of a URL (Regex)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27745/getting-parts-of-a-url-regex) for a related question.  In particular, look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27745/getting-parts-of-a-url-regex/27821#27821), then realize that [`parse_url`](http://docs.php.net/parse_url) might be a good start.  Take `$result['path']` and use a file name parsing API on it to extract the extension.

I'm not sure exactly what you are asking for though.

```
http://domain.com/1/image_1.jpg/.gif <-match first .jpg
http://domain.com/1/image_1.jpg/image.png <-match first .jpg
```

In both of these cases *image_1.jpg* is a perfectly valid directory name.  You could split the path on '/' and check each one for "validity".

**Edit** I just noticed that you need this to work with relative URLs as well.  `parse_url` does not work well in that case.