# match 2 urls with localhost

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm having the hardest time with javascript regex, can't figure out how to match my url:

```
http://localhost:11111/#!/quote/18283
```

and

```
http://www.myurl.com/#!/quote/23834
```

with the same regex.

I just don't understand the regex rules that well.

Comment: What have been your attempts so far?

Comment: FYI - regex is entirely independent of other languages.  Different languages use it differently, but something that is a correct RegEx match will be a correct RegEx match in Java, Javascript, C#, and thousands of others.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Getting parts of a URL (Regex)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27745/getting-parts-of-a-url-regex)

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Are you trying to extract some data from the URL? Anyway, `^http://\w+(\.\w+)*(:\d+)?/#!/(\w+/?)+$` would match both and all other urls having that structure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`http://[\w\d\.:]+/#!/quote/\d{5}` - but obviously that is without any other context. 
I don't know what your negative cases are. Which parts of the URLs are important, etc, etc.

Comment: I just need the number at the end to vary in length, so I'm assuming I can change to http://[\w\d\.:]+/#!/quote/\d{1,10} and that will give me up to 10 digits.  Thanks a lot

Comment: You can just use `\d+`

Comment: As with @Neil Neyman's answer above, you can use `\d+` instead of `\d{5}` to give yourself `1 or more` digits.

Comment: Thanks to everyone for the help

Answer (score 1):

One hint I can add is, if you are only looking to match a specific domain.com with localhost you can use alternation (either/or) with the pipe | symbol like (this is just for one portion of the regex:

```
((www\.)?myurl\.com|localhost:\d+)
```