# How to remove some part of URL by regex?

Tags: java, regex, string

I have full link like this:

```
http://localhost:8080/suffix/rest/of/link
```

How to write regex in Java which will return only main part of url with suffix: `http://localhost/suffix` and without: `/rest/of/link`?

- possible protocols: http, https
- possible ports: many possibilities

I've assumed that I need to remove whole text after 3rd occurrence of `'/'` mark (including). 
I would like to do it as below, but I do not know regex well, can you help please how to write regex correctly?

```
String appUrl = fullRequestUrl.replaceAll("(.*\\/{2})", ""); //this removes 'http://' but this is not my case
```

Comment: What's the point of the regex? Just find the index of the fourth `/`.

Comment: The point is to retrieve base application url (protocol+serverName+serverPort+contextPath) from url which can be full it means which can have also servlet path and params which I am not interested.

Comment: `URL` will not recognize contextPath from simple String. I've already tried it.

Comment: See if this helps : http://stackoverflow.com/q/27745/2666913

Comment: what do you mean `URL` won't recognize the context path?  certainly it will.

Comment: after initialize by constructor URL(String url) then we don't have info about contextPath. URL gives protocol, host, port, path. The path property contains contextPath and other stuff. So I still need to parse it some how

Comment: yes, obviously.  you would need to separate out the part of the path you care about.  but URL will handle the larger parsing issues and leave you with a simple problem (pulling "suffix" off of the path).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code gets main part of URL:

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class RegexpExample {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String urlStr  = "http://localhost:8080/suffix/rest/of/link";
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("^((.*:)//([a-z0-9\\-.]+)(|:[0-9]+)/([a-z]+))/(.*)$");

        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(urlStr);
        if(matcher.find())
        {
            //there is a main part of url with suffix:
            String mainPartOfUrlWithSuffix = matcher.group(1);
            System.out.println(mainPartOfUrlWithSuffix);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

I am not sure why you want to use Regex for this. Java provides a **[Query URL Objects](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/urls/urlInfo.html)** for doing the same for you.

Here is an example taken from the same [site](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/urls/urlInfo.html) to show how it works:

```
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;

public class ParseURL {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        URL aURL = new URL("http://example.com:80/docs/books/tutorial"
                           + "/index.html?name=networking#DOWNLOADING");

        System.out.println("protocol = " + aURL.getProtocol());
        System.out.println("authority = " + aURL.getAuthority());
        System.out.println("host = " + aURL.getHost());
        System.out.println("port = " + aURL.getPort());
        System.out.println("path = " + aURL.getPath());
        System.out.println("query = " + aURL.getQuery());
        System.out.println("filename = " + aURL.getFile());
        System.out.println("ref = " + aURL.getRef());
    }
}
```

Here is the output displayed by the program:

```
protocol = http
authority = example.com:80
host = example.com
port = 80
path = /docs/books/tutorial/index.html
query = name=networking
filename = /docs/books/tutorial/index.html?name=networking
ref = DOWNLOADING
```

Comment: @Boris the Spider:- Were you refering this?

Comment: nice, but the point is that I need to seperate contextPath which is the first part after port in url. So `URL` class is not able to recognize it (but it would be nice). Here in your example contextPath is `docs` - and with `URL` I still need to parse `path` and exlude rest of text from `path`

Comment: How about finding the index of the / and then do what you want?

Comment: @Roman:- Yes that may help. Give that a try! :) P.S. And if this helped you then do upvote or accept this as an answer! :)