# extract all URLs in a free text block using RegEx

Tags: c#, regex

I'm attempting to detect all URLs listed in a free text block. I'm using the .nets `Regex.Matches` call.. with the following regex: `(http|https)://[^\s "']{4,}`

Now, I've put in the following text:
    here is a link http://somelink.com
    here is a link that I didn't space withhttp://nospacelink.com/something?something=&39358235
    http://nospacelink.com/something?something=&12233454
    [here](http://alreadyhandledlink.com) is a link I already handled.
    Here is some secret t&cs you're not allowed to know https://somethingbad.com
    Just to be a little annoying I've put in a new address thingy capture type of 'http://somethinginspeechmarks.com' and what are you going to do now?
    here is a link http://postTextLink.com at then some post text
    Here is a link with a full stop http://alinkwithafullstoplink.com. And then some more.

and I get the following output:

```
http://somelink.com
http://nospacelink.com?something=&39358235
http://nospacelink.com?something=&12233454
http://alreadyhandledlink.com
https://somethingbad.com
http://somethinginspeechmarks.com
http://postTextLink.com
http://alinkwithafullstoplink.com.
```

Please notice the full stop on the last entry. How can I update my regex to say "If there is a full stop at the end, please ignore it?"

Also, please note that "[Getting parts of a URL (Regex)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27745/getting-parts-of-a-url-regex)" has nothing to do with my question, as that question is about how to break down a particular URL. I want to extract multiple, complete urls. Please see my input and current outputs for clarification! 
I have got a regex already that does most of what I want, but isn't quite right. Could you please explain where my approach might be improved?

Comment: Loving that I can't just mark my own question as duplicate *lol*

Comment: Change to `(http|https)://[^\s "']{4,}(?<!\.)` - added `(?<!\.)` in the end.

Comment: @Kilazur, I was meaning I could only vote it as a duplicate, as apposed to just closing it as duplicate...

Comment: @smerny, could you provide an example of a url which wouldn't pass with (http|https)://[^\s "']{4,}[^\.\s"']+?

Comment: @ImmortalBlue, that regex isn't in the answer marked as duplicate

Answer (score 1):

I would add something like `[^\.]` to the pattern.

This pattern says that the last char can't be a full stop.

So for `(http|https)://[^\s "']{4,}[^\.]` it will try to match all adresses not ending with a full stop.

Edit:

This one should be better as said in comments: [^.\s"']

Comment: This would actually match `http://alinkwithafullstoplink.com. ` (with an extra space at the end) as well as `http://somethinginspeechmarks.com'` (the quote mark)

Comment: Exact !
then [^\.\s"']+

Comment: User wants dots, just not at the end.

Answer (score -1):

**Updated:**

Consider the following minor change to your pattern:

```
(http|https)://[^\s "']{4,}(?=\.)
```

Comment: that stops at any ., so gives the output of `http://somelink` and `http://nospacelink` etc...

Comment: Fixed the pattern. Try that for size.

Comment: That still returns the . at the end...
    `http://linkwithafullstop.com.`
    `http://alinkwithafullstoplink.com.`

Comment: Made a minor change to the pattern... . to \.