# Regex: Find & Replace in String

Tags: java, regex

I have a string

```
String customHtml = "<html><body><iframe src=https://zarabol.rediff.com/widget/end-of-cold-war-salman-hugs-abhishek-bachchan?search=true&header=true id=rediff_zarabol_widget name=rediff_zarabol_widget scrolling=auto transparency= frameborder=0 height=500 width=100%></iframe></body></html>";
```

I need to replace the last index of weburl with another string. In the above example replace

```
end-of-cold-war-salman-hugs-abhishek-bachchan
```

with

```
srk-confesses-found-gauri-to-be-physically-attractive
```

I tried using Lazy `/begin.*?end/` but it fails.
Any help will be highly appreciated. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You definitely need a html parser. Do not use regex for html content. It slows down.

Comment: I don't think regex is the right tool for parsing HTML.  You might gain something from reading http://stackoverflow.com/q/1732348

Comment: try using JSoup for parsing HTML instead of regex based match.

Comment: I think regex is the right choice because html parser can parse only the whole url in this case

Comment: @Faheem did all these tags are on a single line?

Comment: View this question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27745/getting-parts-of-a-url-regex

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regex:

```
(?<=\/)[^\/]*(?=\?)
```

Java regex:

```
(?<=/)[^/]*(?=\\?)
```

Replacement string:

```
srk-confesses-found-gauri-to-be-physically-attractive
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/gF5vY6/1)

Java code would be,

```
String url= "<html><body><iframe src=https://zarabol.rediff.com/widget/end-of-cold-war-salman-hugs-abhishek-bachchan?search=true&header=true id=rediff_zarabol_widget name=rediff_zarabol_widget scrolling=auto transparency= frameborder=0 height=500 width=100%></iframe></body></html>";
String m1 = url.replaceAll("(?<=\\/)[^\\/]*(?=\\?)", "srk-confesses-found-gauri-to-be-physically-attractive");
System.out.println(m1);
```

[IDEONE](http://ideone.com/GRPAQY)

Comment: No need to escape forward slashes.

Answer (score 1):

This should do it:

```
url = url.replaceAll("(?<=/)[^/?]+(?=\\?)", "your new text");
```

Answer (score 0):

Regex:
[^/]*?(?:\?)

You must remove "/" from regex.

Answer (score 0):

As others have said, a DOM parser would be better. For completion, here is a regex solution that will work for your input:

```
String replaced = yourString.replaceAll("(https://\\S+/)[^?]+", 
                    "$1srk-confesses-found-gauri-to-be-physically-attractive");
```

**Explanation**

- `(https://\\S+/)` captures to Group 1 the literal `https://`, any chars that are not white-spaces `\S+`, and a forward slash `/`
- `[^?]+` matches any chars that are not `?` (the text to replace)
- We replace with `$1` Group 1 (unchanged) and the text you specified