# How to extract a substring using regex for this pattern

Tags: java, regex, substring

i have to extract a string between `/` and `?`, i.e `exampleproduct`

```
https://local.host.com/order/faces/Home/myorder/exampleproduct?_adf.ctrl-state=mfun9p14r_19
```

how  to write regular expression for this
i am using this logic but i am unable to

```
 private static String extractPageNameFromURL(String urlFull) {    
    if (urlFull != null) {
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("/(.*?).jspx?");
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(urlFull);
        while (matcher.find()) {
            String str1 = matcher.group(1);
            String[] dataRows = str1.split("/");
            urlFull = dataRows[dataRows.length - 1];
        }
    }
    return urlFull;
}


 public static void main(String[] args) {
 System.out.println(DtmUtils.extractPageNameFromURL("https://local.host.com/order/faces/Home/myorder/exampleproduct?_adf.ctrl-state=mfun9p14r_19"));

}
```

Thanks
Raj

Comment: do you want to get the word between `/` and `?` ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27745/getting-parts-of-a-url-regex

Comment: i am not getting exampleproduct which in between " ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To match `exampleproduct` in your input this lookahead based regex will work for you:

```
[^/]+(?=\?)
```

In Java code:

```
Pattern pat = Pattern.compile("[^/]+(?=\\?)");
```

#### [RegEx Demo](http://regex101.com/r/iE0kC7/1)

Answer (score 1):

If I'm following what you're asking, then you're attempting to pull `exampleproduct` from the URL.

Here's the regex to use to accomplish this. Group 1 should have the name after the last `/` and before the first `?` after that slash.

```
^.*\/([^?]+)\?.*$
```

See an example of the [regex](http://regex101.com/r/zJ1lE6/1)

```
^           -- Beginning of line anchor
.*          -- find 0 or more characters. Note the * is greedy.
\/          -- Find a literal /.
([^?]+)     -- Capture everything that is not a question mark
\?          -- Find a literal question mark
.*          -- now match everything after the question mark
$           -- end of line anchor
```

and here's a quick example of using it in Java. This is a quick example, and will need to be modified before using it.

```
String urlFull = "https://local.host.com/order/faces/Home/myorder/exampleproduct?_adf.ctrl-state=mfun9p14r_19";

Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("^.*\\/([^?]+)\\?.*$");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(urlFull);

matcher.find();

String p = matcher.group(1);
System.out.println(p);
```

I didn't follow why the original regex you wrote had the `.jspx?`, but if there's more to the problem you'll need to update the question to explain.

Answer (score 0):

This pattern might work for you `\?(.*)`.

This regex finds a question mark and selects everything after it.

Answer (score 0):

I tried this pattern with your path and it worked fine: `([\w_-]*)(\.)*([\w_-]*)?(?=\?)`

It would also match, if your filename had a file ending.