# JS regex to check url

Tags: javascript, regex

This must habe been asked a million times, but I can't find a solution to fit my needs.

I need to regex to check if a string contains an url, then get it. So I have this :

```
    var regexToken = /(((ftp|https?):\/\/)[\-\w@:%_\+.~#?,&\/\/=]+)|((mailto:)?[_.\w-]+@([\w][\w\-]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,3})/g;

    while( (matchArray = regexToken.exec( source )) !== null )
    {
        var result = matchArray[0];

    }

    return result;
```

This can retrieve :

- http(s)|ftp://domain.com
- http(s)|ftp://www.domain.com
- http(s)|ftp://www.domain.com/with/path

But I need to modify that so it could also retrieve url that just begin with www :

- www.domain.com/with/path

How to do that ? I'm really noob with regex...

Comment: Check this 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27745/getting-parts-of-a-url-regex

Comment: I don't see how that can help me ?

Comment: Take a look at this https://github.com/segmentio/is-url/blob/master/index.js#L12

Answer (score 0):

Something like this may help:

```
/(((ftp|https?):\/\/|www\.)[continue from here]/
```

This will start matches allowing `ftp://`, `http://`, `https://` or `www.`

Answer (score 0):

Try this way to match url of different format.Like,

```
 var re = /^((ftp|https?):\/\/|www\.).*/gm;
    var str = 'http://domain.com\nhttps://domain.com\nftp://domain.com\nftp://www.domain.com\nhttp://www.domain.com\nhttps://www.domain.com\nhttp://www.domain.com/with/path\nhttps://www.domain.com/with/path\nftp://www.domain.com/with/path\nwww.domain.com/with/path \n\n';
    var m;

    while ((m = re.exec(str)) != null) {
    if (m.index === re.lastIndex) {
    re.lastIndex++;
    }
    // View your result using the m-variable.
    // eg m[0] etc.
    }
```

[image]

[DEMO](https://www.regex101.com/r/tC2aS4/1)