# Getting dynamic value from URL

Tags: javascript, jquery

I tried multiple ways with splits, substrings to get the value of employeeid below, but is there an effective regex way?

```
/api/getValue;id=12345;age:25;employeeid=4?test=true&othervalues=test
```

I want to get the employee id value, which is 4. How can I do that?

Comment: Does a regex /employeeid=[0-9]+/ not work?

Comment: it should be generic enough, i can pass employeeid or age or anything and it should get the value. They are not part of querystring thats the problem

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27745/getting-parts-of-a-url-regex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a simple regular expression to match on `employeeid`:

```
// Extract the employeeid with a RegEx
var employeeid = url.match(/;employeeid=(\d+)/, url)[1];

console.log(employeeid);

>>> 4
```

Or if you'd like this as a function so that any value can be selected you could use the following:

```
function getValue(url, name) {
    var m = new RegExp(';' + name + '[=:](\\d+)', 'g').exec(url);
    if (m) {
        return m[1];
    }
    return '';
}

var age = getValue(
    '/api/getValue;id=12345;age:25;employeeid=4?test=true&othervalues=test', 
    'age'
    );

console.log(age);

>>> 25
```

Comment: curretly i did this way, but not happy

Comment: hi @kobe I've updated my answer to include a simple regular expression option specifically for `employeeid` - is that what you were after?

Comment: @kobe if you `did this way, but not happy`, please update your question with **the code you've tried**, with the result you've got and **why** it's not the result you want/expect: `not happy` is definitely not explicit enough imho

Comment: @kobe I've also added an example of using a function to extract a specific value - I realise my initial example didn't cater for the `age:25` key/value pair being separated by a `:` not a `=` so I've removed that from my original answer.