# Splitting code can compile, but does not start

Tags: java, string, split

I wrote a method that takes a website address and returns a `String[]`, which contains protocol, domain and context (if there is one).

Example: `http://stackoverflow.com/questions =>  {"http", "stackoverflow", "questions"}`

```
String[] splitAddress(String address) {
String[] split = address.split("://");
String[] split1 = split[1].split(".com");
if (split1[1] == "") {
    String[] end = new String[2];
    end[0] = split[0];
    end[1] = split1[0];
    return end;
} else {
    String[] e = new String[3];
    e[0] = split[0];
    e[1] = split1[0];
    e[2] = split1[1];
    return e;
}
```

It can compile, but when I start this, nothing happens.
Where is a mistake?

Comment: What do you mean by "when I start this" ? How do you "start" this? What do you mean by "nothing happens"?

Comment: `.` means "any character" in regex. If you need dot, use `\.`. And comparing strings using `==` won't work in most cases.

Comment: I wrote method in Main and start. (Using Eclipse - no errors)

Comment: Console shows `[Ljava.lang.String;@2a139a55`

Comment: What's in your main method?

Comment: `Tester t = new Tester();
  String[] a = t.splitAddress("http://stackoverflow.com/questions");
  System.out.println(a);`

Comment: Tester is class name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`System.out.println(array)` does not work for Arrays. You must write array values to console in a for loop or you can use `Arrays.toString(array)` method as M. Mariscal wrote below. Code below is working, you need only remove the `/` character before "/question".

```
public class SplitTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String[] array = splitAddress("http://stackoverflow.com/questions");
        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            System.out.println(array[i]);
        }
    }

    static String[] splitAddress(String address) {
        String[] split = address.split("://");
        String[] split1 = split[1].split(".com");
        if (split1.length < 2) {
            String[] end = new String[2];
            end[0] = split[0];
            end[1] = split1[0];
            return end;
        } else {
            String[] e = new String[3];
            e[0] = split[0];
            e[1] = split1[0];
            e[2] = split1[1];
            return e;

        }
    }
}
```

Result:

```
http
stackoverflow
/questions
```

Comment: Can lack of `static` modifier in method splitAddress may be the cause?

Comment: No, cause is you are using System.out.println(array). It is not prints the elements of an array.

Comment: OK. It works if as address we give http://stackoverflow.com/questions, but if we give http://stackoverflow.com, then appear an error: `java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`.

Comment: try change  `String[] split1 = split[1].split(".com");` to  `String[] split1 = split[1].split(".com", -1);`

Comment: And if you need a more complex regex to parse an url, take a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27745/getting-parts-of-a-url-regex

Comment: But it still returns 3 Strings in String[]. Is it possible to do, that it will be return 2 String if address is without text after `.com`?

Answer (score 0):

I think that you are looking for something like this:

```
 import java.util.Scanner;

    public class Main
    {

        public static void main (String[] args){

     System.out.println(java.util.Arrays.toString(
     splitAddress("http://stackoverflow.com/questions")));
        }

        public static String[] splitAddress(String address) {
        String[] split = address.split("://");
        String[] split1 = split[1].split(".com/");
        if (split1[1] == "") {
            String[] end = new String[2];
            end[0] = split[0];
            end[1] = split1[0];
            return end;
        } else {
            String[] e = new String[3];
            e[0] = split[0];
            e[1] = split1[0];
            e[2] = split1[1];
            return e;
        }
    }
}
```

finally shows: [http, stackoverflow, questions]