# Regex matching URL with www and no consecutive dots

Tags: java, regex, url

Can you help me with regex?

I have line

```
"Sites www.google.com и www.ridd.rdd..com good."
```

After parse I'v get this type of line:

```
"Sites http://www.google.com и www.ridd.rdd..com good."
```

Problem with checking consecutive points. **To sites with an error (with two points in a row) `"http//:"` should not be appended**.

My regex:

```
 Matcher matchr = Pattern.compile("w{3}(\\.\\w+)+[a-z]{2,6}").matcher(text);

        while (matchr.find()) {
            text = text.replace(matchr.group(0), "http://" + matchr.group(0));
        }

        System.out.println(text);
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27745/getting-parts-of-a-url-regex

Comment: Егор, just add `+` after `\\.`.

Comment: So are you trying to add "http://" to the start of all the url strings?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew It didn't help

Comment: See [this demo](http://ideone.com/STFdHe), please explain what output is expected if it does not work for you.

Comment: @jazibobs Yes, before Url

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew to sites with an error (with two points in a row) should not append the "http"//"

Comment: How can you distinguish between `"Sites www.google.com и www.ridd.rdd..com good."` and `"Sites www.ridd.rdd..com и www.google.com."`? What are URL boundaries? BTW, try [`text.replaceAll("\\b(?!\\S*\\.{2})w{3}(\\.+\\w+)+[a-z]{2,6}\\b", "http://$0")`](http://ideone.com/vdVVzv).

Comment: Before regex: "Sites www.google.com и www.ridd.rdd..com good." After: "Sites http://www.google.com и www.ridd.rdd..com good.";  http added only www.[site].[prefix]

Comment: The question got closed with [*Getting parts of a URL (Regex)*](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27745/getting-parts-of-a-url-regex) that is totally unrelated to the current problem.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew thants. latest regex working

Comment: Ok, I will edit the question and post an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Your regex `w{3}(\\.\\w+)+[a-z]{2,6}` matches a *part of* the second bad "URL", **www.ridd.rdd**..com. So, you need to make sure the substring you match has no consecutive dots. You may use word boundaries and a negative lookahead `(?!\S*\.{2})`.

Use

```
String text = "Sites www.google.com и www.ridd.rdd..com good.";
text = text.replaceAll("\\b(?!\\S*\\.{2})w{3}(\\.\\w+)+[a-z]{2,6}\\b", "http://$0");
// => Sites http://www.google.com и www.ridd.rdd..com good.
```

See the [IDEONE demo](http://ideone.com/vdVVzv)

Pattern explanation:

- `\\b` - leading word boundary
- `(?!\\S*\\.{2})` - there should not be any consecutive dots in the non-whitespace chunk to follow
- `w{3}` - match `www`
- `(\\.\\w+)+` - 1+ sequences of `.` followed with 1+ alphanumeric or underscore characters
- `[a-z]{2,6}` - make sure there are 2 to 6 `a-z` letters...
- `\\b` - at the end of this "word"

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation)

Comment: Glad to help, please consider accepting the answer since it worked for you.