# RegEx: Removing select parts of a URL, except variables

Tags: javascript, regex, string, url, split

Trying to remove parts of a URL via RegEx.

I'm getting my content via an AJAX requst thus I cannot use

```
$(location).attr('search').split("&")[2]
```

[My RegEx (Regex101)](https://regex101.com/r/xF1oC6/2)

Any direct answer will be greatly appreciated as I cannot comprehend RegEx, other better or more efficient suggestions will also be greatly valued.

Comment: for most good browsers you may want to look at the [URL object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/URL)

Comment: What exactly are you trying to remove from the URL?

Comment: you don't need to specifically use the `location` object, just use `.split()` on whatever url or string is being returned. `\?.+$` will return all of the variables in a url however

Comment: @Jaromanda X, Like I said, I'm getting my data via an AJAX query, thus there is no URL to take data from.

Comment: Your question states that you are trying to remove parts of a URL ... now you say there is no URL ... you can't have both

Comment: 'I'm getting my content via an AJAX requst thus I cannot use

$(location).attr('search').split("&")[2]'

I have the URL, but not in the fashion of im at the location, its just a string

Answer (score 0):

Straightforward approach: [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27745/getting-parts-of-a-url-regex) already has helpful answers on how to parse a URL with and without a RegEx. Try one of those methods, then keep the parts you want and discard the ones you don't.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I got your question fully. For the example you have, this is the regexp I have for your matching. May not be the elegant ones, but it should work for your example.

http[s]*://opskins.com/?loc=shop_search&app=730_2

http[s]://[a-z]+.com/\?[a-z]+=[a-z_]+&[a-z]+=[0-9_]+