# How to match only the domain part of a URL with regex?

Tags: python, regex

I'm writing a Python code that would process a block of text which, among the text useless for me, features URLs. Out of the text block I only need the domains, not the full URLs. Example input:

```
47.91.158.176 or 54.145.185.110 port 80 - gooolgeremf.top - GET /search.php
47.90.205.113 or 35.187.59.173 port 80 - voperforseanx.top/site/chrome_update.html
```

So here I need only `gooolgeremf.top` and `voperforseanx.top` matched but the regex I've written will also match `search.php` and `chrome_update.html`.

What I'm thinking is that the regex should stop matching after `/`. However I don't know how to implement it and especially how to not prevent matching domains that appear after the first `/` in the whole text file.

The way it works so far in my code:

```
regexdm="[A-Za-z0-9]{1,}\.[A-Za-z0-9]{1,10}\.?[A-Za-z]{1,}\.?[A-Za-z]{1,}"
dmsc=re.findall(regexdm, iocsd.read())
```

Comment: Do you mean FQDN/hostname, or the domain name only ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd suggest adding delimiter conditions. Provided a domain name may be only surrounded by spaces, start/end of line and two forward slashed before the domain and one slash after it, the regex would be:

```
(?: |//|^)([A-Za-z0-9]{1,}\.[A-Za-z0-9]{1,10}\.?[A-Za-z]{1,}\.?[A-Za-z]{1,})(?: |/|$)
```

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/TQKlDP/1

Comment: RaminNietzsche: that's because the original regex disallows such domain names (i.e. ones having less than three letters in the TLD). I admit that it looks like the domain name filter is too restrictive and even erroneous but I prepared an answer in assumption that such restrictions are intentional (or at least acceptable) and the only issue was to distinguish such domain names from other parts of the text.

Answer (score 1):

Regex is not the easiest way to do it, you should use `urlparse.urlparse`:

```
from urlparse import urlparse
parsed_uri = urlparse('http://voperforseanx.top/site/chrome_update.html')
print parsed_uri.netloc
```

Gives

```
voperforseanx.top
```

---

But, for reference, here is how to handle URLs with regex: [Getting parts of a URL (Regex)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27745/getting-parts-of-a-url-regex?answertab=votes#tab-top)

Comment: netloc will not show the domain, if you remove the 'http://' as shown in question input. return None.

Answer (score 0):

In Python 2.7.13, an alternative way example (depends on the input pattern):

```
str = "47.90.205.113 or 35.187.59.173 port 80 - voperforseanx.top/site/chrome_update.html"
parsed_uri = str.split()[6].split('/')[0]
print parsed_uri
>> voperforseanx.top
```

Answer (score 0):

```
(\b[\w\.]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,}\b)(.+)$
```

In this regex the:

```
(\b[\w\.]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,}\b)
```

part, will match what you are looking for, the rest is scrap. To work, this regex needs a gmi modificator.

Comment: What is a "gmi modificator"? Do you have a reference?

Comment: http://www.ciaomondo.it/regular-expressions/english-guide.php#flags In this guide there is a simple explanation