# Truncating the end of variables based on pattern

Tags: python, regex

I have a list of URLs in formats such as "www.blah.com/en-us" and I need to cut-off anything after the "www.blah.com". I've tried using the following:

```
import re
website = www.blah.com/en-us
cleanURL = re.sub('(.|\n)*?com', "", website)
```

Output: 'en-us'

So I'm getting the opposite of what I want. Sorry if this post isn't correctly formatted, first time asking a question.

Comment: Strange, when I run your code, I don't get `en-us`, I get `NameError: name 'www' is not defined`. Are you sure this is the exact code you're running?

Comment: Possibly a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27745/getting-parts-of-a-url-regex

Answer (score 4):

How about just using

```
website = "www.blah.com/en-us"
cleanURL = website.split("/",1)[0]
```

?

Comment: You don't need the conditional; `"www.blah.com".split("/") == ["www.blah.com"]`

Answer (score 2):

Is using regex a must? If there's no protocol (e.g. http://) in the URLs that you're trying to process, you could just use `your_url_string.split('/', 1)[0]` which should split on the first instance of '/' and gives you the part before the split.