# javascript:How to extract country code from url using regex

Tags: javascript, regex

there is country code in url which i need to extract by regex and javascript.

### so my possible url would be

**http://example.com/gb/index.aspx**

**http://localhost:2020/gb/index.aspx**

**http://example:2020/gb/index.aspx**

these code i tried but regex works for a specific type of url.

```
var url = "http://example.com/gb/index.aspx";
//Get the language code
var countrycode = /com\/([^\/]+)/.exec(url)[1];
```

the above code works when url look like **http://example.com/gb/index.aspx** but the moment url look like **http://localhost:2020/gb/index.aspx** or **http://example:2020/gb/index.aspx** then above code does not works. so tell me which regex i need to use which can extract country code from above 3 different kind of url. need some hint. thanks

Comment: Possible help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/27755/259889

Comment: try `location.pathname.split('/')[1]`. In this page returns `"questions"`

Comment: If country will always be the after the domain, like that, charliefl's suggestion works: it breaks up the string in array elems split by `/` character. And you want the second element of that array.

Comment: @charlietfl i tried this `var url="http://mysite:2020/gb/index.aspx";
alert(url.split('/')[1]);` but no luck.

Comment: ```a.split("/")[3]```

Comment: if it's always 2 letter county code, try this: https://regex101.com/r/zU4vX8/3`

Comment: @charlietfl this works `var url="http://mysite:2020/gb/index.aspx";
alert(url.split('/')[3]);`

Comment: @blueren thanks this works a.split("/")[3]

Comment: @KresimirPendic your regex return /gb/ but i want gb without country code. so what regex i need to use?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`^.{8}[^\/]*\/([^\/]*)`

- `^` : anchor at start
- `.{8}` :skip over first 8 chars (http(s)://)
- `[^\/]`: match over any chars except '/'
- `\/` match the first slash after that
- `([^\/]*)` : create a new group and match any char except '/' (this is the country code)

```js
var urls = [
  "http://example.com/gb/index.aspx",
  "http://localhost:2020/gb/index.aspx",
  "http://example:2020/gb/index.aspx"
];

var rxGetCountryCode = /^.{8}[^\/]*\/([^\/]*)/;

urls.forEach(function (str) {
  console.log(rxGetCountryCode.exec(str)[1]);
});
```

Comment: I added the other URLs to your example for completeness. I also added the an item explaining the slash after `[^\/]`; OP seems to understand what you were doing, but just in case someone finds this in the future who doesn't understand RegEx as well.