# Get URL parts in winapi

Tags: url, winapi

Is there an API in Windows that can crack a url into parts?

### Background

The format of a URL is:

```
stackoverflow://iboyd:password01@mail.stackoverflow.com:12386/questions/SubmitQuestion.aspx?useLiveData=1&internal=0#nose
\___________/   \___/ \________/ \____________________/ \___/ \___________________________/\_______________________/ \__/
     |            |       |               |               |                |                          |                |
   scheme     username password        hostname          port             path                      query           fragment
```

Is there a function in (native) Win32 api that can crack a URL into parts:

- **Scheme**: `stackoverflow`
- **Username**: `iboyd`
- **Password:** `password01`
- **Host name:** `mail.stackoverflow.com`
- **Port**: `12386`
- **Path**: `questions/SubmitQuestion.aspx`
- **Query**: `?useLiveData=1&internal=0`
- **Fragment**: `nose`

### Some functions don't work

There are some functions in WinApi, but they fail to do the job because they don't understand schemes except the ones that `WinHttp` can use:

- **[UrlGetPart](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb773781.aspx)**
- **[WinHttpCrackUrl](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384092(v=vs.85).aspx)** *(forbids any scheme other than http or https)*

both fail to understand urls such as:

- `ws://stackoverflow.com` *(web-socket)*
- `wss://stackoverflow.com` *(web-socket secure)*
- `sftp://fincen.gov/submit` *(SSL file transfer)*
- `magnet:?xt=urn:btih:c4244b6d0901f71add9a1f9e88013a2fa51a9900`
- `stratum+udp://blockchain.info`

WinHttpCrackUrl actively prevents being used to crack URLs:

> If the Internet protocol of the URL passed in for *pwszUrl* is not HTTP or HTTPS, then **WinHttpCrackUrl** returns **FALSE** and **GetLastError** indicates **[ERROR_WINHTTP_UNRECOGNIZED_SCHEME](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383770(v=vs.85).aspx#ERROR_WINHTTP_UNRECOGNIZED_SCHEME)**.

Is there another native API in Windows that can get parts of a url?

### Bonus Chatter

Here's how you do it in CLR (e.g. C#): *([fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/G0JDJB))*

```
using System;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var uri = new Uri("stackoverflow://iboyd:password01@mail.stackoverflow.com:12386/questions/SubmitQuestion.aspx?useLiveData=1&internal=0#nose");

        Console.WriteLine("Uri.Scheme: "+uri.Scheme);
        Console.WriteLine("Uri.UserInfo: "+uri.UserInfo);
        Console.WriteLine("Uri.Host: "+uri.Host);
        Console.WriteLine("Uri.Port: "+uri.Port);
        Console.WriteLine("Uri.AbsolutePath: "+uri.AbsolutePath);
        Console.WriteLine("Uri.Query: "+uri.Query);
        Console.WriteLine("Uri.Fragment: "+uri.Fragment);
    }
}
```

**Outputs**

```
Uri.Scheme: stackoverflow
Uri.UserInfo: iboyd:password01
Uri.Host: mail.stackoverflow.com
Uri.Port: 12386
Uri.AbsolutePath: /questions/SubmitQuestion.aspx
Uri.Query: ?useLiveData=1&internal=0
Uri.Fragment: #nose
```

Comment: [`ParseURL`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb773825(v=vs.85).aspx) is not good enough either.

Comment: Does the [Uri](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.foundation.uri) class work for you?

Comment: A [RegEx](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27745/7571258) can work, if you find a good one. ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a number of functions available to native Windows developers:

- [**UrlGetPart**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb773781.aspx): *Shell lightweight utility function*
- [**WinHttpCrackUrl**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384092.aspx): *WinHTTP 5.1*
- **[InternetCrackUrl](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384376.aspx)**: *WinINet (client version of WinHTTP)*

Of these, **InternetCrackUrl** works.

```
URL_COMPONENTS components;
components.dwStructSize      = sizeof(URL_COMPONENTS);
components.dwSchemeLength    = DWORD(-1);
components.dwHostNameLength  = DWORD(-1);
components.dwUserNameLength  = DWORD(-1);
components.dwPasswordLength  = DWORD(-1);
components.dwUrlPathLength   = DWORD(-1);
components.dwExtraInfoLength = DWORD(-1);

if (!InternetCrackUrl(url, url.Length, 0, ref components)
    RaiseLastOSError();

String scheme   = StrLCopy(components.lpszScheme, components.dwSchemeLength);
String username = StrLCopy(components.lpszUserName, components.dwUserNameLength);
String password = StrLCopy(components.lpszPassword, components.dwPasswordLength);
String host     = StrLCopy(components.lpszHostName, components.dwHostNameLength);
Int32  port     = components.nPort;
String path     = StrLCopy(components.lpszUrlPath, components.dwUrlPathLength);
String extra    = StrLCopy(components.lpszExtraInfo, components.dwExtraInfoLength);
```

This means that

> stackoverflow://iboyd:password01@mail.stackoverflow.com:12386/questions/SubmitQuestion.aspx?useLiveData=1&internal=0#nose

is parsed into:

- **Scheme**: `stackoverflow`
- **Username**: `iboyd`
- **Password**: `password01`
- **Host**: `mail.stackoverflow.com`
- **Port**: `12386`
- **Path**: `/questions/SubmitQuestion.aspx`
- **ExtraInfo**: `?useLiveData=1&internal=0#nose`

### Parsing ExtraInfo into query and fragment

It sucks that InternetCrackUrl doesn't make a distinction between:

```
?query#fragment
```

and just mashes them together as *ExtraInfo*:

- **ExtraInfo**: `?useLiveData=1&internal=0#nose`

  - **Query**: `?useLiveData=1&internal=0`
  - **Fragment**: `#nose`

So we have to do some splitting if we want the `?query` or the `#fragment`:

```
/*
   InternetCrackUrl returns ?query#fragment in a single combined extraInfo field.
   Split that into separate
      ?query
      #fragment
*/
String query = extraInfo;
String fragment = "";

Int32 n = StrPos("#", extraInfo);
if (n >= 1) //one-based string indexes
{
   query = extraInfo.SubString(1, n-1);
   fragment = extraInfo.SubString(n, MaxInt);
}
```

Giving us the final desired:

- **Scheme**: `stackoverflow`
- **Username**: `iboyd`
- **Password**: `password01`
- **Host**: `mail.stackoverflow.com`
- **Port**: `12386`
- **Path**: `/questions/SubmitQuestion.aspx`
- **ExtraInfo**: `?useLiveData=1&internal=0#nose`

  - **Query**: `?useLiveData=1&internal=0`
  - **Fragment**: `#nose`

Comment: Again, why not use the [Uri](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.foundation.uri) class? Apparently, you don't care as much about a Windows API as you care about being available to a native Windows developer. That one is, although it is Windows 10 only. On the upside, it parses *query* and *fragment* into separate properties.

Comment: @IInspectable: Windows 10-only is still possibly a pretty major problem. (For instance, I still use Windows 7.)

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand: Yes, possibly. And possibly it isn't. That's why I'm asking for clarification.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there an API in Windows that can crack a url into parts?

There is in Windows 10. The [Uri](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.foundation.uri) class in the Windows Runtime is capable of decomposing a URI into its individual parts. This is not strictly part of the Windows API, but consumable by any Windows API application.

The following code illustrates its usage. It is written using the [C++/WinRT](https://aka.ms/cppwinrt) language projection, requiring a C++17 compiler. If you cannot switch to a C++17 compiler, you can use the [Windows Runtime C++ Template Library (WRL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/windows/windows-runtime-cpp-template-library-wrl) instead to consume the Windows Runtime APIs.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <winrt/Windows.Foundation.h>

#pragma comment(lib, "WindowsApp.lib")

using namespace winrt;
using namespace Windows::Foundation;

int wmain(int argc, wchar_t* wargv[])
{
    if (argc != 2)
    {
        std::wcout << L"Usage:\n  UrlCracker <url>" << std::endl;
        return 1;
    }

    init_apartment();

    Uri const uri{ wargv[1] };
    std::wcout << L"Scheme: " << uri.SchemeName().c_str() << std::endl;
    std::wcout << L"Username: " << uri.UserName().c_str() << std::endl;
    std::wcout << L"Password: " << uri.Password().c_str() << std::endl;
    std::wcout << L"Host: " << uri.Host().c_str() << std::endl;
    std::wcout << L"Port: " << std::to_wstring(uri.Port()) << std::endl;
    std::wcout << L"Path: " << uri.Path().c_str() << std::endl;
    std::wcout << L"Query: " << uri.Query().c_str() << std::endl;
    std::wcout << L"Fragment: " << uri.Fragment().c_str() << std::endl;
}
```

This program digests any URI spelled out in the question. Using the input

> stackoverflow://iboyd:password01@mail.stackoverflow.com:12386/questions/SubmitQuestion.aspx?useLiveData=1&internal=0#nose

produces the following output:

> ```
> Scheme: stackoverflow
> Username: iboyd
> Password: password01
> Host: mail.stackoverflow.com
> Port: 12386
> Path: /questions/SubmitQuestion.aspx
> Query: ?useLiveData=1&internal=0
> Fragment: #nose
> ```

Error handling has been omitted. In case the `Uri` c'tor is passed an invalid string, it throws an exception of type [winrt::hresult_error](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/cpp-ref-for-winrt/error-handling/hresult-error). If you cannot use exceptions in your code, you can activate the type manually (e.g. using the WRL), and inspect the `HRESULT` return values instead.