# Finding string with findall regex python 3 problem

Tags: regex, python-3.x, findall

Below is a list of web addresses. However, I would like to print only hostname of each address.

```
http://www.askoxford.com
http://www.hydrogencarsnow.com
http://www.bnsf.com
http://web.archive.org
```

Expected result:

```
askoxford.com
hydrogencarsnow.com
bnsf.com
web.archive.org
```

My code:

```
import re
import codecs
raw = codecs.open("D:\Python\gg.txt",'r',encoding='utf-8')
string = raw.read()
link = re.findall(r'www\.(\w+\.com|\w+\.org)',string)
print(link)
```

Current Output:

```
['askoxford.com', 'askoxford.com', 'hydrogencarsnow.com', 'bnsf.com']
```

As of current output, it does not include hostname.org. I'm unsure of the way to the make OR condition for reg in front of the string.

My Tries:
    `link = re.findall(r'(http://www\.|http://)(\w+\.com|\w+\.org)',string)`, but it does not work as it would collect http...with the hostname.

Comment: You already have [`urllib.parse`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html) to do that. Also, there already exist [regexes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27745/getting-parts-of-a-url-regex) that extract various parts of URLs, so you should probably use those instead of rolling your own.

Comment: Try `(?m)^(?:https?://)?(?:www\.)?(.*\.(?:com|org|org))$`, see https://regex101.com/r/Roh87C/1