# Extract data from URL, PHP Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

Right now i am working on a Codeigniter project in which I am sending a link to the user to update their password, every thing is working according to the plan. Now all I need to know is that how can I extract data from URL that the user is following to update password.

> Example:
>   http://localhost/ciauth/user/password_reset/user@gmail.com/6f1bb1aeba261e92c390ac28d85267767038703e

I want to extract the code after the E-mail ID.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Getting parts of a URL (Regex)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27745/getting-parts-of-a-url-regex)

Comment: This question is fully compiled by me, I will appreciate if you take your down-vote back.

Answer (score 2):

> Never mind i have solved it doing
>   $url_code=$this->uri->segment(4);

This is okay. But it will be better if you implement it with your action function:

```
    public function password_reset($email, $code){
        // $email: user@gmail.com
        // $code: 6f1bb1aeba261e92c390ac28d85267767038703e
    }
```

Comment: don't forget `$email = null, $code = null` otherwise undefined if that segment isn't present.

Comment: thanks for your time, my code is working right now so i dont want to spend even 1 more second on it.

Answer (score 1):

Try this, From this you can do extract full `url`, Place below code to your `password_reset()` to see your url `extraction`

```
echo'<pre>';print_r($this->uri->segment_array());die;
```

Answer (score 0):

Never mind i have solved it doing

`$url_code=$this->uri->segment(4);`