# Extract the portions of the string using REGULAR Expression in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, regex, pattern-matching

I tried to extract the Only URL part not the Path, for example

if the url is `https://example.com/news/cricket`

the output should be `https://example.com/`

but i am not strong on regular expression.

```js
data = "https://example.com/news/cricket";
var name = data.substring(0, data.lastIndexOf("/"));
console.log(name);
```

this is what i have tried
but output is:-

```
https://example.com/news
```

Expected output is

```
https://example.com/
```

Thank for healping guys

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27745/getting-parts-of-a-url-regex

Comment: @Barmar, yes sorry for the dry Question, i tried to get the index of "/" not "//" after getting the index of "/", i tried to extract the URL but , i didn't work.
Thanks

Comment: Show how you tried to do it, then we can help you fix it.

Comment: @Barmar indexOf will return the index number of the character right.

Answer (score 0):

`lastIndexOf()` returns the index of the last `/`, which is the one before `cricked`, not before `news`.

`indexOf()` takes an optional starting index, you can first search for `//` and then search for the next `/` after that.

You need to add 2 to the index of `//` to skip over it. And you have to add 1 to the index of `/` so you include the `/` in the result.

```js
data = "https://example.com/news/cricket";
var name = data.substring(0, data.indexOf("/", data.indexOf("//")+2)+1);
console.log(name);
```

With a regexp, use a regexp that matches up to the first `//` and then to the next `/`.

```js
var data = "https://example.com/news/cricket";
var match = data.match(/^.*?\/\/.*?\//);
if (match) {
  var name = match[0];
  console.log(name);
}
```