# Get part of the url and insert it in the button

Tags: javascript, jquery, url, referer

There is an address of the type `site.com/userlist/?getlist=XXXX&userid=XX`. I need to get part of the URL, namely `/userlist/?getlist=XXXX&userid=XX` and insert the button with the ID `reg_button`.

I'm leaning towards jquery and apparently regex, but I haven't found a suitable method yet or I don't understand it, I'm just learning)

Answer (score 0):

```js
let url_test=new URL('http://www.yourtestdomain.com/userlist/?getlist=XXXX&userid=XX');
console.log(url_test.pathname+url_test.search);
```

Answer (score 0):

This takes the url minus base *(domain)* aswell as the query part, and also URN if exists

[documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/location)

```js
console.log(window.location.href.replace(window.location.origin, ""))
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to do it. I have included 2 ways here. **URL** class can also be used as mentioned by one of the answerer but the URL string needs to be complete with **http** prefix.

If you want it using regex you check this [Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27745/getting-parts-of-a-url-regex) thread.

```js
var siteurl = "site.com/userlist/?getlist=XXXX&userid=XX";
function method1(){
  var paths = siteurl.split('/');
  paths.shift();
  var basePath = paths.join('/');
  alert(basePath);
} 

function method2(){
  var basePath = siteurl.substring(siteurl.indexOf('/'));
  alert(basePath);
}
```

```html
<button onclick = 'method1()'>Method1</button>
<button onclick = 'method2()'>Method2</button>
```